# Quantifying the amount of change in a git diff?

Tags: git, word-count

I use git for a slightly unusual purpose--it stores my text as I write fiction. (I know, I know...geeky.)

I am trying to keep track of productivity, and want to measure the degree of difference between subsequent commits. The writer's proxy for "work" is "words written", at least during the creation stage. I can't use straight word count as it ignores editing and compression, both vital parts of writing. I think I want to track:

```
 (words added)+(words removed)
```

which will double-count (words changed), but I'm okay with that.

It'd be great to type some magic incantation and have git report this distance metric for any two revisions. However, git diffs are patches, which show entire lines even if you've only twiddled one character on the line; I don't want that, especially since my 'lines' are paragraphs. Ideally I'd even be able to specify what I mean by "word" (though \W+ would probably be acceptable).

Is there a flag to git-diff to give diffs on a word-by-word basis? Alternately, is there a solution using standard command-line tools to compute the metric above?

Comment: That's really an excellent usage - git's a content tracker. And it's not that unusual - have a look at last year's git survey https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSurvey2009#07._I_use_Git_for_.28check_all_that_apply.29:

Comment: Actually, I use git for all my writing. I first started when I wrote my dissertation, and it saved my bacon a ton of times in ways backups would not have. I use markdown or Latex to write in, too, which git plays well with.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[wdiff](http://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/) does word-by-word comparison. Git can be configured to use an external program to do the diffing. Based on those two facts and [this blog post](http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-meld-for-git-diffs-in-ubuntu-hardy), the following should do roughly what you want.

Create a script to ignore most of the unnecessary arguments that `git-diff` provides and pass them to `wdiff`. Save the following as `~/wdiff.py` or something similar and make it executable.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os

os.system('wdiff -s3 "%s" "%s"' % (sys.argv[2], sys.argv[5]))
```

Tell `git` to use it.

```
git config --global diff.external ~/wdiff.py
git diff filename
```

Comment: This was a good answer for the time before there was `git diff --word-diff`

Comment: @Jarus It's still the best answer as far as I can tell: `--word-diff` doesn't show per-word statistics.

Comment: Now with `git difftool` it is no longer necessary to permanently modify git's `diff` output, you can define as many custom diff commands as you want, and of course you can then give them aliases. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40849802/1764245

Answer (score 14):

Building on [James' and cornmacrelf's input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874318/quantifying-the-amount-of-change-in-a-git-diff/31823590#answer-28183710), I've added [arithmetic expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348902/how-can-i-add-numbers-in-a-bash-script#answer-6348941),
and came up with a few reusable alias commands for counting words added, deleted, and duplicated in a git diff:

```
alias gitwa='git diff --word-diff=porcelain origin/master | grep -e "^+[^+]" | wc -w | xargs'
alias gitwd='git diff --word-diff=porcelain origin/master | grep -e "^-[^-]" | wc -w | xargs'
alias gitwdd='git diff --word-diff=porcelain origin/master |grep -e"^+[^+]" -e"^-[^-]"|sed -e's/.//'|sort|uniq -d|wc -w|xargs'

alias gitw='echo $(($(gitwa) - $(gitwd)))'
```

Output from `gitwa` and `gitwd` is [trimmed using xargs trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable#answer-12973694).

Words duplicated added from Miles' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44615229/3823857).

Answer (score 13):

git diff --word-diff works in the latest stable version of git (at git-scm.com)

There are a few options that let you decide what format you want it in, the default is quite readable but you might want --word-diff=porcelain if you're feeding the output into a script.

Comment: It doesn't give per-word statistics though, which is what the question is about.

Comment: It gets you 99% of the way there. For example: ``git diff --word-diff=porcelain | grep -e '^+[^+]\|^-[^-]'``

Answer (score 13):

I figured out a way to get concrete numbers by building on top of the other answers here. The result is an approximation, but it should be close enough to serve as a useful indicator of the amount characters that were added or removed. Here's an example with my current branch compared to origin/master:

```
$ git diff --word-diff=porcelain origin/master | grep -e '^+[^+]' | wc -m
38741
$ git diff --word-diff=porcelain origin/master | grep -e '^-[^-]' | wc -m
46664
```

The difference between the removed characters (`46664`) and the added characters (`38741`) shows that my current branch has removed approximately `7923` characters. Those individual added/removed counts are inflated due to the diff's `+`/`-` and indentation characters, however, the difference should cancel out a significant portion of that inflation in most cases.

Comment: Why not go all the way and answer the original question? `wc -w` would find word counts instead. Much more useful.

Comment: You can add `sed 's/^.//'` to the pipeline to remove the trailing '+'/'-'.

Answer (score 5):

I liked [Stoutie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/826331/stoutie)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31823590/532524) and wanted to make it a bit more configurable to answer some word count questions I had. Ended up with the following solution that works in ZSH and should work in Bash. Each function takes any [revision or revision difference](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection), with a default of comparing the current state of the world with `origin/master`:

```
# Calculate writing word diff between revisions. Cribbed / modified from:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874318/quantifying-the-amount-of-change-in-a-git-diff
function git_words_added {
  revision=${1:-origin/master}

  git diff --word-diff=porcelain $revision | \
    grep -e "^+[^+]" | \
    wc -w | \
    xargs
}

function git_words_removed {
  revision=${1:-origin/master}

  git diff --word-diff=porcelain $revision | \
    grep -e "^-[^-]" | \
    wc -w | \
    xargs
}

function git_words_diff {
  revision=${1:-origin/master}

  echo $(($(git_words_added $1) - $(git_words_removed $1)))
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
$ git_words_added
# => how many words were added since origin/master

$ git_words_removed
# => how many words were removed since origin/master

$ git_words_diff
# => difference of adds and removes since origin/master (net words)

$ git_words_diff HEAD
# => net words since you last committed

$ git_words_diff master@{yesterday}
# => net words written today!

$ git_words_diff HEAD^..HEAD
# => net words in the last commit

$ git_words_diff ABC123..DEF456
# => net words between two arbitrary commits
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 4):

Git has had (for a long time) a `--color-words` option for `git diff`. This doesn't get you your counting, but it does let you see the diffs.

scompt.com's suggestion of wdiff is also good; it's pretty easy to shove in a different differ (see [git-difftool](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-difftool.html)). From there you just have to go from the output wdiff can give to the result you really want.

There's one more exciting thing to share, though, from git's what's cooking:

```
* tr/word-diff (2010-04-14) 1 commit
  (merged to 'next' on 2010-05-04 at d191b25)
 + diff: add --word-diff option that generalizes --color-words
```

Here's the [commit introducing word-diff](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=882749a04f828fccd795deec4d0bf10ba09ae549). Presumably it will make its way from next into master before long, and then git will be able to do this all internally - either producing its own word diff format or something similar to wdiff. If you're daring, you could build git from next, or just merge that one commit into your local master to build.

Thanks to Jakub's comment: you can further customize word diffs if necessary by providing a word regex (config parameter diff.*.wordRegex), documented in [gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_customizing_word_diff).

Comment: There is also `diff.<diff driver>.wordRegex` configuration variable, to go together with `diff=<diff driver>` gitattribute, where you can define what constitutes word.

Answer (score 4):

The above answers fail for some use cases where you need to exclude moved text (e.g., if I move a function in code or paragraph in latex further down the document, I don't want to count all of those as changes!)

For that, you can also calculate the number of duplicate lines, and exclude those from your query if there are too many duplicates.

For example, building on the other answers, I can do:

```sh
git diff $sha~1..$sha|grep -e"^+[^+]" -e"^-[^-]"|sed -e's/.//'|sort|uniq -d|wc -w|xargs
```

calculates the number of duplicate words in the diff, where `sha` is your commit.

You can do this for all the commits within the last day (since 6 am) by:

```sh
for sha in $(git rev-list --since="6am" master | sed -e '$ d'); do
     echo $(git diff --word-diff=porcelain $sha~1..$sha|grep -e"^+[^+]"|wc -w|xargs),\
     $(git diff --word-diff=porcelain $sha~1..$sha|grep -e"^-[^-]"|wc -w|xargs),\
     $(git diff $sha~1..$sha|grep -e"^+[^+]" -e"^-[^-]"|sed -e's/.//'|sort|uniq -d|wc -w|xargs)
done
```

Prints: added, deleted, duplicates

(I take the line diff for duplicates, as it excludes the times where `git diff` tries to be too clever, and assumes you have actually just changed text rather than moved it. It also discounts instances where a single word is counted as a duplicate.)

Or, if you want to be sophisticated about it, you can exclude commits entirely if there is more than 80% duplication, and sum up the rest:

```sh
total=0
for sha in $(git rev-list --since="6am" master | sed -e '$ d'); do
    added=$(git diff --word-diff=porcelain $sha~1..$sha|grep -e"^+[^+]"|wc -w|xargs)
    deleted=$(git diff --word-diff=porcelain $sha~1..$sha|grep -e"^-[^-]"|wc -w|xargs)
    duplicated=$(git diff $sha~1..$sha|grep -e"^+[^+]" -e"^-[^-]"|sed -e's/.//'|sort|uniq -d|wc -w|xargs)
    if [ "$added" -eq "0" ]; then
        changed=$deleted
        total=$((total+deleted))
        echo "added:" $added, "deleted:" $deleted, "duplicated:"\
             $duplicated, "changed:" $changed
    elif [ "$(echo "$duplicated/$added > 0.8" | bc -l)" -eq "1" ]; then
        echo "added:" $added, "deleted:" $deleted, "duplicated:"\
             $duplicated, "changes counted:" 0
    else
        changed=$((added+deleted))
        total=$((total+changed))
        echo "added:" $added, "deleted:" $deleted, "duplicated:"\
             $duplicated, "changes counted:" $changed
    fi
done
echo "Total changed:" $total
```

I have this script to do it here: https://github.com/MilesCranmer/git-stats.

This prints out:

```
➜  bifrost_paper git:(master) ✗ count_changed_words "6am" 

added: 38, deleted: 76, duplicated: 3, changes counted: 114
added: 14, deleted: 19, duplicated: 0, changes counted: 33
added: 1113, deleted: 1112, duplicated: 1106, changes counted: 0
added: 1265, deleted: 1275, duplicated: 1225, changes counted: 0
added: 4207, deleted: 4208, duplicated: 4391, changes counted: 0
Total changed: 147
```

The commits where I am just moving around things are obvious, so I don't count those changes. It counts up everything else and tells me the total number of changed words.

Comment: To make this work exactly like [Stoutie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31823590/3823857) you can do `git diff --word-diff=porcelain origin/master |grep -e"^+[^+]" -e"^-[^-]"|sed -e's/.//'|sort|uniq -d|wc -w|xargs`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation points to comment on @codebeard's answer. It is the one I used, and I added both of his versions to my .gitconfig file. They gave different answers, and I traced the problem to  `wdiff -sd` in the second version (the one that combines all modified files together) counting the words in the two lines at the top of the output of `diff -pdrU3`. It will be something like:

```
--- 1   2018-12-10 22:53:47.838902415 -0800
+++ 2   2018-12-10 22:53:57.674835179 -0800
```

I fixed this by piping through `tail -n +4`.

Here's my full .gitconfig settings with the fix in place:

```
[alias]
    wdiff = diff
    wdiffs = difftool -t wdiffs
    wdiffs-all = difftool -d -t wdiffs-all
[difftool "wdiffs"]
    cmd = wdiff -n -s \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" | colordiff
[difftool "wdiffs-all"]
    cmd = diff -pdrU3 \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" | tail -n +4 | wdiff -sd
```

If you'd rather use `git config` here are the commands:

```
git config --global difftool.wdiffs.cmd 'wdiff -n -s "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"' | colordiff
git config --global alias.wdiffs 'difftool -t wdiffs'
git config --global difftool.wdiffs-all.cmd 'diff -pdrU3 "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" | wdiff -sd'
git config --global alias.wdiffs-all 'difftool -d -t wdiffs-all'
```

Now, you can do `git wdiffs` or `git wdiffs-all` to get your word count since the last commit.

To compare to origin/master, do `git wdiffs origin/master` or `git wdiffs-all origin/master`.

I like this answer the best because it gives both the word count and the diff, and if you pipe through `colordiff`, it comes out nice and colored. (@Miles answer is also good but requires you to figure out what time to use. However, I like the idea of looking for moved text.)

wdiff's stats output at the end looks like this:

```
file1.txt: 12360 words  12360 100% common  0 0% deleted  5 0% changed
file2.txt: 12544 words  12360 99% common  184 1% inserted  11 0% changed
```

To find out how many words you have added, add `inserted` and `changed` from the second line, 184+11, in the example above.

Why not anything from the first line? Answer: those are words removed.

Here's a bash script to get a single, unified word count:

```
wdiffoutput=$(git wdiffs-all | tail -n 1)
wdiffins=$(echo "$wdiffoutput" | grep -oP "common *\K\d*")
wdiffchg=$(echo "$wdiffoutput" | grep -oP "inserted *\K\d*")
echo "Word Count: $((wdiffins+wdiffchg))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Git 1.6.3 there is also `git difftool`, which can be configured to run nearly any external diff tool. This is a lot easier than some of the solutions which require creating scripts etc. If you like the output of `wdiff -s` you can configure something like:

```
git config --global difftool.wdiffs.cmd 'wdiff -s "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"'
git config --global alias.wdiffs 'difftool -t wdiffs'
```

Now you can just run `git difftool -t wdiffs` or its alias `git wdiffs`.

If you prefer to get statistics for all modified files together, instead do something like:

```
git config --global difftool.wdiffs.cmd 'diff -pdrU3 "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" | wdiff -sd'
git config --global alias.wdiffs 'difftool -d -t wdiffs'
```

This takes the output of a typical unified `diff` and pipes it into `wdiff` with its `-d` option set to just interpret the input. In contrast, the extra `-d` argument to `difftool` in the alias tells git to copy all modified files to a temporary directory before doing the diff.