# How can I add numbers in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, integer-arithmetic, mathematical-expressions

I have this Bash script and I had a problem in line 16.
How can I take the previous result of line 15 and add
it to the variable in line 16?

```
#!/bin/bash

num=0
metab=0

for ((i=1; i<=2; i++)); do
    for j in `ls output-$i-*`; do
        echo "$j"

        metab=$(cat $j|grep EndBuffer|awk '{sum+=$2} END { print sum/120}') (line15)
        num= $num + $metab   (line16)
    done
    echo "$num"
 done
```

Comment: I think you will print a zero value even using following answer. There's a trick, e.g. process substition, to bring the final value of "inside num" to "outside num".

Answer (score 1299):

*For integers*:

- Use [arithmetic expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html): `$((EXPR))`

  ```
  num=$((num1 + num2))
  num=$(($num1 + $num2))       # Also works
  num=$((num1 + 2 + 3))        # ...
  num=$[num1+num2]             # Old, deprecated arithmetic expression syntax
  ```
- Using the external `expr` utility. Note that this is only needed for really old systems.

  ```
  num=`expr $num1 + $num2`     # Whitespace for expr is important
  ```

---

*For floating point*:

Bash doesn't directly support this, but there are a couple of external tools you can use:

```
num=$(awk "BEGIN {print $num1+$num2; exit}")
num=$(python -c "print $num1+$num2")
num=$(perl -e "print $num1+$num2")
num=$(echo $num1 + $num2 | bc)   # Whitespace for echo is important
```

You can also use scientific notation (for example, `2.5e+2`).

---

*Common pitfalls*:

- When setting a variable, you cannot have whitespace on either side of `=`, otherwise it will force the shell to interpret the first word as the name of the application to run (for example, `num=` or `num`)

  <strike>`num= 1`</strike> <strike>`num =2`</strike>
- `bc` and `expr` expect each number and operator as a separate argument, so whitespace is important. They cannot process arguments like `3+` `+4`.

  <strike>`` num=`expr $num1+ $num2` ``</strike>

Comment: In the first answer it prints me expr:non-numeric argument
The second doesn't work..

Comment: @Nick: Did you try this while variables named `num1` and `num2` existed and had integer values?

Comment: Yew they are existed but the one variable is double..
is that a problem??

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem :)
Note: the `$((..))` arithmetic evaluation is executed in bash. `expr` is executed as a separate process, so it's going to be a lot slower. use the latter one on systems where the arithemtic evaluation isn't supported (sh!=bash)

Comment: Since `$((…))` is standardized by POSIX, it should become increasingly rare that `expr` is necessary.

Comment: I am thinking your answer here for local variables http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229049/16920

Comment: Any issues with a function like this in your profile? function calc() { echo "${1}" | bc -l; } callable as calc '1 + 2' or calc '1 / 2'.   originally I was going with $((...)) but it does not handle floating point.

Comment: `expr` POSIX documentation itself recommends to use $(()) instead in new scripts: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html —

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I'm trying to use my integer `$num` (which equals 13 in this example), as computed in the first example, in a for loop ```for i in {$numDays..1}```, but I get ```{13..1}: integer expression expected```.  Why isn't `$num` an integer?

Answer (score 180):

Use the `$(( ))` arithmetic expansion.

```
num=$(( $num + $metab ))
```

See *[Chapter 13. Arithmetic Expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html)* for more information.

Comment: Strange. It does not work here when I try to compute `191.003 + 190`.

Comment: @Sigur I believe this is because bash doesn't natively support floating point maths .i.e this method, nice as it is, only works with integers. Try using one of the `dc` or `bc` solutions instead.

Comment: Is mandatory use `$` between the `(())`? Seems not

Comment: @ManuelJordan No, `num=$((num1 + num2))` should work just as well.

Comment: Using `$` inside an arithmetic expansion is unnecessary, and in fact, it can lead to some bugs. See: https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2004.

Comment: Also, spaces after `((` and before `))` are unnecessary - unlike in conditionals (e.g. `[ $somevar = 'something' ]`

Answer (score 37):

There are a thousand and one ways to do it. Here's one using [`dc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dc) (a reverse Polish desk calculator which supports unlimited precision arithmetic):

```
dc <<<"$num1 $num2 + p"
```

But if that's too bash-y for you (or portability matters) you could say

```
echo $num1 $num2 + p | dc
```

But maybe you're one of those people who thinks RPN is icky and weird; don't worry! [`bc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc) is here for you:

```
bc <<< "$num1 + $num2"
echo $num1 + $num2 | bc
```

That said, there are some unrelated improvements you could be making to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=0
metab=0

for ((i=1; i<=2; i++)); do
    for j in output-$i-* ; do # 'for' can glob directly, no need to ls
            echo "$j"

             # 'grep' can read files, no need to use 'cat'
            metab=$(grep EndBuffer "$j" | awk '{sum+=$2} END { print sum/120}')
            num=$(( $num + $metab ))
    done
    echo "$num"
done
```

As described in [Bash FAQ 022](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022), Bash does not natively support floating point numbers. If you need to sum floating point numbers the use of an external tool (like `bc` or `dc`) is required.

In this case the solution would be

```
num=$(dc <<<"$num $metab + p")
```

To add accumulate possibly-floating-point numbers into `num`.

Comment: @Sorpigal Thankssss a lot..
Can i ask you something else..how can i print at the end not the num but the num/10 ??

Answer (score 27):

In Bash,

```
 num=5
 x=6
 (( num += x ))
 echo $num   # ==> 11
```

Note that Bash can only handle integer arithmetic, so if your AWK command returns a fraction, then you'll want to redesign: here's your code rewritten a bit to do all math in AWK.

```
num=0
for ((i=1; i<=2; i++)); do
    for j in output-$i-*; do
        echo "$j"
        num=$(
           awk -v n="$num" '
               /EndBuffer/ {sum += $2}
               END {print n + (sum/120)}
           ' "$j"
        )
    done
    echo "$num"
done
```

Answer (score 27):

I always forget the syntax so I come to Google Search, but then I never find the one I'm familiar with :P. This is the cleanest to me and more true to what I'd expect in other languages.

```
i=0
((i++))

echo $i;
```

Answer (score 20):

I really like this method as well. There is less clutter:

```
count=$[count+1]
```

Comment: Why is this working, by the way? How do we call this? I can't find docs about these.

Comment: Less clutter, but deprecated.

Answer (score 18):

```
 #!/bin/bash
read X
read Y
echo "$(($X+$Y))"
```

Comment: Works well in macOS.

Answer (score 11):

You should declare *metab* as integer and then use arithmetic evaluation

```
declare -i metab num
...
num+=metab
...
```

For more information, see *[6.5 Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic)*.

Answer (score 11):

Use the shell built-in `let`. It is similar to `(( expr ))`:

```
A=1
B=1
let "C = $A + $B"
echo $C # C == 2
```

Source: *[Bash let builtin command](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/let.htm)*

Answer (score 7):

Another portable [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) compliant way to do in Bash, which can be defined as a function in `.bashrc` for all the arithmetic operators of convenience.

```
addNumbers () {
    local IFS='+'
    printf "%s\n" "$(( $* ))"
}
```

and just call it in command-line as,

```
addNumbers 1 2 3 4 5 100
115
```

The idea is to use the [Input-Field-Separator(IFS)](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS), a special variable in Bash used for word splitting after expansion and to split lines into words. The function changes the value locally to use word-splitting character as the sum operator `+`.

Remember the `IFS` is changed locally and does *not* take effect on the default `IFS` behaviour outside the function scope. An excerpt from the `man bash` page,

> The shell treats each character of IFS as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions into words on these characters. If IFS is unset, or its value is exactly , the default, then sequences of , , and  at the beginning and end of the results of the previous expansions are ignored, and any sequence of IFS characters not at the beginning or end serves to delimit words.

The `"$(( $* ))"` represents the list of arguments passed to be split by `+` and later the sum value is output using the `printf` function. The function can be extended to add scope for other arithmetic operations also.

Comment: If you use Bash it's not POSIX compliant since it won't work on POSIX machines without Bash.

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#integer numbers
#===============#

num1=30
num2=5

echo $(( num1 + num2 ))
echo $(( num1-num2 ))
echo $(( num1*num2 ))
echo $(( num1/num2 ))
echo $(( num1%num2 ))

read -p "Enter first number : " a
read -p "Enter second number : " b
# we can store the result
result=$(( a+b ))
echo sum of $a \& $b is $result # \ is used to espace &


#decimal numbers
#bash only support integers so we have to delegate to a tool such as bc
#==============#

num2=3.4
num1=534.3

echo $num1+$num2 | bc
echo $num1-$num2 | bc
echo $num1*$num2 |bc
echo "scale=20;$num1/$num2" | bc
echo $num1%$num2 | bc

# we can store the result
#result=$( ( echo $num1+$num2 ) | bc )
result=$( echo $num1+$num2 | bc )
echo result is $result

##Bonus##
#Calling built in methods of bc 

num=27

echo "scale=2;sqrt($num)" | bc -l # bc provides support for calculating square root

echo "scale=2;$num^3" | bc -l # calculate power
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash

num=0
metab=0

for ((i=1; i<=2; i++)); do      
    for j in `ls output-$i-*`; do
        echo "$j"

        metab=$(cat $j|grep EndBuffer|awk '{sum+=$2} END { print sum/120}') (line15)
        let num=num+metab (line 16)
    done
    echo "$num"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

5.1

```
git clone https://github.com/datablist/sample-csv-files.git
```

5.2

```
cd sample-csv-files
git log --pretty=format:"%h - %s" -n 3
```

5.3

```
awk -F, 'NR>=40 && NR<=70 {print $1":"$2":"$3}' files/people/people-100.csv
```

5.4

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
echo "Utilizare: $0 adresa_de_email"
exit 1
fi

EMAIL=$1

FILE="files/people/people-10000.csv"

RESULT=$(grep -n "$EMAIL" "$FILE")

if [ -z "$RESULT" ]; then
echo "Adresa de email '$EMAIL' nu a fost găsită."
else
echo "Date găsite: $RESULT"
fi
```

1

Here is my solution:

5.1

```
mkdir -p ~/student/my-app
cd ~/student/my-app
git init
```

5.2

```
echo "Hello, World!" > ~/student/my-app/hello.txt
cd ~/student/my-app
git add hello.txt
git commit -m "Added hello.txt with 'Hello, World!'"
```

5.3

```
command -v cowsay >/dev/null 2>&1 || sudo apt-get install -y cowsay
```

5.4

```
echo "PID-ul procesului părinte este: $$" și "PPID-ul este: $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=)"
```

2

Answer (score -1):

Works on MacOS. bc is a command line calculator

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0
for (( i=1; i<=5; i++ )); do
    sum=$(echo "$sum + 1.1" | bc) # bc: if you want to use decimal
done
echo "Total: $sum"
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution:
6.1
tail -n 15 ~/.bash_history | base64 | sha256sum

6.2

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
echo "Utilizare: $0 nume_utilizator"
exit 1
fi

USERNAME=$1

PASSWORD=$(openssl rand -base64 6 | tr -d 'A-Z+/=')

useradd -m $USERNAME

echo "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" | chpasswd

echo "Utilizatorul '$USERNAME' a fost creat."
echo "Parola: $PASSWORD"
```

6.3

for i in {1..50}; do echo "This is mambo no. 5."; done > mambo_no_5.txt && openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -salt -in mambo_no_5.txt -out mambo_no_5.enc -k yourpassword
6.4
nano ~/.bashrc
export HISTSIZE=50
source ~/.bashrc

1

Here is my solution:
6.1
#!/bin/bash

```
sum=0
count=0

while true; do
  echo -n "Introduceți un număr (0 sau non-număr pentru a opri): "
  read num
  # Verificăm dacă inputul este un număr
  if [[ $num =~ ^-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]]; then
    if [ $num -eq 0 ]; then
      break
    fi
    sum=$(echo "$sum + $num" | bc)
    ((count++))
  else
    break
  fi
done

if [ $count -ne 0 ]; then
  average=$(echo "scale=2; $sum / $count" | bc)
  echo "Media aritmetică este: $average"
else
  echo "Nu s-au introdus numere valide."
fi
```

6.2
#!/bin/bash

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Utilizare: $0 nume_utilizator"
  exit 1
fi

username=$1

if getent passwd "$username" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  # Extragem UID-ul și shell-ul
  uid=$(getent passwd "$username" | cut -d: -f3)
  shell=$(getent passwd "$username" | cut -d: -f7)
  echo "Utilizator: $username, UID: $uid, Shell: $shell"
else
  echo "Eroare: Utilizatorul '$username' nu există."
fi
```

6.3

```
chmod +x nume_script.sh
sudo mv nume_script.sh /usr/local/bin
```

Sau cu alias

6.4

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Utilizare: $0 -u (utilizator curent) | -m (memorie liberă) | orice 
altceva (eroare)"
  exit 1
fi

case $1 in
  -u)
    echo "Utilizatorul curent este: $(whoami)"
    ;;
  -m)
    free -h | grep Mem | awk '{print "Memorie liberă: " $4}'
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Argument necunoscut. Utilizați -u pentru utilizatorul curent sau 
-m pentru memoria liberă."
    ;;
esac
```

2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).