# A variable that changes value in a bash for loop

Tags: bash, echo, increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add numbers in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348902/how-can-i-add-numbers-in-a-bash-script)

I have a variable that changes value in a for loop:

```
for i in {1..10..1}
  do
    while ((count < max+1))
      do 
        echo $count >> /directory/outfile_${max}.txt
        ((count++))
      done
    max=$max+100
  done
```

The ten outfiles should have the names "outfile_100.txt", "outfile_200.txt" etc..

But what happens is that they become like "outfile_100+100+100....txt"

Is it in how I resize `max`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to compute arithmetic expression and this will not happen with simple assignement. Use max=$(($max + 100))

Answer (score 3):

max=$max+100 is a string operation.  You're saying, "substitute the string represented by the variable $max, then take that string, and the string "+100", and assign it to the variable max."  For example, you could say:

```
max=IamSoSexy+100
```

because the shell has no types whatsoever, only strings. What you're looking for is a command that interprets its arguments as numbers.  You want:

```
let max=$max+100
```

because the "let" command does the lifting.

Answer (score 1):

Or use expr

```
max=`expr $max + 100`
```

Comment: While it "works", `expr` is a program used in ancient shell code to do math. In Posix shells like bash, use $(( expression )). In bash and ksh93, you can also use '(( expression ))' or 'let expression' if you don't need to use the result in an expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the integer attribute on `max`, so that arithmetic evaluation is performed on it automatically.

```
declare -i max
for i in {1..10..1}
do
    while ((count < max+1))
    do 
        echo $count >> /directory/outfile_${max}.txt
        ((count++))
    done
    max+=100
done
```