# How to add an integer number and a float number in a bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have two numbers:

```
value1=686
value2=228.35
```

I am not able to add an integer and a float. Please help me out to get the result.

I am running it in bash.

Comment: bc, awk, python, perl

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add numbers in a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348902/how-can-i-add-numbers-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: Korn shell 93 supports floating point.  Do you have ksh installed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
echo 1 + 3.5 | bc

awk "BEGIN {print 1+3.5; exit}"

python -c "print 1+3.5"

perl -e "print 1+3.5"
```

Just replace the numbers with your variables, eg: `echo $n1 + $n2 | bc`

Comment: thnx :)
bc language is not present on my linux machine and i dont have rights to install it asd well that was big problem.

Answer (score 10):

If you have the `bc` language installed, you can do the following:

```
#!bin/bash
numone=1.234
numtwo=0.124
total=`echo $numone + $numtwo | bc`
echo $total
```

If you don't have `bc`, then you can try with awk. Just in one single line:

```
echo 1.234 2.345 | awk '{print $1 + $2}'
```

There are plenty of other options, also. Like python, perl, php....

Comment: `bc` is a language, so it may not be installed by default. try `sudo apt-get install bc`

Comment: I dont have rights to install bc language, can we do it some other way.

Comment: echo 1.234 2.345 | awk '{print $1 + $2}'

Answer (score 5):

Bash doesn't have floating-point types, but you can use a calculator such as `bc`:

```
a=686
b=228.35
c=`echo $a + $b | bc`
echo "$c"
```

Answer (score -7):

```
 #!/bin/Bash
echo "Enter the two numbers to be added:"
read n1
read n2
answer=$(($n1+$n2))
echo $answer
```

Comment: 686+228.35: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".35")

Comment: you can also add using...   calc 686.0+228.35

Comment: This doesn't work because the bash builtin math operator `$(( ))` only supports integers math operations.