# Adding an integer and a float

Tags: bash, shell

How do I add a float and an integer in shell scripts?

For example, the following throws an error:

```
i=1; ((t=i+2.5)); echo "$t";
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo 1.234 2.345 | awk '{print $1 + $2}'`

Use awk

[Duplicate question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355229/how-to-add-an-integer-number-and-a-float-number-in-a-bash-shell-script)