# Arithmetic with numeric bash variables?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, math

I have this:

```
normal=$(find dl -type f | wc -l)
reverse=$(find dlR -type f | wc -l)
```

where both variables have numbers, but when I try to do something like this:

```
printf "$normal"+"$reverse"
```

I dont get the values summed up. What mus I do to add both variables?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348902/how-can-i-add-numbers-in-a-bash-script

Answer (score 1):

```
 printf "$((normal + reverse))\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
printf `expr $num1 + $num2`
```