# Arithmetic operation from a file using cat

Tags: shell, unix

I have written a arithmetic operation in a file, below is my input. I'm trying to assign the result into a variable by

```
c=`cat file`

c=`echo cat file`
```

But is not working, What's the correct way to do it?

```
cat file
$(($a+$b))
```

Code Snippet:

```
a=40.3
b=7.4
c='cat file`
```

Comment: `$($a + $b)` is not a shell arithmetic expression. `$(($a + $b))` (or better `$((a + b))`) would be though.

Comment: And what you are looking for here is `eval` I think though I would strongly reconsider needing to use `eval`.

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner i Have used `$(($a + $b))`, updated the question. Also tried `$((a + b))`.

Answer (score 2):

Can I assume that you've created weird artificial requirements? The file in its current form isn't usable...

If you had `c=$(($a+$b))` in the file, you could simply `source` it:

```
. ./file
echo $c    # 47
```

You could also have a script that expects two arguments, `echo $(($1+$2))`, and you could use it like this:

```
c=$(./file $a $b)
```

Comment: I Have a huge number of variables and it's difficult to pass the argumnent. But `. ./file` is rounding the values, updated the input with float values `echo $c` `#47` i want the result as 47.7

Comment: still prefer to pass them. that's how you can build bigger programs. none of the solutions rounding, *your* approach does. see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348902/how-can-i-add-numbers-in-a-bash-script