# Add and Multiply numbers using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm learning Shell scripting,  I'm trying to write a small script that adds  and multi number as shown below But amt value not display

```
value=212
amt=`expr "( $value * 2 + ( $value * 2 * .075 ) ) " | bc`
echo $amt
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add numbers in a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348902/how-can-i-add-numbers-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: That code works fine: http://ideone.com/MauwYb though I wouldn't use `expr` there since it isn't doing anything that `echo` can't do and is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, but I suggest some improvements:

1. Use `$(...)` instead of backticks.
2. Replace `expr` with `echo`.

Example:

```
value=212
amt=$(echo "( $value * 2 + ( $value * 2 * .075 ) ) " | bc)
echo $amt
```

Output:

```
455.800
```

Answer (score -1):

First things first. This:

```
value * 2 + (value * 2 * .075)
```

is a hot mess, this is equivalent:

```
value * 43 / 20
```

Next, I prefer to use awk for this job:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  value = 212
  print value * 43 / 20
}
```