# Expression as a string (shell scripting)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an expression declared as a string and I want the output to be the result of the expression. I am trying to solve it using shell scripting. 
For example

```
expr="123+456"
```

expecting output

```
579
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [arithmetic expransion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) syntax:

```
$ expr="123+456"
$ answer=$(($expr))
$ echo $answer
579
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `bc`

```
> echo "123+456" | bc
579
```

Hard to say more without more details about what you are trying to do

See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348902/how-can-i-add-numbers-in-a-bash-script) for more details about doing this only using bash

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing only in integers, bash can do it:

```
(( foo=123+456 ))
echo $foo
```

returns: 579