# Can IFS be changed locally in a Bash function?

Tags: bash, shell, local, ifs

I have a function that needs to change IFS for its logic:

```
my_func() {
  oldIFS=$IFS; IFS=.; var="$1"; arr=($var); IFS=$oldIFS
  # more logic here
}
```

Can I declare IFS as `local IFS` inside the function so that I don't need to worry about backing its current value and restore later?

Comment: why not change the value of IFS _only_ when calling your function? `IFS=. my_func "some arg"`

Comment: I don't want the caller to take that responsibility so that there is no coupling between the caller and the callee.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears to work as you desire.

```
#!/bin/bash
changeIFSlocal() {
    local IFS=.
    echo "During local: |$IFS|"
}
changeIFSglobal() {
    IFS=.
    echo "During global: |$IFS|"
}
echo "Before: |$IFS|"
changeIFSlocal
echo "After local: |$IFS|"
changeIFSglobal
echo "After global: |$IFS|"
```

This prints:

```text
Before: |
|
During local: |.|
After local: |
|
During global: |.|
After global: |.|
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes it can be defined!

As long as you define it `local`, setting of the value in the function does not affect the global `IFS` value. See the difference between the snippets below

```
addNumbers () {
    local IFS='+'
    printf "%s\n" "$(( $* ))"
}
```

when called in command-line as,

```
addNumbers 1 2 3 4 5 100
115
```

and doing

```
nos=(1 2 3 4 5 100)
echo "${nos[*]}"
```

from the command line. The `hexdump` on the above `echo` output wouldn't show the `IFS` value defined in the function

```
echo "${nos[*]}" | hexdump -c
0000000   1       2       3       4       5       1   0   0  \n
000000e
```

See in one of my answers, how I've used the localized `IFS` to do arithmetic - [How can I add numbers in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41651775/5291015)

Answer (score 3):

You can designate `IFS` as a `local` variable; the local version is still used as the field separator string.

Sometimes it is useful to run a function in a completely isolated environment, where no changes are permanent. (For example, if the function needs to change shell options.) This can be achieved by making the function run in a subshell; just change the `{}` in the function definition to `()`:

```
f() ( 
  shopt -s nullglob
  IFS=.
  # Commands to run in local environment
)
```

Comment: Nice. I didn’t know that. Is it guaranty that it will happen in a sub-process with this `f() ( …)` construction. It seems that because of some optimization Bash may apply it could not be the case every times?

Answer (score 3):

I got confused because I changed the value of IFS to `:` inside the function (without using `local`) and then tried to display the value of IFS with this command, after calling the function:

```
echo $IFS
```

which displayed an empty line that made me feel the function wasn't changing IFS.  After posting the question, I realized that word splitting was at play and I should have used

```
echo "$IFS"
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' "$IFS"
```

or, even better

```
set | grep -w IFS=
```

to accurately display the IFS value.

Coming back to the main topic of local variables, yes, any variable can be declared as `local` inside a function to limit the scope, except for variables that have been declared readonly (with `readonly` or `declare -r` builtin commands).  This includes Bash [internal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) variables like `BASH_VERSINFO` etc.

From `help local`:

> ## local: local [option] name[=value] ...
>
> ```
> Define local variables.
>
> Create a local variable called NAME, and give it VALUE.  OPTION can
> be any option accepted by `declare'.
>
> Local variables can only be used within a function; they are visible
> only to the function where they are defined and its children.
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns success unless an invalid option is supplied, a variable
> assignment error occurs, or the shell is not executing a function.
> ```

Comment: Not sure about what you mean with “accurately display the IFS value” but with printf this is the %q format specifier, and not %s, that will give you the best idea of what’s IFS:
`$ printf %q "${IFS}"` → `$' \t\n' `

`echo -n "$IFS" | cat -A` is another option but I find the first one better.

Answer (score 0):

It’s also possible to set the IFS only for one particular command, typically the *read* command. It then won’t modify the IFS variable for the following commands:

```
$ printf "%q"  "${IFS}"
$' \t\n'

$ IFS='t' read a b  < /etc/os-release ; echo $a ; echo $b
NAME="Red Ha
Enterprise Linux"

$ printf "%q"  "${IFS}"
$' \t\n'
```

While I’m here this is an occasion to tell something that I learnt far too late myself: when using Bash as a script language, and not as an interactive shell, you should consider setting the IFS with `$'\t\n'` for the whole script, whatever you could use something different locally. This is the same as the  default value, but **without the space** (ie: only tabulations and line returns will be considered as field separators). This is far more convenient IMO…