# Taking averages from a CSV file bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

So I'm having trouble taking a table of values (csv) and taking the averages of the heights and weights provided. I can display and read it, but am unsure of how exactly to store each value provided.

Heres the table - [image]

and here is my code so far -
[image]

Comment: Bash is perhaps not the best scripting language for this, but if that's the assignment...  You'll need a total variable for height and weight that are set to zero up front, and also a counter.  When the loop is over, divide the totals by the counter and that's the average.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348902/how-can-i-add-numbers-in-a-bash-script for how to keep a running total, and increment the counters.

Awk/Python/Perl would be easier than bash though, especially with non-integer arithmetic.

Comment: One more link to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-do-i-use-floating-point-division-in-bash

Comment: Post some usable for testing (ie. text) sample data with the related expected output.

Comment: [edit] your question to provide your sample input and output as plain text so we can test a potential solution against it.

Answer (score -1):

```
#! /usr/bin/sh
# get height, weight from column 4, 5

printf "Input CSV: "
read CSV
DATA_HEIGHT=$( echo $( wc -l $CSV  | cut -f1 -d" " )-1 | bc )

HEIGHT=$(
tail -n +2 $CSV | 
( while 
read line; 
do
VAR=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f4` ;
echo $VAR
done; 
) | grep -oE '[0-9]+' | paste -s -d + - | bc
)

WEIGHT=$(
tail -n +2 $CSV |
( while 
read line; 
do
VAR2=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f5` ;
echo $VAR2
done; 
) | grep -oE '[0-9]+' | paste -s -d + - | bc  
)

printf "\nHeight(in): "
echo $HEIGHT/$DATA_HEIGHT | bc
printf "Weight(lbs): "
echo $WEIGHT/$DATA_HEIGHT | bc
```