# Homework: Trying to calculate Easter using arithmetic evaluations

Tags: linux, bash

So our homework is to calculate Easter using some calculations:

```
p = v1+v2
v1 = (6*v2+m4+m2) mod 7
v2 = (16+m19 ) mod 30
m2 = 2*(year mod 4)
m4 = 4*(year mod 7)
m19 = 19*(year mod 19)
```

So these are the calculations we need to translate to Bash. This is what I have done so far with little luck:

```
 read -p year

 Am19=$(expr year%19)

 m19=$(19*(Am19))

 Am4=$(expr year%7)

 m4=$(19*(Am4))

 Am2=$(expr year%4)

 m2=$(2*(Am2))

 Av2=$(16+(m19))

 v2=$(expr Av2%30)

 Av1=$(6*(v2)+m4+m2)

 v1=$(expr Av1%7)

 p=$(v1+v2)

 echo "$p"
```

The user is supposed to input a year with the read command (like 2000)
And the program should give back the number $p I get these errors

```
main.sh: command substitution: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `Am19'
main.sh: command substitution: line 5: `19*(Am19))'
main.sh: command substitution: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `Am4'
main.sh: command substitution: line 7: `19*(Am4))'
main.sh: command substitution: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `Am2'
main.sh: command substitution: line 9: `2*(Am2))'
main.sh: command substitution: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `m19'
main.sh: command substitution: line 10: `16+(m19))'
main.sh: command substitution: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `v2'
main.sh: command substitution: line 12: `6*(v2)+m4+m2)'
main.sh: line 13: v1+v2: command not found
```

And I got no clue whats going on, Any help is always appreciated, thank you all

Comment: Have a look at http://www.shellcheck.net . Paste your code in there, and solve all it's issues.

Comment: Related to being a close duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348902

Answer (score 2):

Arithmetic expansions uses double parentheses:

```
m19=$((19*(Am19)))
```

So, if you omit the `expr`, you need to double the parentheses.

Comment: choroba, thank you friend, did what you said and the program turned out quite well but i still have errors                                                        
 main.sh: line 2: expr year % 19: syntax error in expression (error token is "year % 19")
main.sh: line 4: expr year%7: syntax error in expression (error token is "year%7")
main.sh: line 6: expr year%4: syntax error in expression (error token is "year%4")
main.sh: line 9: expr Av2%30: syntax error in expression (error token is "Av2%30")
main.sh: line 11: expr Av1%7: syntax error in expression (error token is "Av1%7")

Comment: You need to expand the variables _and_ have spaces between operators: `$(expr $year % 19)` or use bash arithmetic expansion `$((year%19)`

Comment: I did do that and had no issue when checking it on shellcheck, however the result keeps being the same number(21) This is the code so far, cant spot the issue:                                                                                                              
read -p year

Am19=$((year% 19))
m19=$((19*(Am19)))                                                                        Am4=$((year%7))
m4=$((19*(Am4)))
Am2=$((year%4))
m2=$((2*(Am2)))
Av2=$((16+(m19)))
v2=$((Av2%30))
Av1=$((6*(v2)+m4+m2))
v1=$((Av1%7))
p=$((v1+v2))
echo "$p"

Comment: Ask a new question if you have a new question.