# Count the number of words for each contributor

Tags: github, repository

How can I count the number of words that each contributor wrote in a repository ?

Comment: By trying to count them and then asking here when you have a concrete problem? What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: number of commits? number of lines added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best solved on a local clone of that GitHub, in order to analyze the git log and check each contributor.

See "[getting contributor stats](http://codeimpossible.com/2011/12/16/Stupid-Git-Trick-getting-contributor-stats/)", based on:

```
git log --author="Jared Barboza" --pretty=tformat: --numstat | \
grep -v public/javascripts/jquery | \
gawk '{ add += $1 ; subs += $2 ; loc += $1 - $2 } END \
{ printf "added lines: %s removed lines : %s total lines: %s\n",add,subs,loc }' -
```

But that is for lines added/removed for a given contributor.

(a bit like in "[Git: How to estimate a contribution of a person to my project in terms of added/changed lines of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592866/git-how-to-estimate-a-contribution-of-a-person-to-my-project-in-terms-of-added)")

You can combined a similar approach with the one described in "[Quantifying the amount of change in a git diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874318/quantifying-the-amount-of-change-in-a-git-diff)".
Or you can use a dedicated program for that, like **[git-wordcount](https://github.com/huitseeker/git-wordcount)**.