# Showing Words Added to a file

Tags: git

How can one show the **words added** to a file between two commits (say `HEAD` vs `HEAD^`)?

`git diff` seems to show "additions", which I believe are defined as **lines added**. But this is not as useful when you are marking up written text in a git repository.

Answer (score 2):

Try

`git diff --color-words HEAD HEAD^`

From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

> `--word-diff-regex=<regex>`
>
> Use  to decide what a word is, instead of considering runs of non-whitespace to be a word. Also implies `--word-diff` unless it was already enabled.
>
> Every non-overlapping match of the  is considered a word. Anything between these matches is considered whitespace and ignored(!) for the purposes of finding differences. You may want to append `|[^[:space:]]` to your regular expression to make sure that it matches all non-whitespace characters. A match that contains a newline is silently truncated(!) at the newline.
>
> For example, `--word-diff-regex=.` will treat each character as a word and, correspondingly, show differences character by character.
>
> The regex can also be set via a diff driver or configuration option, see gitattributes[5] or git-config[1]. Giving it explicitly overrides any diff driver or configuration setting. Diff drivers override configuration settings.
>
> `--color-words[=<regex>]`
> Equivalent to `--word-diff=color` plus (if a regex was specified) `--word-diff-regex=<regex>.`

Check out a longer description of other suggestions for more powerful diffs [here](http://oli.jp/2012/git-powerup/#diff)

Comment: This is great -- but is there a way to show the total number of words added/deleted rather than just exposing the changes visually?

Comment: I'm sure that could be hacked together. Sounds like it'd be worth opening a new question for that...

Comment: Actually, take a look at this question and answer that does exactly that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874318

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question, correctly, you are looking for a way to diff two commits which would show differences on a word level, rather than just a line level.

To do that you could use an appropriate external diff tool, e.g. `kdiff3`, that can handle showing differences of parts of a line. `kdiff3` will highlight every character difference.

There are other answers on StackOverflow that detail how to set up a diff tool in git. For example [Git: How configure KDiff3 as merge tool and diff tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308482/git-how-configure-kdiff3-as-merge-tool-and-diff-tool)