# Get just the integer from wc in bash

Tags: bash, wc

Is there a way to get the integer that wc returns in bash?

Basically I want to write the line numbers and word counts to the screen after the file name.

`output: filename linecount wordcount`
Here is what I have so far:

```
files=\`ls`
for f in $files;
do
        if [ ! -d $f ] #only print out information about files !directories
        then
                # some way of getting the wc integers into shell variables and then printing them
                echo "$f $lines $words"
        fi
done
```

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: ...it would be far more reliable to write `for f in *; do` and skip `$files` entirely. If you want to store a list of filenames, the correct data structure is an _array_: `files=( * ); for f in "${files[@]}"; do if [ ! -d "$f" ]; then ...` -- note the quotes, they're important; if you run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and follow the links in the warnings it throws, they go to wiki pages explaining why.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use the [`cut`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/) command to get just the first word of `wc`'s output (which is the line or word count):

```
lines=`wc -l $f | cut -f1 -d' '`
words=`wc -w $f | cut -f1 -d' '`
```

Comment: Running wc twice for the same file is inefficient.

Comment: True, that's why I think James Broadhead's answer is much better. I couldn't get `cut` to work on the full output of `wc $f` because the number of spaces between fields varies.

Comment: @casablanca You can squeeze the number of spaces using 'tr -s'. I have listed more portable solutions to this question in my answer below.

Answer (score 100):

Most simple answer ever:

```
wc < filename
```

Comment: But doesn't produce the desired output.

Comment: sure it does, you just pass in the proper parameters that you would anyway. for example, if you do `wc -c < file name`, it will give you just the integer number of bytes and nothing else.

Comment: My point was that if you're going to answer a (1.5 yr-old) question) might as well put all the info into the answer, that's all :)

Comment: whoops, just re-read the question.. #fail, i was researching how to get *just* the integers, and i was using information from one of the answers, when i discovered a better answer, and then decided to post about it. sorry..

Comment: The only trickiness to this approach is that if you want to quiesce the error channel, you have to do it before the input, like so: `wc -l 2>/dev/null < /path/to/filename`. You can't redirect the error channel at the end of the pipeline like this usually: `wc -l < /path/to/filename 2>/dev/null`. This is a crucial difference in how you use this approach, especially if you use this in a script and might not always have a valid filename.

Answer (score 94):

Just:

```
wc -l < file_name
```

will do the job. But this output includes prefixed whitespace as `wc` right-aligns the number.

Comment: To get just line count without whitespace: `wc -l < foo.txt | xargs` ref - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973694/149428

Comment: So, while the command produces an answer with leading spaces, the questioner was assigning to a variable and that drops the leading spaces automatically (at least that was my experience on the older OSX bash). In other words, `lines=\`wc -l < $f\``
results in a variable "line" whose value has no leading spaces.

Comment: What if I'm piping with with find? I get an error: 
`find . -path -prune -o -name "*.swift" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l` works ok but prints every file. If I use `find . -path -prune -o -name "*.swift" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l <` I get an error. `parse error near '\n'`

Comment: @cycollins, whether spaces are dropped depends on the current value of `IFS`; it's not reliable behavior.

Answer (score 59):

Sometimes wc outputs in different formats in different platforms. For example:

**In OS X:**

```
$ echo aa | wc -l

         1
```

**In Centos:**

```
$ echo aa | wc -l

1
```

So using only cut may not retrieve the number. Instead try `tr` to delete space characters:

```
$ echo aa | wc -l | tr -d ' '
```

Comment: This answer works cross-platform, is concise, and above all, correctly addresses the full question, formatting included. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does not work on OSX, please check @rouble version.

Answer (score 57):

```
wc $file | awk {'print "$4" "$2" "$1"'}
```

Adjust as necessary for your layout.

It's also nicer to use positive logic ("is a file") over negative ("not a directory")

```
[ -f $file ] && wc $file | awk {'print "$4" "$2" "$1"'}
```

Comment: On my Windows in Cmder (bash 4.4.12) this works: `wc $file | awk '{print $4" "$2" "$1}'` -- apostrophes outside of `{}`.

Answer (score 36):

The accepted/popular answers do **not** work on OSX.

Any of the following should be portable on bsd and linux.

```
wc -l < "$f" | tr -d ' '
```

OR

```
wc -l "$f" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

OR

```
wc -l "$f" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Indeed. This answer really works cross-platform. Testes on OSX, bsd, debian and Ubuntu. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

If you redirect the filename into `wc` it omits the filename on output.

Bash:

```
read lines words characters <<< $(wc < filename)
```

or

```
read lines words characters <<EOF
$(wc < filename)
EOF
```

Instead of using `for` to iterate over the output of `ls`, do this:

```
for f in *
```

which will work if there are filenames that include spaces.

If you can't use globbing, you should pipe into a `while read` loop:

```
find ... | while read -r f
```

or use process substitution

```
while read -r f
do
    something
done < <(find ...)
```

Comment: I upvoted you anyway, but you don't need to redirect the filename. Just capture it as an additional field. `read lines words characters filename <<< $(wc "$f")` Oh, and if you used * to be hardened against spaces, you also want to double quote the var when you use it.

Comment: Using an additional variable is indeed another way to do it, but if you're not going to use the variable (perhaps you already have the filename in a variable - `$f` in this case), it's unnecessary. Also, the OP asked for how to get *just* the integer. You are correct about quoting a variable, but I didn't show the use of the variable, so I omitted mentioning that point. The `for f in *` form should almost always be used instead of using the output of `ls`, as you know.

Comment: I completely agree on the `ls` point. That'll get you an award. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#ls

Comment: If you don't want the filename, you could do this: `read lines words characters _ <<< $(wc "$f")`

Comment: @EvanTeitelman: As discussed in a couple of the comments above yours. `$_` is just a different variable.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: `$_` is often used as a sort of sink variable since its contents are overwritten by bash after every command. Using it avoids having to create a new variable.

Answer (score 3):

If the file is small you can afford calling `wc` twice, and use something like the following, which avoids piping into an extra process:

```
lines=$((`wc -l "$f"`))
words=$((`wc -w "$f"`))
```

The `$((...))` is the [Arithmetic Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) of bash. It removes any whitespace from the output of `wc` in this case.

This solution makes more sense if you need **either** the linecount **or** the wordcount.

Answer (score 2):

How about with `sed`?

```
wc -l /path/to/file.ext | sed 's/ *\([0-9]* \).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typeset -i a=$(wc -l fileName.dat  | xargs echo | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for numeric result:
nlines=$( wc -l < $myfile )

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf '%-10s %-10s %-10s\n' 'File' 'Lines' 'Words'
for fname in file_name_pattern*; {
    [[ -d $fname ]] && continue
    lines=0
    words=()
    while read -r line; do
        ((lines++))
        words+=($line)
    done < "$fname"
    printf '%-10s %-10s %-10s\n' "$fname" "$lines" "${#words[@]}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To (1) run `wc` once, and (2) not assign any superfluous variables, use

```
read lines words <<< $(wc < $f | awk '{ print $1, $2 }')
```

---

Full code:

```
for f in *
do
    if [ ! -d $f ]
    then
        read lines words <<< $(wc < $f | awk '{ print $1, $2 }')
        echo "$f $lines $words"
    fi
done
```

---

Example output:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec wc {} \; # without formatting
 1  2 27 ./CNAME
  21  169 1065 ./LICENSE
 33 130 961 ./README.md
  86  215 2997 ./404.html
  71  168 2579 ./index.html
 21  21 478 ./sitemap.xml

$ # the above code
404.html 86 215
CNAME 1 2
index.html 71 168
LICENSE 21 169
README.md 33 130
sitemap.xml 21 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions proposed in the *answered* question doesn't work for Darwin kernels.

Please, consider following solutions that work for all UNIX systems:

1. print exactly the number of lines of a file:

```
wc -l < file.txt | xargs
```

2. print exactly the number of characters of a file:

```
wc -m < file.txt | xargs
```

3. print exactly the number of bytes of a file:

```
wc -c < file.txt | xargs
```

4. print exactly the number of words of a file:

```
wc -w < file.txt | xargs
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the kernel -- whether you have a BSD version of `wc` or a GNU version of `wc` is completely unrelated to the OS kernel providing the syscalls used by `wc` to perform I/O operations. If you ran GNU `wc` on Linux, you'd have the same behavior as GNU `wc` on Darwin; likewise, if you compiled Apple's `wc` on Linux, it would behave the same way it does on Darwin.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great solution with examples on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53177403/2031849)

I will copy the simplest solution here:

```
FOO="bar"
echo -n "$FOO" | wc -l | bc                     # "3"
```

Maybe these pages should be merged?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
wc `ls` | awk '{ LINE += $1; WC += $2 } END { print "lines: " LINE  " words: " WC }'
```

It creates a line count, and word count (LINE and WC), and increase them with the values extracted from wc (using $1 for the first column's value and $2 for the second) and finally prints the results.

Answer (score -1):

> *"Basically I want to write the line numbers and word counts to the screen after the file name."*

```
answer=(`wc $f`)
echo -e"${answer[3]}
lines:  ${answer[0]}
words:  ${answer[1]}
bytes:  ${answer[2]}"
```

Outputs :
    myfile.txt
    lines:  10
    words:  20
    bytes:  120

Comment: Don't use the `-e` argument to `echo` without a _very_ good reason -- [POSIX outright disallows it](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), and consequently, major shells can be configured to turn it off (or don't treat it as anything other than an instruction to print the string `-e` by default).

Comment: Moreover, you don't need `-e` here at all -- your newlines are literal to start with, so you don't need any transformation from the two-character `\n` sequence to the single-character newline in the first place. And beyond that, not having any space between the `-e` and the opening quotes make behavior _very_ much undefined.

Comment: (and beyond _that_, performing an unquoted expansion introduces a bunch of unnecessary variables into this software's reliability -- f/e, if the filename contains spaces, then `${answer[3]}` will have only the first part of it; or if the first part of the filename can be expanded as a glob, you can get a list of other filenames in your current directory in its place -- consider the file created with `touch '* READ ME FIRST *'`).

Answer (score -1):

```
files=`ls`
echo "$files" | wc -l | perl -pe "s#^\s+##"
```

Comment: If you are using `perl` anyway, might as well do the word count in Perl too. A more economical approach would be to pipe to `tr -d '[:space:]'`

Answer (score -1):

You have to use input redirection for `wc`:

```
number_of_lines=$(wc -l <myfile.txt)
```

respectively in your context

```
echo "$f $(wc -l <"$f") $(wc -w <"$f")"
```