# How to get "wc -l" to print just the number of lines without file name?

Tags: shell, wc

```
wc -l file.txt
```

outputs number of lines and file name.

I need just the number itself (not the file name).

I can do this

```
 wc -l file.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

But maybe there is a better way?

Comment: `wc -l < file.txt` does the job precisely and concisely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get just the integer from wc in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746947/get-just-the-integer-from-wc-in-bash)

Comment: This is a question I've looked up twice now. This behavior of wc is unintuitive and anti-paradigmatic for -nix  usual terseness. That terseness is there for a reason, because you *exactly do not* want to work around all kinds of fluffy redundancy. After all, I *know* the file name, don't I? What I want is the line count.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica You can run `wc` with multiple arguments (`wc -l *.txt) in which case you will get a line for each file and need to distinguish them.

Answer (score 318, accepted):

Try this way:

```
wc -l < file.txt
```

Comment: In AIX,ksh, this will always have a space preceeding the number. We have to use | awk '{print $1}' or a cut, to trim off the spaces. Another way to trim would be to enclose with an echo.

Comment: @rao is correct, this will add a space before the number. My solution solves this and is simpler than awk or cut.

Comment: @rao There is no space with bash. Where does the space come from in ksh? `wc -l` should not emit one, and why would ksh prepend the standard output of a program with a space?

Comment: While this is the correct workaround (and it is easy enough that wc never got amended), it likely is slower and unintuitive. For one, I'd expect  something like `4711 [stdin]` as the output.

Comment: Also consider pairing with `printf "%'d"`, which takes care of the space and prints out large numbers nicely.

Comment: Can someone explain why this works? What is the `<` doing?

Comment: @rao Interesting. Where does the space come from?

Answer (score 34):

```
cat file.txt | wc -l
```

According to [the man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/wc/) (for the BSD version, I don't have a GNU version to check):

> If no files are specified, the standard input is used and no file
>   name is
>        displayed.  The prompt will accept input until receiving EOF, or [^D] in
>        most environments.

Comment: I don't like cat - concatenation consumes to much time.

Comment: `wc -l < file.txt` has the same effect.

Comment: @user: Test it. By far the slowest part will be reading the file off disk.

Answer (score 23):

To do this without the leading space, why not:

```
wc -l < file.txt | bc
```

Answer (score 18):

## Comparison of Techniques

I had a similar issue attempting to get a character count without the leading whitespace provided by `wc`, which led me to this page. After trying out the answers here, the following are the results from my personal testing on Mac (BSD Bash). Again, this is for character count; for line count you'd do `wc -l`. `echo -n` omits the trailing line break.

```
FOO="bar"
echo -n "$FOO" | wc -c                          # "       3"    (x)
echo -n "$FOO" | wc -c | bc                     # "3"           (√)
echo -n "$FOO" | wc -c | tr -d ' '              # "3"           (√)
echo -n "$FOO" | wc -c | awk '{print $1}'       # "3"           (√)
echo -n "$FOO" | wc -c | cut -d ' ' -f1         # "" for -f < 8 (x)
echo -n "$FOO" | wc -c | cut -d ' ' -f8         # "3"           (√)
echo -n "$FOO" | wc -c | perl -pe 's/^\s+//'    # "3"           (√)
echo -n "$FOO" | wc -c | grep -ch '^'           # "1"           (x)
echo $( printf '%s' "$FOO" | wc -c )            # "3"           (√)
```

I wouldn't rely on the `cut -f*` method in general since it requires that you know the exact number of leading spaces that any given output may have. And the `grep` one works for counting lines, but not characters.

`bc` is the most concise, and `awk` and `perl` seem a bit overkill, but they should all be relatively fast and portable enough.

Also note that some of these can be adapted to trim surrounding whitespace from general strings, as well (along with `` echo `echo $FOO` ``, another neat trick).

Comment: `echo $(printf '%s' "$FOO" | wc -c)` is one of the rare occasions when [`echo` with a command subshitution](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) isn't useless.

Comment: @tripleee Whoa... based on your code, `echo \`echo $FOO\`;` also acts like a String.trim() command on a variable! That's amazingly handy. I'll also add your line to my answer.

Comment: Perhaps for context see also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](/q/10067266)

Comment: ... as well as [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 12):

How about

```
wc -l file.txt | cut -d' ' -f1
```

i.e. pipe the output of `wc` into `cut` (where delimiters are spaces and pick just the first field)

Comment: this isn't any better than the `wc -l file.txt | awk '{print $1}'` OP tried.

Comment: Faster than the `wc -l < file.txt` method. But must use `| cut -d' ' -f2` on BSD, as long as the `wc` command returns a leading space, example:  " 34068289 file.txt", instead of "34068289 file.txt".

Comment: @doubleDown well, using awk is like using a CNC machine to cut a board instead of a saw. Use a saw for sawing.

Comment: This will not work on a Mac (BSD based). The number of leading spaces depends on the padding, so the field value will depend on the result. One of the solutions above will be much better.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: Why would this be faster than the input redirection method?

Comment: @einpoklum I don't know why, but on my FreeBSD v10 the test was faster . Maybe the piping is a more efficient way than input redirection due to avoid disk usage, at least on big files.

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
grep -ch "^" file.txt
```

Comment: Nice. Very original/creative use of `grep` but checking this it turns out (unsurprisingly) to be 2x to 6x slower than the simpler/straightforward `wc` method in my tests.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to strip the leading zeros without invoking an external command is to use *Arithmetic expansion* `$((exp))`

```
echo $(($(wc -l < file.txt)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, there are a lot of solutions to this.
Here is another one though:

`wc -l somefile | tr -d "[:alpha:][:blank:][:punct:]"`

This only outputs the number of lines, but the trailing newline character (`\n`) is present, if you don't want that either, replace `[:blank:]` with `[:space:]`.

Comment: This has the issue when the file name has a number in it. For example for the file `test9` with 1 line in it, the output will be 19.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be first of all find all files in directory then use AWK NR (Number of Records Variable)

below is the command :

```
find <directory path>  -type f | awk  'END{print NR}'
```

example : -  `find /tmp/ -type f | awk  'END{print NR}'`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using the normal `wc -l` and `sed` to strip any char what is not a number.

```sh
wc -l big_file.log | sed -E "s/([a-z\-\_\.]|[[:space:]]*)//g"

# 9249133
```