# awk shell parameter FILENAME vs ARGV

Tags: shell, awk

Trying to solve this question [append wc...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843165/append-wc-lines-to-filename/41844980?noredirect=1#comment70881383_41844980) I cannot understand how to catch filename passed as argument to awk command.

```
awk 'BEGIN {for ( i=1;i<ARGC;i++ )print "ARGV " i ": [" ARGV[i] "]" }
     FNR==1 {print "FILENAME " ++a ": [" FILENAME "]" }
    ' $( ls )
```

work fine for *standard* file name like `file1.txt` but problem arise with spaced file name lile `file with space` (in fact certainly when file name contains $IFS character and IFS is not to be touch). FILENAME is OK, ARGV separate on space (quoted or not) like if parsed all parameter as one string after shell pass it.

I use this to count file lines even if file is empty (so never reach the FNR == 1 ) but it's not the question here.

So

1. how should i format spaced character (i try to surround via sed with quote like `$( ls | sed "s/'/'\"'\"'/g;s/.*/'&'/")` but did'nt help)
2. how to catch spaced value via ARGV

I use awk on linux and AIX (and not gawk in this case :-( )

some sample

```
#ls -1 file*
file
file and space
file'qu .txt
file"qu .txt

# awk '...' "file and space"
ARGV 1: [file and space]
FILENAME 1: [file and space]

# awk '...' $( ls file* | sed -e 's/ /?/g' )
ARGV 1: [file]
ARGV 2: [file and space]
ARGV 3: [file'qu .txt]
ARGV 4: [file"qu .txt]
FILENAME 1: [file]
FILENAME 2: [file and space]
FILENAME 3: [file'qu .txt]
```

last ls show that awk COULD make the difference ( *file"qu .txt* is an empty file so is FNR==1 never reach).

I see now that this is at shell passing info level, not awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem is not related to `awk`, but to the *shell* (how you pass the filenames):**

Unquoted command substitution `$( ls )` will expand to a list of filenames, but **the filenames are subject to word-splitting**, so that filenames with embedded spaces are each broken into *multiple* arguments passed to `awk`.

This results in `awk` seeing either *nonexistent* filenames (at which point a fatal error occurs) or accidentally processing *different* files (multiple times); e.g., if files `file one`, `file` and `one` all exist in the current directory, `awk` will *not* process `file one`, and instead process both `file` and `one` *twice*.

**A simple glob (`*`) will do** in this case, whose expansion results are *not* subject to work-splitting, and is generally preferable to parsing `ls` output:

```
awk 'BEGIN {for ( i=1;i<ARGC;i++ )print "ARGV " i ": [" ARGV[i] "]" }
     FNR==1 {print "FILENAME " ++a ": [" FILENAME "]" }
    ' *
```

**Using an unquoted command substitution to expand to multiple arguments passed to a command (`command $(...)`) is an anti-pattern in general**, because the resulting output is subject not only to word-splitting, but also to *globbing* (filename expansion), as part of the so-called [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html).

---

**Diagnosing** the problem:

```
$ touch file 'file 1'
$ bash -s - $(ls file 'file 1') <<<'echo "$# args passed: [$1] [$2] [$3]"'
3 args passed: [file] [file] [1]
```

Note how, even though `file 1` was passed with quotes, the target command (an ad-hoc bash script) sees *3* arguments, as a result of the shell having broken `file 1` into separate arguments `file` and `1` (word-splitting), due to unquoted use of `$(...)` (command substitution).
(Note that `"$(...)"` wouldn't have helped, because the command output is then invariably passed as a *single* argument.)

The following simplified command causes `awk` to  *fail fundamentally*, because instead of seeing single filename `File One`, it sees filenames `File` and `One`, neither of which exist:

```
$ rm -f File One; echo 'hi from File One' > 'File One'
$ awk '{ print FILENAME }' $(ls 'File One')
awk: fatal: cannot open file `File' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

The above is *GNU* `awk`'s error message; BSD Awk and Mawk fundamentally behave the same, except for variations in the wording of the error message. All these implementations set the exit code to `2` in this scenario.

Comment: if you want to print a space in between words, just say `print a, b` --> `print "FILENAME", ++a, ...`

Comment: understand but why FILENAME is thus correct in this case (with a spaced name). If it is purely shell  expansion, FILENAME will received several *bad* file names ?

Comment: @fedorqui problem is not the print, I use it to show the problem when inside the code. I use something like `Files[ ARGV[i]]++` in BEGIN section for catching empty files. this is where my problem appear

Comment: @NeronLeVelu yes I know, it was just a side note since I did see a hardcoded space `print "a ", b` and I think `print "a", b` looks better. Nothing worth worrying about.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu It is simply impossible for awk or any other command to recognize an unquoted file name with spaces in it as a single argument. It sounds like you might have a question worth posting as a new question on the site.

Comment: @EdMorton: I concur - a command would have to go out of its way to rebuild a single argument from individual arguments, which would seem misguided, and it's certainly not what `awk` should do - I'm mystified by the OP's claim.

Comment: @EdMorton and @mklement0 see last info in OP. awk DO the difference if file is passed as parameter directly (like `"spa ce"` or `spa*`) but not after a `$()` that return a single string that awk parse by space inside

Comment: forget my last comment. I agree your info, i try just to find a way to recreate a shell interprestation after the $() occur to reseparate the argument at shell levell before awk catch them

Answer (score 1):

Would that work in your specific shell?

```
declare -a files=(*)
awk 'BEGIN {for ( i=1;i<ARGC;i++ )print "ARGV " i ": [" ARGV[i] "]" }
     FNR==1 {print "FILENAME " ++a ": [" FILENAME "]" }
    ' "${files[@]}"
```

The array expansion should too, sidestepping your issue, hopefully.

Comment: using an array is also a way to separate argument at shell level, thanks