# Output number of lines in a text file to screen in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bash echo number of lines of file given in a bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022319/bash-echo-number-of-lines-of-file-given-in-a-bash-variable)

Was wondering how you output the number of lines in a text file to screen and then store it in a variable.
I have a file called stats.txt and when I run `wc -l stats.txt` it outputs `8 stats.txt`

I tried doing `x = wc -l stats.txt` thinking it would store the number only and the rest is just for visual but it does not work :(

Thanks for the help

Comment: How about `x=$(wc -l <stats.txt)`?

Comment: A bash tutorial may help you: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/

Answer (score 18):

There are two POSIX standard syntax for doing this:

```
x=`cat stats.txt | wc -l`
```

or

```
x=$(cat stats.txt | wc -l)
```

They both run the program and replace the invocation in the script with the standard output of the command, in this case assigning it to the `$x` variable. However, be aware that both trim ending newlines (this is actually what you want here, but can be dangerous sometimes, when you expect a newline).

Also, the second case can be easily nested (example: `$(cat $(ls | head -n 1) | wc -l)`). You can also do it with the first case, but it is more complex:

```
`cat \`ls | head -n 1\` | wc -l`
```

There are also quotation issues. You can include these expressions inside double-quotes, but with the back-ticks, you must continue quoting inside the command, while using the parenthesis allows you to "start a new quoting" group:

```
"`echo \"My string\"`"
"$(echo "My string")"
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: There's no need for 'cat' or any redirection/pipes - just do : x=$(wc -l /path/to/file.txt)

Answer (score 3):

you may try:

```
x=`cat stats.txt | wc -l`
```

or (from the another.anon.coward's comment):

```
x=`wc -l < stats.txt`
```

Comment: You can do it w/o `cat` & pipe as `x=$(wc -l <stats.txt)`

Comment: @gokcehan when I ran it ---- cat coursefile.txt | wc -l -----it worked. however when I tried to store it I got an error : -bash: x: command not found

Comment: don't forget the backticks (``)

Comment: @gokcehan I used the backquotes/backticks and it did not work, using bash shell if it helps

Comment: I can run it on my bash. what's the error you have?