# Bash: Using Number of Lines in File in Variable

Tags: bash, wc

I am trying to extract the number of lines from a file, and then use it in a variable. However, it keeps passing the file name, not the number of lines. I read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022319/bash-echo-number-of-lines-of-file-given-in-a-bash-variable), but the examples are not working.

```
for i in $BASE/$TEMPLATE_DIR-$i$PRUNING_METHOD/*.txt
    do
        NUM_LINES=$(wc -l < $i)
        echo $NUM_LINES
        UPLOAD_CMD="sh sshpass_setup_verification.sh $EXP_ID-$i$PRUNING_METHOD__$NUM_LINES__features";
        echo "$UPLOAD_CMD"
        break 1;
    done
```

Prints:

```
15 #the correct number of lines
sh sshpass_setup_verification.sh di-60sec-max/TemplateUser1.txt #where TemplateUser1.txt is the name of the file
```

Should print:

```
15
sh sshpass_setup_verification.sh di-60sec-max__15__features
```

Comment: Use `${NUM_LINES}` (with the curlies) in your `echo` statement. Otherwise, Bash thinks you mean the variable named `NUM_LINES__features` which isn't set and expands to nothing.

Comment: `....${EXP_ID}-${i}${PRUNING_METHOD}__${NUM_LINES}__features`. Since `_` is a valid character in a variable name, and you don't actually have a `NUM_LINES__features` variable defined... Just get in the habit of always using braces (and always quoting, and ...)...

Comment: It's now putting a space in, like this: `sh sshpass_setup_verification.sh di-60sec-best-test2-1-max__ 822__features`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A summary of what people are telling you in the comments:

```
for i in "${BASE}/${TEMPLATE_DIR}-${i}${PRUNING_METHOD}"/*.txt
do
    num_lines=$(wc -l < "$i")
    echo "$num_lines"
    upload_cmd="sh sshpass_setup_verification.sh ${EXP_ID}-${i}${PRUNING_METHOD}__${num_lines}__features"
    echo "$upload_cmd"
    break
done
```

The key thing here is using double quotes around your parameter expansions and curly braces to disambiguate in situations where characters such as `_` could be interpreted as part of a variable name but shouldn't. I've added them in several places where they aren't strictly needed but they do no harm.

I've also changed your variable names to lowercase. This will help you one day when you decide to have a variable called `PATH` and suddenly all your commands stop working.

Comment: This is still adding spaces before the `num_lines` value

Comment: @Adam_G I forgot to change `NUM_LINES` to `num_lines` in the command (but not sure that was the problem). Is it definitely that variable with a space in front of it? What does `declare -p num_lines` tell you??

Comment: Weird. It has a huge space in it: `declare -- num_lines="     822"`. Any idea why this got added, and how to trim it out?

Comment: @Adam_G I'm not sure where it came from, but there are many ways to trim it out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/369758/2088135 - in this case, as you want to remove all space characters, you could just use `${num_lines// /}`.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Could you explain what the double and single backslash do?

Comment: The syntax `${var//a/b}` means "replace all occurrences of a with b". Here, we're replacing all spaces with nothing.

Comment: Ahh, right. I just didn't recognize it with the empty string. Thank you again.