# Why does bash return the file directory when using a back tick?

Tags: bash, syntax, backticks

I'm running this series of commands

```
passwd=`wc -l /etc/passwd`

echo $passwd
```

Returns:

```
34 /etc/passwd
```

What do I need to do to this so that it will only show the output of `wc -l`?

Comment: passwd=$(cat /etc/passwd|wc -l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk` perhaps ?

```
$ passwd=$(wc -l /etc/passwd | awk '{print $1}')
$ echo $passwd
32
```

Using `cut`, from `cut (GNU coreutils)`

```
$ passwd=$(wc -l /etc/passwd | cut -d" " -f1)
$ echo $passwd
32
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read from standard input instead of giving `wc` a file name:

```
$ passwd=`wc -l < /etc/passwd`
$ echo "$passwd"
      86
```

`wc` still outputs quite a bit of padding, but the file name is omitted (because `wc` has no idea what file the data comes from).

Answer (score 0):

That's the default behaviour of `wc`:

```
» wc -l /etc/passwd                                     
28 /etc/passwd
```

There is no way to tell wc not to output the filename.

Answer (score 0):

`wc` returns also the filename, but there are other ways to do it. Some examples:

```
passwd=`wc -l /etc/passwd | grep -o [1-9]\*`
```

or

```
passwd=`wc -l /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d' '`
```

(answer from this question: [get just the integer from wc in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746947/get-just-the-integer-from-wc-in-bash))