# String expansion in bash with embedded quotes

Tags: bash, shell, expansion, subshell

**Problem:**

The following shell script code does not produce the expected result:

```
# MYSQL, MyUSER MyHost etc ... all defined above as normal

TARG_DB="zztest";
DB_CREATE="$($MYSQL -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS -Bse 'create database $TARG_DB')";
```

**Expected outcome:**

A new database created with the name `zztest`

**Actual outcome:**

A new database created with the name `$TARG_DB`

**Question:**

How can this example code be changed such that `$TARG_DB` is interpolated or expanded, giving the expected outcome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `$TARG_DB` is within single quotes within the subshell, it's taken literally. Use double quotes there, they won't mess up the subshell. e.g.

```
$ tmp="a b c"
$ echo $tmp
a b c
$ echo $(echo $tmp)
a b c
$ echo $(echo "$tmp")
a b c
$ echo $(echo '$tmp')
$tmp
$ echo "$(echo '$tmp')"
$tmp
$ echo "$(echo "$tmp")"
a b c
```

Comment: Great answer, direct: with examples. Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, Stack Overflow misinterprets the quotes (making the answer misleading) while a decent editor knows about the command substitution and highlights it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Don't wrap it in single-quotes.

There is no need to quote the command substitution `$()` so you can remove those and use double-quotes inside it.

```
DB_CREATE=$($MYSQL -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS -Bse "create database $TARG_DB");
```

Comment: Is this indeed true, that there is no difference between VAR="$(...)" and VAR=$(...) in bash?

Comment: @macieksk It is NOT true.  The entire RHS of the assignment expression should be wrapped in double quotes.  It won't matter that another double-quoted string exists in the content; bash doesn't delimit nested strings in the same way as an imperative programming language.

Comment: @JoeCoder it is 100% true when we are talking about `$( )`.  Per https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html *”When using the $(command) form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.”*

Comment: @SiegeX I meant in the outer context of being the RHS of an assignment statement.  However I was wrong in thinking that string splitting or globbing was a concern, it turns out that is not the casee (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50528429/159570).  No quotes necessary on RHS of simple assignment expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
TARG_DB="zztest";
DB_CREATE="$(${MYSQL} -u ${MyUSER} -h ${MyHOST} -p${MyPASS} -Bse \"create database ${TARG_DB}\")";
```

Comment: Because it's within a subshell, you don't even need to escape the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The `'create database $TARG_DB'` part is wrong! Single quotes supress variable substitution in bash. MySQL "sees" the literal text "$TARG_DB" and creates a database with that name. Put your sql statement in double quotes.