# How to address error "bash: !d': event not found" in Bash command substitution

Tags: bash, parsing, sed, command-substitution

I am attempting to parse the output of a VNC server startup event and have run into a problem in parsing using sed in a command substitution. Specifically, the remote VNC server is started in a manner such as the following:

```
address1="user1@lxplus.cern.ch"
VNCServerResponse="$(ssh "${address1}" 'vncserver' 2>&1)"
```

The standard error output produced in this startup event is then to be parsed in order to extract the server and display information. At this point the content of the variable `VNCServerResponse` is something such as the following:

```
New 'lxplus0186.cern.ch:1 (user1)' desktop is lxplus0186.cern.ch:1

Starting applications specified in /afs/cern.ch/user/u/user1/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /afs/cern.ch/user/u/user1/.vnc/lxplus0186.cern.ch:1.log
```

This output can be parsed in the following way in order to extract the server and display information:

```
echo "${VNCServerResponse}" | sed '/New.*desktop.*is/!d' \
    | awk -F" desktop is " '{print $2}'
```

The result is something such as the following:

```
lxplus0186.cern.ch:1
```

What I want to do is use this parsing in a command substitution something like the following:

```
VNCServerAndDisplayNumber="$(echo "${VNCServerResponse}" \
    | sed '/New.*desktop.*is/!d' | awk -F" desktop is " '{print $2}')"
```

On attempting to do this, I am presented with the following error:

```
bash: !d': event not found
```

I am not sure how to address this. It appears to be a problem in the way sed is being used in the command substitution. I would appreciate guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that within double quotes, bash is trying to expand `!d` before passing it to the subshell. You can get around this problem by removing the double quotes but I would also propose a simplification to your script:

```
VNCServerAndDisplayNumber=$(echo "$VNCServerResponse" | awk '/desktop/ {print $NF}')
```

This simply prints the last field on the line containing the word "desktop".

On a newer bash, you can use a herestring rather than piping an `echo`:

```
VNCServerAndDisplayNumber=$(awk '/desktop/ {print $NF}' <<<"$VNCServerResponse")
```

Answer (score 13):

Bash history expansion is a very odd corner in the bash command line parser, and you are clearly running into an unexpected history expansion, which is explained below. However, any sort of history expansion in a script is unexpected, because normally history expansion is not enabled in scripts; not even scripts run with the `source` (or `.`) builtin.

## How history expansion is enabled (or disabled)

There are two shell options which control history expansion:

- `set -o history`: Required for the history to be recorded.
- `set -H` (or `set -o histexpand`): Additionally required for history expansion to be enabled.

Both of these options must be set for history expansion to be recognized. (I found the manual unclear on this interaction, but it's logical enough.)

According to the bash manual, these options are unset for non-interactive shells, so if you want to enable history expansion in a script (and I cannot imagine a reason you would want this), you would need to set both of them:

```
set -o history -o histexpand
```

The situation for scripts run with `source` is more complicated (and what I'm about to say only applies to bash v4, and since it's undocumented in might change in the future). [Note 3]

History recording (and consequently expansion) is turned off in `source`'d scripts, but through an internal flag which, as far as I know, is not made visible. It certainly does not appear in `$SHELLOPTS`. Since a `source`d script runs in the current bash context, it shares the current execution environment, including shell options. So in the execution of a `source`d script initiated from an interactive session, you'll see both `history` and `histexpand` in `$SHELLOPTS`, but no history expansion will take place. In order to enable it, you need to:

```
set -o history
```

which is not a no-op because it has the side-effect of resetting the internal flag which suppresses history recording. Setting the `histexpand` shell option does not have this side-effect.

In short, I'm not sure how you managed to enable history expansion in a script (if, indeed, the misbehaving command was in a script and not in an interactive shell), but you might want to consider not doing so, unless you have a really good reason.

## How history expansion is parsed

The bash implementation of history expansion is designed to work with `readline`, so that it can be performed during command input. (By default this function is bound to <kbd>Meta-^</kbd>; generally <kbd>Meta</kbd> is <kbd>ESC</kbd>, but you can customize that as well.) However, it is also performed immediately after each line is input, before any bash parsing is performed.

By default, the history expansion character is <kbd>!</kbd>, and -- as mostly documented -- that will trigger history expansion except:

1. when it is followed by whitespace or <kbd>=</kbd>
2. if the shell option `extglob` is set, and it is followed by <kbd>(</kbd> [Note 1]
3. if it appears in a single-quoted string
4. if it is preceded by a <kbd>\</kbd> [Note 2 and see below]
5. if it is preceded by <kbd>$</kbd> or <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> [Note 1]
6. if it is preceded by <kbd>[</kbd> [Note 1]
7. (As of bash v4.3) if it is the last character in a double-quoted string.

The immediate issue here is the precise interpretation of the third case, an <kbd>!</kbd> appearing inside of a single-quoted string. Normally, `bash` starts a new quoting context for a command substitution (`$(...)` or the deprecated backtick notation). For example:

```
$ s=SUBSTITUTED
$ # The interior single quotes are just characters
$ echo "'Echoing $s'"
'Echoing SUBSTITUTED'
$ # The interior single quotes are single quotes
$ echo "$(echo 'Echoing $s')"
Echoing $s
```

However, the history expansion scanner isn't that intelligent. It keeps track of quotes, but not of command substitution. So as far as it is concerned, both of the single quotes in the above example are double-quoted single quotes, which is to say ordinary characters. So history expansion occurs in both of them:

```
# A no-op to indicated history expansion
$ HIST() { :; }
# Single-quoted strings inhibit history expansion
$ HIST
$ echo '!!'
!!
# Double-quoted strings allow history expansion
$ HIST
$ echo "'!!'"
echo "'HIST'"
'HIST'
# ... and it applies also to interior command substitution.
$ HIST
$ echo "$(echo '!!')"
echo "$(echo 'HIST')"
HIST
```

So if you have a perfectly normal command like `sed '/foo/!d' file`, where you would expect the single-quotes to protect you from history-expansion, and you put it inside a double-quoted command substitution:

```
result="$(sed '/foo/!d' file)"
```

you suddenly find that the <kbd>!</kbd> is a history expansion character. Worse, you can't fix this by backslash escaping the exclamation point, because although `"\!"` inhibits history expansion, it doesn't remove the backslash:

```
$ echo "\!"
\!
```

In this particular example -- and the one in the OP -- the double quotes are completely unnecessary, because the right-hand side of a variable assignment does not undergo either filename expansion nor word splitting. However, there are other contexts in which removing the double quotes would change the semantics:

```
# Undesired history expansion
printf "The answer is '%s'\n" "$(sed '/foo/!d' file)"

# Undesired word splitting
printf "The answer is '%s'\n" $(sed '/foo/!d' file)
```

In this case, the best solution is probably to put the sed argument in a variable

```
# Works
sed_prog='/foo/!d'
printf "The answer is '%s'\n" "$(sed "$sed_prog" file)"
```

(The quotes around $sed_prog were not necessary in this case but usually they would be, and they do no harm.)

---

**Notes:**

1. The inhibition of history expansion when the following character is some form of open parenthesis only works if there is a corresponding close parenthesis in the rest of the string. However, it doesn't have to really match the open parenthesis. For example:

   ```
   # No matching close parenthesis
   $ echo "!("
   bash: !: event not found
   # The matching close parenthesis has nothing to do with the open
   $ echo "!(" ")"
   !( )
   # An actual extended glob: files whose names don't start with a
   $ echo "!(a*)"
   b
   ```
2. As indicated in the `bash` manual, a history-expansion character is treated as an ordinary character if immediately preceded by a backslash. This is literally true; it doesn't matter whether the backslash will later be considered an escape character or not:

   ```
   $ echo \!
   !
   $ echo \\!
   \!
   $ echo \\\!
   \!
   ```

   <kbd>\</kbd> also inhibits history expansion inside double quotes, but `\!` is not a valid escape sequence inside the double quoted string, so the backslash is not removed:

   ```
   $ echo "\!"
   \!
   $ echo "\\!"
   \!
   $ echo "\\\!"
   \\!
   ```
3. I'm referring to the source code for bash v4.2 as I write this, so any undocumented behaviour may be completely different as of v4.3.

Comment: @konsolebox: Thanks. I hope it makes clear why *in this particular case*, quoting the `!` with `''` or `\\` is not going to work.

Comment: Your answer has its own specifics until you added how to disable history expansion which are already told in other answers :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Doesn't `Only ‘\’ and ‘'’ may be used to escape the history expansion character.` hold true? Please don't try to complicate it with `""` by the way. `""` has its own rules of parsing which is similar but different from the open command-line.

Comment: If history expansion didn't also handle `!$` and friends I'd almost certainly just turn it off entirely to avoid all of this nonsense.

Comment: @EtanReisner: yes, all of that baggage (and a lot of bug reports over the years) is an attempt to balance the use of `!` for things other than history expansion with its historical use for history expansion. None of this is easy. For example, the issue that you cannot include a `!` in a double-quoted string was reported as a bug in 2002, and recently in v4.3 (still in alpha), it will be possible to do, but only if the `!` is the last (or only) character. I often do turn it off, because I use `!` in arguments and I hate the fact that "event not found" means the line isn't in my history.

Comment: @konsolebox: It's impossible to disentangle the answer from double-quotes, because *that is what the question is about*. Also, the other answers did not actually help me debug the problem, because its not obvious that you need to `set -o history` and not `histexpand` to reproduce the problem in a script.

Comment: The fact that history expansion failures don't end up in the history is a horrific annoyance.

Comment: @rici But it's just simple: double-quotes does not prevent history expansion no matter what kind of quoting you do inside it. It may perhaps but it's certainly not ruled to be. Well you'd need `set -o history` to make it work too but to disable it, you just need to unset `histexpand` which is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I was getting _very_ frustrated, trying to use `$!` on the commandline to get the PID of a subshell; I _knew_ there was a simple way to inhibit the history expansion, but I didn't think to try a space or braces. :)

Comment: And in Bash 4.4-beta: "History expansion now skips over the history expansion character in command and process substitution."

Comment: Oops, right, sorry about that! I skimmed right over that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't wrap the `$(...)` command substitution in double quotes. You are asking the shell to perform evaluation on the contents of the quotes and are hitting the history substitution expansion feature. Drop the quotes and you stop telling the shell to do that and you won't hit that problem.

And **yes**, dropping those quotes is safe on that assignment line even if the output may contain spaces or newlines or whatever. Assignments of that sort are not going to split on those the way command substitution or variable evaluation will on a normal shell execution line.

Alternatively, disable history expansion in your shell/script before you run that. (It should be off when running a script by default I believe anyway.)

Comment: How does not quoting $(...) avoid evaluation? In general, quotes avoid word splitting and globbing, but neither of these are performed on an assignment, actually the quotes are irrelevant.

Comment: @rici I'm not sure of the mechanism involved either but empirically it would seem that wrapping the command substitution in this case in quotes forces the shell to perform history expansion (at the very least) and thus cause the problem in question where leaving them off (which is what I recommend since as you said they aren't necessary) does not cause that behaviour. Of course this should all be moot in a script since history expansion shouldn't be occurring there anyway.

Comment: The amazing thing about bash is that no matter how much you *think* you know about it, there is always some obscure gotcha waiting to catch you. In this case, there are at least two of them, maybe more.

Comment: @rici Indeed. I would never in a million years have guessed that quotes there could trigger history expansion like this (or really do anything at all). Though I'm not sure what the second gotcha you are thinking about it.

Comment: I wrote up all the gotchas I found in an answer which is much longer than is merited, but I thought having done the work, I should at least record it somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

This only happens when history expansion is enabled, which it normally isn't and definitely shouldn't be for scripts.

Rather than trying to work around it, figure out why history expansion is enabled and what to do so it isn't.

1. If you're executing your script with `. foo` or `source foo`, use `./foo` instead.
2. If you're writing this as a function in `.bashrc` or similar, consider making it a separate script.
3. If your script (or BASH_ENV) explicitly does `set -H`, don't.

Answer (score 0):

Quote it with `''` or `\` or disable history expansion with `set +H` or `shopt -u -o histexpand`. See [History Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html).