# -bash: !": event not found

Tags: bash, command-line

How do I fix this bash terminal? Why would the '!' suddenly be a problem and the need for quotation marks are no longer seem to be necessary to produce the string. Did I break something? If so how do I reset it to factory setting? I'm sure it was working properly yesterday

```
Last login: Sat Oct 18 15:30:48 on ttys001
Michels-MacBook-Pro:~ michelfrechette$ echo "hello, world!"
-bash: !": event not found
Michels-MacBook-Pro:~ michelfrechette$ echo hello, world
hello, world
Michels-MacBook-Pro:~ michelfrechette$ echo "hello, world"
hello, world
```

`-bash: !": event not found`, this is curious.

Comment: This is also BashPitfalls #23: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.22Hello_World.21.22

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to address error "bash: !d': event not found" in Bash command substitution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003162/how-to-address-error-bash-d-event-not-found-in-bash-command-substitution)

Answer (score 54):

Running

```
set +H
```

will turn off the offending (history expansion) functionality in its entirety. Putting this in your `~/.bashrc` is a common practice.

Alternately, you can modify the `histchars` variable to change the characters used to trigger history expansion (by default, `!`), quick substitution (by default, `^`) and comments (by default, `#`).

As yet another option, using single- rather than double-quotes avoids triggering the shell feature in question.

Comment: What if it is wanted sometimes?

Comment: @user2864740, ...then learn to use readline properly, and you'll no longer want it. :)