# Why NO error "-bash: !": event not found" when executed from shell script file?

Tags: bash, shell

Command below in interactive shell produces the error which is explained in other questions:

```
$ echo "Hello World !"
-bash: !": event not found
```

Why is the error gone when put in a shell script file and executed?

```
cat <<EOT > test.sh
#!/bin/sh

VAR=1
echo "Hello World !$VAR"
echo "Hello World !2"
echo "Hello World !3"
EOT
```

None of below produce the error!

```
chmod a+x ./test.sh
./test.sh
bash   ./test.sh
sh     ./test.sh
source ./test.sh
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443880/bash-event-not-found

Comment: I am asking why NO error when same commands are executed from shell script file!?

Comment: History expansion is off by default in scripts. It's an interactive feature only.

Comment: `case $- in *H*) echo "History expansion is on";; *) echo "History expansion is off";; esac` -- you'll see different behavior there as well. And as usual with all `$-` / `set` flags, `set -H` will force it on, and `set +H` will force it off.

Comment: `set -H` in a script file does not make any difference - it always print  `History expansion is off` and echo works properly

Comment: yes I did that - after the shebang I added `set -H` and still echo did not error out

Comment: ("Why can't I successfully turn on history expansion in a script?" strikes me as a perfectly on-topic question; if you wrote a question demonstrating that, contrary to the preexisting/linked answers, you can't use `set -H` to reenable history expansion in bash, that would be a useful thing -- I'd also gladly reopen this question if it were edited thusly)