# tmux send-keys swallows spaces

Tags: function, tmux, spaces

Synopsis: "tmux send-keys" strips the spaces from a bash command and I don't understand why (or how, really.)

```
test ()
  {
    tmux new -s testsession -d
    tmux send-keys -t testsession "time tar -I \"zstd -19 -T0\" -cvf ${1}.tar.zst "${@:2}""
    tmux attach -t testsession
  }
```

with an input of

> input1 input2 input3 i\ n\ p\ u\ t\ 4

Expected (and desired) output is

> time tar -I "zstd -19 -T0" -cvf input1.tar.zst "input2" "input3" "i n
> p u t 4"

Instead I get

> time tar -I "zstd -19 -T0" -cvf input1.tar.zst "input2input3input4"

Note I have omitted the `; C-m` or `; ENTER` at the end of the send-keys. (And I've also simplified the original function since other parts are more straightforward and work.) I've done that to get a more precise understanding of what is outputted on the terminal during several hours spent last night trying to brute-force the 'correct' syntax (, to no avail.)

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over the same problem and I found the not-so-nice solution of adding the keyword, "Space", for the spaces.

So, in your case, I would expect following command to work:

```
tmux send-keys -t testsession "time Space tar Space -I Space \"zstd Space -19 Space -T0\" Space -cvf Space ${1}.tar.zst Space "${@:2}""
```

I got this idea from this page's [send-keys description](https://blog.damonkelley.me/2016/09/07/tmux-send-keys/) "list of Keys" section.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"$*"` instead of `"$@"`:

```bash
tmux send-keys -t bar "$*" C-m
```

`"$*"` represents the arguments as single string instead of split into an array.

When using `"$@"`, the word boundaries are kept even when surrounded by quotes, so sending `"$@"` into another program sends each input seperately. This makes it easy to pass input from a wrapper funciton into another function.

The difference between `$@` and `"$@"` is that while `"$@"` preserves argument splits, it will not split it any further. See [shellcheck wiki](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2068).

The script I used for testing, `test.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

printargs()
{
    echo "\$1: $1"
    echo "\$2: $2"
    echo "\$3: $3"
}

foo="$@"

printargs $@
printargs "$@"
printargs $*
printargs "$*"
printargs $(echo "$@")
printargs "$(echo "$@")"
printargs $foo
printargs "$foo"
```

Calling `./test.sh foo 'bar baz'` prints to the terminal:

```
$1: foo
$2: bar
$3: baz
$1: foo
$2: bar baz
$3:
$1: foo
$2: bar
$3: baz
$1: foo bar baz
$2:
$3:
$1: foo
$2: bar
$3: baz
$1: foo bar baz
$2:
$3:
$1: foo
$2: bar
$3: baz
$1: foo bar baz
$2:
$3:
```

I am using `dash`, a POSIX compliant shell, but running it with `bash` produced the same result.

Comment: Replacing `"${@:2}"` with `"${*:2}"` in the definition of `test()` from the original post makes the tmux session write: `time tar -I "zstd -19 -T0" -cvf input1.tar.zst input2input3input4`. How would you solve the specific problem in the post?

Answer (score 0):

### Update

It turns out I had misread the definition of the E operator, and it basically does nothing in this context. Removing `@E` still works, so the only problem was writing quotes explicitly:

```
function quote() { for arg; do echo \"$arg\"; done | paste -sd' ' ; }

function test() { 
  tmux new -s testsession -d
  command="time tar -I \"zstd -19 -T0\" cvf ${1}.tar.zst $(quote "${@:2}")"
  tmux send-keys -t testsession "${command}"
  tmux attach -t testsession
}
```

### Original answer

One way is to use [shell parameter expansion with the E operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
function quote() { for arg; do echo \"$arg\"; done | paste -sd' ' ; }

function test() { 
  tmux new -s testsession -d
  command="time tar -I \"zstd -19 -T0\" cvf ${1}.tar.zst $(quote "${@:2}")"
  tmux send-keys -t testsession "${command@E}"
  tmux attach -t testsession
}
```

Then running the command

```
test input1 input2 input3 i\ n\ p\ u\ t\ 4
```

attaches us to a tmux window with the keys sent to it:

```
$ time tar -I "zstd -19 -T0" cvf input1.tar.zst "input2" "input3" "i n p u t 4"
```

**How send-keys reads a string:** from the [man page for tmux](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html):

> Each argument key is the name of the key (such as ‘C-a’ or ‘NPage’) to send; **if the string is not recognised as a key, it is sent as a series of characters**.

So what we're doing is sending a string as one token.

There are two levels of quotation here. Your shell is interpreting a quoted string, then sending it to tmux, which again *reads and interprets the string you sent*, i.e., the contents of the outer quote marks. It's a bit like sending a letter inside an envelope inside an envelope. Thus

```
tmux send-keys -t session-name "echo \"hello world!\""
```

puts `echo "hello world!"` on the console. (If you get `bash: !\": event not found`, make sure you [turn off history expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443880/bash-event-not-found) using `set +H` first.)

**Why it swallows spaces:** it reads spaces as delimiters between tokens. Here it's reading the whole thing as one token (`echo "hello world!"`), then typing it directly because `echo "hello world!"` is not the name of a key. But if we hadn't quoted it out (`echo hello world`), then it would read three tokens:

1. `echo` (passed as keystrokes because it's not a key),
2. `hello` (passed as keystrokes because it's not a key), and
3. `world` (passed as keystrokes because it's not a key).

The result:

```
$ echohelloworld
```

**How I'm making the string tmux-friendly:** I changed `"${@:2}"` to a function that explicitly writes quotes around each argument and concatenates them with spaces in between. (My function has to call `echo` and `paste`, so there's probably a more elegant way to do this just in bash.)

The `${parameter@E}` syntax uses the E operator, defined [in the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) this way:

> The expansion is a string that is the value of *parameter* with backslash escape sequences expanded as with the `$'…'` quoting mechanism.

The `$'...'` quoting mechanism is [the ANSI-C quoting standard](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html). In other words, `${parameter@E}` escapes out all the troublesome characters in `$parameter` the same way you would escape them in C. Tmux seems to be happy with this quoting standard, although I can’t find any documentation that says so.