# Single quotes in history expansion (bash)

Tags: linux, string, bash, syntax

I have a theoretical question about the syntax of Bash.
I am running Bash 4.3.11(1) in Linux Ubuntu 14.04.

In the official GNU's website: [Bash official web (GNU)](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction)
in Subection 9.3.1. it says:

> !string
>
> Refer to the most recent command preceding the current position 
>      in the history list starting with string.

In general it's understood that `string` is, syntactically speaking, a sequence of characters ending before the first blank or newline.

However, when describing **quoting** in subsection 3.1.2., we can read in paragraph 3.1.2.2. what follows:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal
>   value of each character within the quotes.

In particular, the blanks inside single quotes are not broking the strings in separated words.

So, a expression like `!'some text'` would have to search in the history list of Bash for the most recent command starting by `'some text'`.

However, the blank between `some` and `text` is broken when I write it in my terminal, since the following error message is shown:

> bash: !'some: event not found

Is this behaviour a bug in the implementation of the shell, or well I am not understanding the expansion rules of Bash for this example?

Comment: I don't know anything official but I'm going to go with the same sort of answer that rici gives [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25021905/258523) which is basically just that the history parsing isn't very smart (despite the docs specifically talking history expansion handling quoted strings in the lines that it pulls from the history). Or, perhaps more precisely, history expansion is pre-parse and not very clever.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Thank you very much (the **rici**'s reference was very clarifier to me).

Comment: @EtanReisner: Yeah, what I said there. History expansion is such a kludge. If you specify !string, the string will be terminated by whitespace or colon; quoting is *not* taken into account. Or, in other words, history expansion happens before bash even looks at quotes. If you specify substring match (!?string?), the rules change, though. Then the string is terminated only by a ? or a newline.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Oh, and as usual it's more complicated than that :) Otherwise, I would have written an answer, I suppose. But afaik, whitespace *always* terminates !string, as do :, shell metacharacters, and sometimes quotes.

Comment: Instead of quoting, have you tried escaping the space?  For example `!some\ text`?

Comment: @rici: your answer in [rici's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003162/how-to-address-error-bash-d-event-not-found-in-bash-command-substitution/25021905#25021905) is mostly about **double quoting**. However this case is, more or less, considered in the reference (paragraph 3.1.2.3 in [bash in gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes). But **single quoting** can be a little different. For example, in my terminal if I wrote `echo '!!'`, there is not pre-parsing there of !! and the output is just `!!` (the correct answer).

Comment: @Mr.Llama: Yes, I always try everything. :) It doesn't work. (`!some\ text` searchs for the event `some\`).

Comment: @pablo1977: That's correct. My answer to the other question is about an odd corner case where the `!` (logically) appears with single quotes (so it should be an ordinary character), but the history expansion doesn't recognize that fact because the single quotes appear inside a double-quoted command substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call the observed behaviour a bug, because there is no specification for history expansion other than the observed behaviour of the bash shell itself. But it is certainly the case that the precise mechanics of parsing a history expansion expression is not well documented and has a lot of possibly surprising corner cases.

The bash manpage does state that history expansion "is performed immediately after a complete line is read, *before the shell breaks it into words*" (emphasis added), while the bash manual mentions that history expansion is provided by the History library. This is the root cause of most of the history expansion parsing oddities: history expansion works on raw unparsed input without any assistance from the bash tokenizer, and is mostly done with an external library which is not bash-specific. Since tokenizing `bash` input is non-trivial, it is not really surprising that the relatively simple parsing rules used during history expansion are only a rough approximation to a real bash parse.

For example, the bash manual does indicated that you can prevent a history expansion character (<kbd>!</kbd>) from being recognized as such by backslash-quoting it. But it is not explicitly documented that any <kbd>\</kbd> which immediately precedes an <kbd>!</kbd> will inhibit recognition of the history expansion, even if the backslash was itself quoted with a backslash. So the <kbd>!</kbd> in `\\!word` does *not* cause the previous command starting with `word` to be substituted. (`\\word` is a common way to execute the *command* `word` instead of the *alias* `word`, so the example is not entirely contrived.)

A longer discussion of some of the corner cases of the recognition of the history expansion character can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003162/how-to-address-error-bash-d-event-not-found-in-bash-command-substitution/25021905#25021905).

The issue raised by this question is slightly different, since it is about the next phase of the history expansion parse. Once it has been established that a particular character is a history expansion character, it is then necessary to parse the "event" which follows; as indicated by the bash manual, the event can take several forms, one of which is `!string`, representing the most recent command which starts with "`string`".

It is implied that this form will only be used if no other form applies, which means that `string` may not start with a digit or <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>!</kbd>, <kbd>#</kbd> or <kbd>?</kbd>. It also may not start with whitespace or <kbd>=</kbd> (since those would inhibit history expansion) and in some circumstances <kbd>(</kbd> or <kbd>"</kbd> (which may inhibit history expansion). And finally, it may not start with <kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>$</kbd>, <kbd>%</kbd> or <kbd>*</kbd>, which would be interpreted as a word designator (from the default event, which is the previous command).

The [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) does not specify what terminates the `string`. It is semi-documented in the [`history` library manual](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html#SEC17), which mentions that a history search string (or "event" as it is called in the bash manual) is terminated by whitespace, <kbd>:</kbd>, or any of the characters in the history configuration variable `history_search_delimiter_chars`. (For the record,  `bash` currently (v4.3) sets that variable to `";&()|<>"`.)

As indicated earlier, quoting is taken into account when deciding whether or not to recognize a history expansion character; as it turns out, if the history expansion occurs inside a double-quoted string, then the closing double-quote is also considered a history search delimiter character.  And that, as far as I know, is the entire list of characters which will delimit `!string`.

Nowhere in either the bash nor the history documentation does it state that a history search delimiter character can be made non-special by quoting, and indeed this does not happen. An open quote, whether double or single, or even a backslash *following* the <kbd>!</kbd> will be treated as just part of the `string` to be searched for, without any special processing.

Parsing of the substring-match history expansion -- `!?string?` -- is completely different. That string can only be terminated by a <kbd>?</kbd> or by a newline. (As the bash manual says, the trailing <kbd>?</kbd> is optional if terminated by a newline.)

Once the history expansion character has been recognized and the history search string has been identified, it may then be necessary to split the retrieved history entry into words. Again, the bash manual is slightly cavalier about corner cases, when it says that "the line is broken into words in the same fashion that Bash does, so that several words surrounded by quotes are considered one word."

A pedant would observe that "in the same fashion that Bash does" is not quite the same as saying "exactly as Bash would do", and in fact the second part of the sentence is literall true: several words surrounded by quotes are considered one word *even if the quotes are not really matching quotes*. For example, the line:

```
command "$(echo " foo bar ")"
```

is considered by the history library to consist of the following five words:

```
0. command
1. "$(echo "
2. foo
3. bar
4. ")"
```

although the bash parse would be quite different. By contrast, bash and the history library agree on the parsing of

```
command "$(echo ' foo bar ')"
```

as two words.