# Multi-line, double quoted string triggers history expansion on subsequent single-quoted commands it gets piped to

Tags: bash, gnu, command-substitution

I am on GNU bash, version 4.3.11.

Say I want to print unique lines on a file. I am using this approach, which works well on a file:

```
$ cat a
9
10
9
11
$ awk '!seen[$0]++' a
9
10
11
```

However, if I get the input from stdin, using double quotes in a multi-line and piping to awk, it fails:

```
$ echo "9
> 10
> 9
> 11" | awk '!seen[$0]++'
bash: !seen[$0]++': event not found
```

That is, bash tries to expand the command `seen`, which of course does not know because it is a variable name. But it shouldn't happen, since the command is placed within single-quotes.

`echo`ing in a single-quoted, multi-line input works well:

```
$ echo '9
> 10
> 9
> 11' | awk '!seen[$0]++'
9
10
11
```

The funny thing is that it also works well on a single-line input that is double-quoted:

```
$ printf "9\n10\n9\n11" | awk '!seen[$0]++'
9
10
11
```

I wonder why is Bash trying to expand history if it occurs after a mutiline input, even though the command itself uses single-quotes.

Other considerations:

Having a pipe in between does not fix it, either:

```
$ echo "9
> 10
> 9
> 11" | cat - | awk '!seen[$0]++'
bash: !seen[$0]++': event not found
```

And setting [`set +H` turns history off](https://serverfault.com/a/208414/200076), so it works well because it does not try to expand anything:

```
$ set +H
$ echo "9
> 10
> 9
> 11" | awk '!seen[$0]++'
9
10
11
```

I went through the canonical answer by rici on [how to address error “bash: !d': event not found” in Bash command substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25021905/1983854) and found many possible reasons, but none matches this behaviour.

Comment: It appears that the last line is parsed as a single line, instead of include the before quoted string. Meaning that the `!` is processed as though it is in double quotes. You will also notice that you will get a `>` on the next line as it waits for you to close this perceived quoted string. This is why it works on a single line as well. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Reproducible in 4.2.47. I'd file a bug.

Comment: Also reproducible all the way back to `3.2.51`

Comment: `$ ls<press enter here>` `$ echo "<press enter here>asdasd<another enter here>" | echo '!!'` will print weird outputs...

Comment: @anishsane same with `!#`, not what you would expect, try `echo "<ENTER>123<ENTER>" | awk '!#'`. It returns `" | awk '" | awk ''`

Comment: Also note that, this issue is reproducible only if line containing the second command starts with `"`. If you add a multiline single quoted string in between, it works correctly.

Comment: @anishsane yep, thanks! I mentioned this in the question.

Comment: Need your opinions on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816059/bash-hashmap-using-quote-as-key too...

Comment: @anishsane interesting one! I see the VIP in bash already handled it : )

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) out!

Comment: @meain why is this relevant?

Comment: @choroba so I thought. I filed a bug and got an answer stating that this is kind of "normal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug.

After asking this in the bash-bugs mailing list, I got the following answer:

> History expansion is explicitly line-oriented.
>
> It doesn't know about shell state, especially shell quoting state,
>   that spans lines.
>
> It does know about vaguely shell-like quoting that's common across a
>   large set of Unix utilities -- since the history and readline
>   libraries are used outside the shell --  and that a double quote
>   introduces a quoted string in which single quotes are not significant
>   and don't inhibit history expansion.

Comment: Upvote for documenting this, but that's insane behavior.