# Bash hashmap using quote as key

Tags: linux, bash, dictionary

In Bash, I want to unset an entry of a hashmap. But I failed. Code is like below:

```
declare -A arr
arr["a'b"]=3
echo ${!arr[@]} ## output: a'b
key="a'b"
unset arr[$key] ## error: -bash: unset: `arr[a'b]': not a valid identifier
```

How can I unset this entry?

Comment: [`unset arr["$key"]`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting) ? **EDIT**: This does not work either...

Comment: Looks like a bug in bash

Comment: Hmm... my bad...  Also, `arr['$x']=123; unset arr['$x']` gives `-bash: unset: [$x]: bad array subscript`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use single quotes:

```
$ declare -A arr=(["a'b"]=3 [foo]=bar)
$ declare -p arr
declare -A arr='(["a'\''b"]="3" [foo]="bar" )'
$ key="a'b"
$ unset 'arr[$key]'
$ declare -p arr
declare -A arr='([foo]="bar" )'
```

Done!

Comment: That is magical. Is it documented that `unset` does a 2nd round of expansion?

Comment: @glennjackman: I haven't seen it documented, really, but it's not specific to `unset`. Arithmetic context also shows this behavior: `declare -A glenn; key='$(ls>&2)'; ((glenn[$key]))`. Surprise. The answer is probably in the source `:)`. Bash has a really crazy way of parsing stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Tricky. You can do it by hand by escaping the "inner" single quote:

```
$ declare -A arr=(["a'b"]=3 [foo]=bar)
$ key="a'b"
$ unset "arr[$key]"
bash: unset: `arr[a'b]': not a valid identifier
$ unset "arr[a\'b]"
$ declare -p arr
declare -A arr='([foo]="bar" )'
```

But how to do it "programmatically"? Fortunately bash does have a mechanism to "escape" a string: `printf "%q"`:

```
$ declare -A arr=(["a'b"]=3 [foo]=bar)
$ echo "$key"
a'b
$ printf "%q" "$key"
a\'b
$ unset "arr[$(printf "%q" "$key")]"
$ declare -p arr
declare -A arr='([foo]="bar" )'
```