# How to escape bash parameter expansion (when a "!" followed by letters is a parameter)

Tags: bash, escaping, variable-expansion, parameter-expansion

I have a bash script I need to call with a string parameter, which string starts with a exclamation mark "!" (this is **mandatory** in what I'm doing):

```
myCommand.sh "!HELLO"
```

Because of parameter expansion, bash reports an error:

```
-bash: !HELLO: event not found
```

Is there any way to escape the "!" that produces this? Another way to pass such parameter?

Comment: Use single quotes: `myCommand.sh '!HELLO'`

Comment: Especially [this fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25021905/3266847).