# How to use gitbash with file names that contain ASCII exclamation point characters like !0-MyFolder

Tags: bash, command-line, git-bash

I need to use gitbash on MS-Windows with file folder names that contain an exclamation point as the first characters, like "!0-MyProjectFolder" (without the quotation marks.  I use the exclamation point to sort Microsoft Windows files to the top, since Windows does not provide a way to index and force sort order of files and folders.

Gitbash keeps giving me error messages:

I've tried several syntaxes already:

```
$ cd "!0-Projects-WIP"
bash: !0: event not found

$ cd "\!0-Projects-WIP"
bash: \!0: event not found

$ cd !0-Projects-WIP
bash: !0: event not found
```

Be clear that I am NOT parsing a string like '/New.*desktop.*is/!d' in the StackOverflow posting at [How to address error "bash: !d': event not found" in Bash command substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003162)

```
VNCServerAndDisplayNumber="$(echo "${VNCServerResponse}" \
    | sed '/New.*desktop.*is/!d' | awk -F" desktop is " '{print $2}')"
```

I am passing the directory name !0-Projects-WIP to GitBash, so that I can change into the directory named !0-Projects-WIP.  I am not intending to do double-quoting or history expansion.  If the exclamation point in the folder name appears to be a history expansion directive, then that is not the intended result.  The ! must be escaped in my case so that it is read correctly as part of the folder name, and the shell command "cd" interprets it as a string.

I realize now that !0-Projects-WIP is probably a bad name to a Unix shell parser because it directs the command line parser to do something that was not my intention, but for the MS-Windows command line shell there is no confusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to address error "bash: !d': event not found" in Bash command substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003162/how-to-address-error-bash-d-event-not-found-in-bash-command-substitution)

Comment: The intention of my command is different from what the other poster in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003162/how-to-address-error-bash-d-event-not-found-in-bash-command-substitution was trying to do.  The solution is different in my case too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [echo "#!" fails -- "event not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816122/echo-fails-event-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with just a single escape character in front of the string:

```
$ cd \!0-Projects-WIP

rlysa@domainname MINGW64 /c/users/rlysak01/desktop/!0-Projects-WIP (master)
$
```

Simple solution.  No quotation marks needed on the folder name string.