# Understand double quote with echo and shebang

Tags: shell

I have a basic question about Shell interpretation

When i make something like :

> echo "#!/bin/bash"
>
> -bash: !/bin/bash: event not found

What does the shell really pass to the echo command.
If i understand well, the double quote make the shell doesnt do globbing.

Comment: Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25003162/3266847).

Comment: This doesn't happen in scripts (where history expansion is off-by-default), only at interactive shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!` is used for [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction), not for globbing.

From the [bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes):

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the  literal  value  of
>     all  characters  within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \, and,
>     when history expansion is enabled, !.

Comment: Note the bullet point in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) regarding questions which "have already been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: sorry @CharlesDuffy, I should have checked. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: No obligation to. Personally, what I usually do when I discover that I answered a duplicate (where it's a simple enough question that there won't be a huge amount of extra benefit to someone clicking through and reading the preexisting canonical answers) is toggle the "community wiki" flag, but that too isn't obligatory.