# How to split a string into an array in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, split

In a Bash script, I would like to split a line into pieces and store them in an array.

For example, given the line:

```
Paris, France, Europe
```

I would like to have the resulting array to look like so:

```
array[0] = Paris
array[1] = France
array[2] = Europe
```

A simple implementation is preferable; speed does not matter. How can I do it?

Comment: This is #1 Google hit but there's controversy in the answer because the question unfortunately asks about delimiting on `, ` (comma-space) and not a *single character* such as comma.  If you're only interested in the latter, answers here are easier to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash#tab-top

Comment: If you want to munge a string and don't care about having it as an array, `cut` is a useful bash command to bear in mind too. Separator is definable https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cut You can also extract out data from a fixed width record structure too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)  https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucut.htm

Answer (score 1513, accepted):

```
IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$string"
```

Note that the characters in `$IFS` are treated individually as separators so that in this case fields may be separated by *either* a comma or a space rather than the sequence of the two characters. Interestingly though, empty fields aren't created when comma-space appears in the input because the space is treated specially.

To access an individual element:

```
echo "${array[0]}"
```

To iterate over the elements:

```
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done
```

To get both the index and the value:

```
for index in "${!array[@]}"
do
    echo "$index ${array[index]}"
done
```

The last example is useful because Bash arrays are sparse. In other words, you can delete an element or add an element and then the indices are not contiguous.

```
unset "array[1]"
array[42]=Earth
```

To get the number of elements in an array:

```
echo "${#array[@]}"
```

As mentioned above, arrays can be sparse so you shouldn't use the length to get the last element. Here's how you can in Bash 4.2 and later:

```
echo "${array[-1]}"
```

in any version of Bash (from somewhere after 2.05b):

```
echo "${array[@]: -1:1}"
```

Larger negative offsets select farther from the end of the array. Note the space before the minus sign in the older form. It is required.

Comment: How can I refer to the elements?

Comment: Just use `IFS=', '`, then you don't have to remove the spaces separately. Test: `IFS=', ' read -a array <<< "Paris, France, Europe"; echo "${array[@]}"`

Comment: @l0b0: Thanks. I don't know what I was thinking. I like to use `declare -p array` for test output, by the way.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Nice one, added to `.bash_history`.

Comment: whats the way if I want to use multiple delimiters like , as well as ;?

Comment: @ram: Add more characters to the value of `IFS`.

Comment: How about having the array's length?

Comment: Augustin-Riedinger: I've added that and a couple of other bits of information. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to respect quotes. For example `France, Europe, "Congo, The Democratic Republic of the"` this will split after congo.

Comment: @YisraelDov: Bash has no way to deal with CSV by itself. It can't tell the difference between commas inside quotes and those outside them. You will need to use a tool that understands CSV such as a lib in a higher level language, for example the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module in Python.

Comment: Thanks for this cool code.  Is there anyway to place this in a function?  When I do, I echo ${arr[@]} but in so doing, I may miss the cases where arr[x] may be a nul string.

Comment: @Bitdiot: You may need to ask this as a separate question so you can include more detail about what you're trying to do. Yes, you can place this in a function. I don't know what you mean about missing cases where an array element is an empty string, since there's nothing to output.

Comment: what if the string for tokenizing has wild cards? e.g. IFS='base*'

Comment: @JayD: Each character is used individually, not as a sequence. The asterisk is just another character.

Comment: `"$index ${array[index]}"` should be `"$index ${array[$index]}"`, no?

Comment: @tetris11: It can be either way. The array index is an arithmetic context where the dollar sign is not usually required.

Comment: @caesarsol: Compare yours to `IFS=', ' read -a array <<< "a, d r s, w"` with spaces after the commas in the input. The result is the same (no empty array elements are created) because spaces are treated specially. Also compare inputs such as `"a, d r s,,w"` which does create an empty element and `"a, d r s    w"` (multiple spaces between "s" and "w" - which don't show well here) which does not create any empty elements. Also, I commented regarding the characteristic of `IFS` you mentioned, earlier, on August 7, 2015, above.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson that IFS will split also by spaces: the `d r s` words in my example should be a single array element.

Comment: @caesarsol: The `IFS` in your first comment includes a space. `declare -p array` is a good way to show an array's elements, btw.

Comment: what if we have string like "/opt/test/dir" and want to split using "/"? i tried IFS='/' which is not working :(

Comment: @Ganesh: It works for me. How exactly are you doing it and how are you determining that it's not working? This is what I did with your example: `IFS='/' read -r -a array <<< "/opt/test/dir"; for d in "${array[@]}"; do echo "$d"; done`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson thanks for the reply it worked, was my mistake. i was having string "/opt/test/dir" and spliting with "/". was trying to echo 0th element which :P

Comment: Great answer, thanks. A little note, if someone is using Bash < 4.2, `echo "$array[@]: -1:1}` is missing initial `{` and ending `"`, should be `echo "${array[@]: -1:1}"`

Comment: `str="Paris, France, Europe, Los Angeles"; IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$str"` will split into `array=([0]="Paris" [1]="France" [2]="Europe" [3]="Los" [4]="Angeles")` as a note. So this only works with fields with no spaces since `IFS=', '` is a set of individual characters -- not a string delimiter.

Comment: @dawg As noted by caesarsol on 10/29/2015 above. I'll add the information to my answer.

Comment: Any idea what's going wrong here? `s="a:b:c"; IFS=':' read -r -a array <<< $s; echo $array; echo ${array[1]}`. Expected output `a b c<newline>a`, actually got `a b c<newline><blank line>`

Comment: @scubbo: I don't get what you got, I got `a<newline>b<newline>` which is what I would expect from your code which says "print the first element of the array; print the second element of the array". If you want your expected output: `s="a:b:c"; IFS=':' read -r -a array <<< "$s"; echo "${array[@]}"; echo "${array[0]}"` The reason for this is that a scalar reference to an array is the same as the first element of the array and array indices are zero-based. Note also that you should always use proper quoting (but that wasn't the issue for you). I have no idea how you got the output you showed...

Comment: ...unless you didn't set `IFS=':'` but then the output would be `a:b:c<newline><blank line>`.

Comment: Hmm - not sure why we got different results (maybe it's due to different shells? I got the error above in `sh` and `bash`, but in `zsh` I got `zsh: bad option: -a`), but your proposed solution works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Ohhh I found the difference. I need to quote-wrap `"$s"` to get the behaviour I expect.

Comment: @scubbo: Copy and paste what you posted in your first message. I suspect that what you posted doesn't match what you're actually testing.

Comment: @scubbo: OK, this is a bug that was fixed in Bash 4.3.

Comment: There are many ways to make it work.The simple one use tr command it can work either MacOS and Linux.  arrayData=($(echo "1.0.0.1 | tr "." "\n"))

Comment: I receive an error "read: bad option: -a" when I tried this

Comment: @Patlatus: You are probably using a shell (non-Bash) that doesn't support arrays (or using `read` to populate them). Bash has supported this for a very long time.

Answer (score 695):

All of the answers to this question are wrong in one way or another.

---

[***Wrong answer #1***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10586169/4272464)

```
IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$string"
```

**1:** This is a misuse of `$IFS`. The value of the `$IFS` variable is **not** taken as a *single variable-length* string separator, rather it is taken as a *set* of *single-character* string separators, where each field that `read` splits off from the input line can be terminated by *any* character in the set (comma **or** space, in this example).

Actually, for the real sticklers out there, the full meaning of `$IFS` is slightly more involved. From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting):

> The shell treats each character of **IFS** as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions into words using these characters as field terminators. If **IFS** is unset, or its value is exactly **<space><tab><newline>**, the default, then sequences of **<space>**, **<tab>**, and **<newline>** at the beginning and end of the results of the previous expansions are ignored, and any sequence of **IFS** characters not at the beginning or end serves to delimit words. If **IFS** has a value other than the default, then sequences of the whitespace characters **<space>**, **<tab>**, and **<newline>** are ignored at the beginning and end of the word, as long as the whitespace character is in the value of **IFS** (an **IFS** whitespace character). Any character in **IFS** that is not **IFS** whitespace, along with any adjacent **IFS** whitespace characters, delimits a field. A sequence of **IFS** whitespace characters is also treated as a delimiter. If the value of **IFS** is null, no word splitting occurs.

Basically, for non-default non-null values of `$IFS`, fields can be separated with either (1) a sequence of one or more characters that are all from the set of "IFS whitespace characters" (that is, whichever of **<space>**, **<tab>**, and **<newline>** ("newline" meaning [line feed (LF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)) are present anywhere in `$IFS`), or (2) any non-"IFS whitespace character" that's present in `$IFS` along with whatever "IFS whitespace characters" surround it in the input line.

For the OP, it's possible that the second separation mode I described in the previous paragraph is exactly what he wants for his input string, but we can be pretty confident that the first separation mode I described is not correct at all. For example, what if his input string was `'Los Angeles, United States, North America'`?

```
IFS=', ' read -ra a <<<'Los Angeles, United States, North America'; declare -p a;
## declare -a a=([0]="Los" [1]="Angeles" [2]="United" [3]="States" [4]="North" [5]="America")
```

**2:** Even if you were to use this solution with a single-character separator (such as a comma by itself, that is, with no following space or other baggage), if the value of the `$string` variable happens to contain any LFs, then `read` will stop processing once it encounters the first LF. The `read` builtin only processes one line per invocation. This is true even if you are piping or redirecting input *only* to the `read` statement, as we are doing in this example with the [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) mechanism, and thus unprocessed input is guaranteed to be lost. The code that powers the `read` builtin has no knowledge of the data flow within its containing command structure.

You could argue that this is unlikely to cause a problem, but still, it's a subtle hazard that should be avoided if possible. It is caused by the fact that the `read` builtin actually does two levels of input splitting: first into lines, then into fields. Since the OP only wants one level of splitting, this usage of the `read` builtin is not appropriate, and we should avoid it.

**3:** A non-obvious potential issue with this solution is that `read` always drops the trailing field if it is empty, although it preserves empty fields otherwise. Here's a demo:

```
string=', , a, , b, c, , , '; IFS=', ' read -ra a <<<"$string"; declare -p a;
## declare -a a=([0]="" [1]="" [2]="a" [3]="" [4]="b" [5]="c" [6]="" [7]="")
```

Maybe the OP wouldn't care about this, but it's still a limitation worth knowing about. It reduces the robustness and generality of the solution.

This problem can be solved by appending a dummy trailing delimiter to the input string just prior to feeding it to `read`, as I will demonstrate later.

---

[***Wrong answer #2***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15400047/4272464)

```
string="1:2:3:4:5"
set -f                     # avoid globbing (expansion of *).
array=(${string//:/ })
```

[Similar idea:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31405855/4272464)

```
t="one,two,three"
a=($(echo $t | tr ',' "\n"))
```

(Note: I added the missing parentheses around the command substitution which the answerer seems to have omitted.)

[Similar idea:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37618160/4272464)

```
string="1,2,3,4"
array=(`echo $string | sed 's/,/\n/g'`)
```

These solutions leverage word splitting in an array assignment to split the string into fields. Funnily enough, just like `read`, general word splitting also uses the `$IFS` special variable, although in this case it is implied that it is set to its default value of **<space><tab><newline>**, and therefore any sequence of one or more IFS characters (which are all whitespace characters now) is considered to be a field delimiter.

This solves the problem of two levels of splitting committed by `read`, since word splitting by itself constitutes only one level of splitting. But just as before, the problem here is that the individual fields in the input string can already contain `$IFS` characters, and thus they would be improperly split during the word splitting operation. This happens to not be the case for any of the sample input strings provided by these answerers (how convenient...), but of course that doesn't change the fact that any code base that used this idiom would then run the risk of blowing up if this assumption were ever violated at some point down the line. Once again, consider my counterexample of `'Los Angeles, United States, North America'` (or `'Los Angeles:United States:North America'`).

Also, word splitting is normally followed by [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion) (*aka* pathname expansion *aka* globbing), which, if done, would potentially corrupt words containing the characters `*`, `?`, or `[` followed by `]` (and, if `extglob` is set, parenthesized fragments preceded by `?`, `*`, `+`, `@`, or `!`) by matching them against file system objects and expanding the words ("globs") accordingly. The first of these three answerers has cleverly undercut this problem by running `set -f` beforehand to disable globbing. Technically this works (although you should probably add `set +f` afterward to reenable globbing for subsequent code which may depend on it), but it's undesirable to have to mess with global shell settings in order to hack a basic string-to-array parsing operation in local code.

Another issue with this answer is that all empty fields will be lost. This may or may not be a problem, depending on the application.

Note: If you're going to use this solution, it's better to use the `${string//:/ }` "pattern substitution" form of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), rather than going to the trouble of invoking a command substitution (which forks the shell), starting up a pipeline, and running an external executable (`tr` or `sed`), since parameter expansion is purely a shell-internal operation. (Also, for the `tr` and `sed` solutions, the input variable should be double-quoted inside the command substitution; otherwise word splitting would take effect in the `echo` command and potentially mess with the field values. Also, the `$(...)` form of command substitution is preferable to the old `` `...` `` form since it simplifies nesting of command substitutions and allows for better syntax highlighting by text editors.)

---

[***Wrong answer #3***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39474755/4272464)

```
str="a, b, c, d"  # assuming there is a space after ',' as in Q
arr=(${str//,/})  # delete all occurrences of ','
```

This answer is almost the same as **#2**. The difference is that the answerer has made the assumption that the fields are delimited by two characters, one of which being represented in the default `$IFS`, and the other not. He has solved this rather specific case by removing the non-IFS-represented character using a pattern substitution expansion and then using word splitting to split the fields on the surviving IFS-represented delimiter character.

This is not a very generic solution. Furthermore, it can be argued that the comma is really the "primary" delimiter character here, and that stripping it and then depending on the space character for field splitting is simply wrong. Once again, consider my counterexample: `'Los Angeles, United States, North America'`.

Also, again, filename expansion could corrupt the expanded words, but this can be prevented by temporarily disabling globbing for the assignment with `set -f` and then `set +f`.

Also, again, all empty fields will be lost, which may or may not be a problem depending on the application.

---

[***Wrong answer #4***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13196466/4272464)

```
string='first line
second line
third line'

oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS='
'
IFS=${IFS:0:1} # this is useful to format your code with tabs
lines=( $string )
IFS="$oldIFS"
```

This is similar to **#2** and **#3** in that it uses word splitting to get the job done, only now the code explicitly sets `$IFS` to contain only the single-character field delimiter present in the input string. It should be repeated that this cannot work for multicharacter field delimiters such as the OP's comma-space delimiter. But for a single-character delimiter like the LF used in this example, it actually comes close to being perfect. The fields cannot be unintentionally split in the middle as we saw with previous wrong answers, and there is only one level of splitting, as required.

One problem is that filename expansion will corrupt affected words as described earlier, although once again this can be solved by wrapping the critical statement in `set -f` and `set +f`.

Another potential problem is that, since LF qualifies as an "IFS whitespace character" as defined earlier, all empty fields will be lost, just as in **#2** and **#3**. This would of course not be a problem if the delimiter happens to be a non-"IFS whitespace character", and depending on the application it may not matter anyway, but it does vitiate the generality of the solution.

So, to sum up, assuming you have a one-character delimiter, and it is either a non-"IFS whitespace character" or you don't care about empty fields, and you wrap the critical statement in `set -f` and `set +f`, then this solution works, but otherwise not.

(Also, for information's sake, assigning a LF to a variable in bash can be done more easily with the `$'...'` syntax, e.g. `IFS=$'\n';`.)

---

[***Wrong answer #5***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41225957/4272464)

```
countries='Paris, France, Europe'
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=', ' array=($countries)
IFS="$OIFS"
```

[Similar idea:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30744597/4272464)

```
IFS=', ' eval 'array=($string)'
```

This solution is effectively a cross between **#1** (in that it sets `$IFS` to comma-space) and **#2-4** (in that it uses word splitting to split the string into fields). Because of this, it suffers from most of the problems that afflict all of the above wrong answers, sort of like the worst of all worlds.

Also, regarding the second variant, it may seem like the `eval` call is completely unnecessary, since its argument is a single-quoted string literal, and therefore is statically known. But there's actually a very non-obvious benefit to using `eval` in this way. Normally, when you run a simple command which consists of a variable assignment *only*, meaning without an actual command word following it, the assignment takes effect in the shell environment:

```
IFS=', '; ## changes $IFS in the shell environment
```

This is true even if the simple command involves *multiple* variable assignments; again, as long as there's no command word, all variable assignments affect the shell environment:

```
IFS=', ' array=($countries); ## changes both $IFS and $array in the shell environment
```

But, if the variable assignment is attached to a command name (I like to call this a "prefix assignment") then it does *not* affect the shell environment, and instead only affects the environment of the executed command, regardless whether it is a builtin or external:

```
IFS=', ' :; ## : is a builtin command, the $IFS assignment does not outlive it
IFS=', ' env; ## env is an external command, the $IFS assignment does not outlive it
```

Relevant quote from the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html#Simple-Command-Expansion):

> If no command name results, the variable assignments affect the current shell environment. Otherwise, the variables are added to the environment of the executed command and do not affect the current shell environment.

It is possible to exploit this feature of variable assignment to change `$IFS` only temporarily, which allows us to avoid the whole save-and-restore gambit like that which is being done with the `$OIFS` variable in the first variant. But the challenge we face here is that the command we need to run is itself a mere variable assignment, and hence it would not involve a command word to make the `$IFS` assignment temporary. You might think to yourself, well why not just add a no-op command word to the statement like the [`: builtin`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) to make the `$IFS` assignment temporary? This does not work because it would then make the `$array` assignment temporary as well:

```
IFS=', ' array=($countries) :; ## fails; new $array value never escapes the : command
```

So, we're effectively at an impasse, a bit of a catch-22. But, when `eval` runs its code, it runs it in the shell environment, as if it was normal, static source code, and therefore we can run the `$array` assignment inside the `eval` argument to have it take effect in the shell environment, while the `$IFS` prefix assignment that is prefixed to the `eval` command will not outlive the `eval` command. This is exactly the trick that is being used in the second variant of this solution:

```
IFS=', ' eval 'array=($string)'; ## $IFS does not outlive the eval command, but $array does
```

So, as you can see, it's actually quite a clever trick, and accomplishes exactly what is required (at least with respect to assignment effectation) in a rather non-obvious way. I'm actually not against this trick in general, despite the involvement of `eval`; just be careful to single-quote the argument string to guard against security threats.

But again, because of the "worst of all worlds" agglomeration of problems, this is still a wrong answer to the OP's requirement.

---

[***Wrong answer #6***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35789043/4272464)

```
IFS=', '; array=(Paris, France, Europe)

IFS=' ';declare -a array=(Paris France Europe)
```

Um... what? The OP has a string variable that needs to be parsed into an array. This "answer" starts with the verbatim contents of the input string pasted into an array literal. I guess that's one way to do it.

It looks like the answerer may have assumed that the `$IFS` variable affects all bash parsing in all contexts, which is not true. From the bash manual:

> **IFS**    The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting after expansion and to split lines into words with the **read** builtin command. The default value is **<space><tab><newline>**.

So the `$IFS` special variable is actually only used in two contexts: (1) word splitting that is performed *after expansion* (meaning *not* when parsing bash source code) and (2) for splitting input lines into words by the `read` builtin.

Let me try to make this clearer. I think it might be good to draw a distinction between *parsing* and *execution*. Bash must first *parse* the source code, which obviously is a *parsing* event, and then later it *executes* the code, which is when expansion comes into the picture. Expansion is really an *execution* event. Furthermore, I take issue with the description of the `$IFS` variable that I just quoted above; rather than saying that word splitting is performed *after expansion*, I would say that word splitting is performed *during* expansion, or, perhaps even more precisely, word splitting is *part of* the expansion process. The phrase "word splitting" refers only to this step of expansion; it should never be used to refer to the parsing of bash source code, although unfortunately the docs do seem to throw around the words "split" and "words" a lot. Here's a relevant excerpt from the [linux.die.net version](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash#Expansion) of the bash manual:

> Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into words. There are seven kinds of expansion performed: *brace expansion*, *tilde expansion*, *parameter and variable expansion*, *command substitution*, *arithmetic expansion*, *word splitting*, and *pathname expansion*.
>
> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and pathname expansion.

You could argue the [GNU version](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) of the manual does slightly better, since it opts for the word "tokens" instead of "words" in the first sentence of the Expansion section:

> Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into tokens.

The important point is, `$IFS` does not change the way bash parses source code. Parsing of bash source code is actually a very complex process that involves recognition of the various elements of shell grammar, such as command sequences, command lists, pipelines, parameter expansions, arithmetic substitutions, and command substitutions. For the most part, the bash parsing process cannot be altered by user-level actions like variable assignments (actually, there are some minor exceptions to this rule; for example, see the various [`compatxx` shell settings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin), which can change certain aspects of parsing behavior on-the-fly). The upstream "words"/"tokens" that result from this complex parsing process are then expanded according to the general process of "expansion" as broken down in the above documentation excerpts, where word splitting of the expanded (expanding?) text into downstream words is simply one step of that process. Word splitting only touches text that has been spit out of a preceding expansion step; it does not affect literal text that was parsed right off the source bytestream.

---

[***Wrong answer #7***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31620022/4272464)

```
string='first line
        second line
        third line'

while read -r line; do lines+=("$line"); done <<<"$string"
```

This is one of the best solutions. Notice that we're back to using `read`. Didn't I say earlier that `read` is inappropriate because it performs two levels of splitting, when we only need one? The trick here is that you can call `read` in such a way that it effectively only does one level of splitting, specifically by splitting off only one field per invocation, which necessitates the cost of having to call it repeatedly in a loop. It's a bit of a sleight of hand, but it works.

But there are problems. First: When you provide at least one *NAME* argument to `read`, it automatically ignores leading and trailing whitespace in each field that is split off from the input string. This occurs whether `$IFS` is set to its default value or not, as described earlier in this post. Now, the OP may not care about this for his specific use-case, and in fact, it may be a desirable feature of the parsing behavior. But not everyone who wants to parse a string into fields will want this. There is a solution, however: A somewhat non-obvious usage of `read` is to pass zero *NAME* arguments. In this case, `read` will store the entire input line that it gets from the input stream in a variable named `$REPLY`, and, as a bonus, it does *not* strip leading and trailing whitespace from the value. This is a very robust usage of `read` which I've exploited frequently in my shell programming career. Here's a demonstration of the difference in behavior:

```
string=$'  a  b  \n  c  d  \n  e  f  '; ## input string

a=(); while read -r line; do a+=("$line"); done <<<"$string"; declare -p a;
## declare -a a=([0]="a  b" [1]="c  d" [2]="e  f") ## read trimmed surrounding whitespace

a=(); while read -r; do a+=("$REPLY"); done <<<"$string"; declare -p a;
## declare -a a=([0]="  a  b  " [1]="  c  d  " [2]="  e  f  ") ## no trimming
```

The second issue with this solution is that it does not actually address the case of a custom field separator, such as the OP's comma-space. As before, multicharacter separators are not supported, which is an unfortunate limitation of this solution. We could try to at least split on comma by specifying the separator to the `-d` option, but look what happens:

```
string='Paris, France, Europe';
a=(); while read -rd,; do a+=("$REPLY"); done <<<"$string"; declare -p a;
## declare -a a=([0]="Paris" [1]=" France")
```

Predictably, the unaccounted surrounding whitespace got pulled into the field values, and hence this would have to be corrected subsequently through trimming operations (this could also be done directly in the while-loop). But there's another obvious error: Europe is missing! What happened to it? The answer is that `read` returns a failing return code if it hits end-of-file (in this case we can call it end-of-string) without encountering a final field terminator on the final field. This causes the while-loop to break prematurely and we lose the final field.

Technically this same error afflicted the previous examples as well; the difference there is that the field separator was taken to be LF, which is the default when you don't specify the `-d` option, and the `<<<` ("here-string") mechanism automatically appends a LF to the string just before it feeds it as input to the command. Hence, in those cases, we sort of *accidentally* solved the problem of a dropped final field by unwittingly appending an additional dummy terminator to the input. Let's call this solution the "dummy-terminator" solution. We can apply the dummy-terminator solution manually for any custom delimiter by concatenating it against the input string ourselves when instantiating it in the here-string:

```
a=(); while read -rd,; do a+=("$REPLY"); done <<<"$string,"; declare -p a;
declare -a a=([0]="Paris" [1]=" France" [2]=" Europe")
```

There, problem solved. Another solution is to only break the while-loop if both (1) `read` returned failure and (2) `$REPLY` is empty, meaning `read` was not able to read any characters prior to hitting end-of-file. Demo:

```
a=(); while read -rd,|| [[ -n "$REPLY" ]]; do a+=("$REPLY"); done <<<"$string"; declare -p a;
## declare -a a=([0]="Paris" [1]=" France" [2]=$' Europe\n')
```

This approach also reveals the secretive LF that automatically gets appended to the here-string by the `<<<` redirection operator. It could of course be stripped off separately through an explicit trimming operation as described a moment ago, but obviously the manual dummy-terminator approach solves it directly, so we could just go with that. The manual dummy-terminator solution is actually quite convenient in that it solves both of these two problems (the dropped-final-field problem and the appended-LF problem) in one go.

So, overall, this is quite a powerful solution. It's only remaining weakness is a lack of support for multicharacter delimiters, which I will address later.

---

[***Wrong answer #8***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31620022/4272464)

```
string='first line
        second line
        third line'

readarray -t lines <<<"$string"
```

(This is actually from the same post as **#7**; the answerer provided two solutions in the same post.)

The `readarray` builtin, which is a synonym for `mapfile`, is ideal. It's a builtin command which parses a bytestream into an array variable in one shot; no messing with loops, conditionals, substitutions, or anything else. And it doesn't surreptitiously strip any whitespace from the input string. And (if `-O` is not given) it conveniently clears the target array before assigning to it. But it's still not perfect, hence my criticism of it as a "wrong answer".

First, just to get this out of the way, note that, just like the behavior of `read` when doing field-parsing, `readarray` drops the trailing field if it is empty. Again, this is probably not a concern for the OP, but it could be for some use-cases. I'll come back to this in a moment.

Second, as before, it does not support multicharacter delimiters. I'll give a fix for this in a moment as well.

Third, the solution as written does not parse the OP's input string, and in fact, it cannot be used as-is to parse it. I'll expand on this momentarily as well.

For the above reasons, I still consider this to be a "wrong answer" to the OP's question. Below I'll give what I consider to be the right answer.

---

**Right answer**

Here's a naïve attempt to make **#8** work by just specifying the `-d` option:

```
string='Paris, France, Europe';
readarray -td, a <<<"$string"; declare -p a;
## declare -a a=([0]="Paris" [1]=" France" [2]=$' Europe\n')
```

We see the result is identical to the result we got from the double-conditional approach of the looping `read` solution discussed in **#7**. We can *almost* solve this with the manual dummy-terminator trick:

```
readarray -td, a <<<"$string,"; declare -p a;
## declare -a a=([0]="Paris" [1]=" France" [2]=" Europe" [3]=$'\n')
```

The problem here is that `readarray` preserved the trailing field, since the `<<<` redirection operator appended the LF to the input string, and therefore the trailing field was *not* empty (otherwise it would've been dropped). We can take care of this by explicitly unsetting the final array element after-the-fact:

```
readarray -td, a <<<"$string,"; unset 'a[-1]'; declare -p a;
## declare -a a=([0]="Paris" [1]=" France" [2]=" Europe")
```

The only two problems that remain, which are actually related, are (1) the extraneous whitespace that needs to be trimmed, and (2) the lack of support for multicharacter delimiters.

The whitespace could of course be trimmed afterward (for example, see [How to trim whitespace from a Bash variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-a-bash-variable)). But if we can hack a multicharacter delimiter, then that would solve both problems in one shot.

Unfortunately, there's no *direct* way to get a multicharacter delimiter to work. The best solution I've thought of is to preprocess the input string to replace the multicharacter delimiter with a single-character delimiter that will be guaranteed not to collide with the contents of the input string. The only character that has this guarantee is the [NUL byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). This is because, in bash (though not in zsh, incidentally), variables cannot contain the NUL byte. This preprocessing step can be done inline in a process substitution. Here's how to do it using [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/):

```
readarray -td '' a < <(awk '{ gsub(/, /,"\0"); print; }' <<<"$string, "); unset 'a[-1]';
declare -p a;
## declare -a a=([0]="Paris" [1]="France" [2]="Europe")
```

There, finally! This solution will not erroneously split fields in the middle, will not cut out prematurely, will not drop empty fields, will not corrupt itself on filename expansions, will not automatically strip leading and trailing whitespace, will not leave a stowaway LF on the end, does not require loops, and does not settle for a single-character delimiter.

---

**Trimming solution**

Lastly, I wanted to demonstrate my own fairly intricate trimming solution using the obscure `-C callback` option of `readarray`. Unfortunately, I've run out of room against Stack Overflow's draconian 30,000 character post limit, so I won't be able to explain it. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

```
function mfcb { local val="$4"; "$1"; eval "$2[$3]=\$val;"; };
function val_ltrim { if [[ "$val" =~ ^[[:space:]]+ ]]; then val="${val:${#BASH_REMATCH[0]}}"; fi; };
function val_rtrim { if [[ "$val" =~ [[:space:]]+$ ]]; then val="${val:0:${#val}-${#BASH_REMATCH[0]}}"; fi; };
function val_trim { val_ltrim; val_rtrim; };
readarray -c1 -C 'mfcb val_trim a' -td, <<<"$string,"; unset 'a[-1]'; declare -p a;
## declare -a a=([0]="Paris" [1]="France" [2]="Europe")
```

Comment: It may also be helpful to note (though understandably you had no room to do so) that the `-d` option to `readarray` first appears in Bash 4.4.

Comment: Great answer (+1). If you change your awk to `awk '{ gsub(/,[ ]+|$/,"\0"); print }'` and eliminate that concatenation of the final `", "`  then you don't have to go through the gymnastics on eliminating the final record. So: `readarray -td '' a < <(awk '{ gsub(/,[ ]+/,"\0"); print; }' <<<"$string")` on Bash that supports `readarray`. Note your method is Bash 4.4+ I think because of the `-d` in `readarray`

Comment: You state: *Unfortunately, there's no direct way to get a multicharacter delimiter to work.* There is actually directly in Bash: You can use a regex similar to what you would use in `sed` or `awk`. An example [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47500443/298607).

Comment: @dawg Very cool solution! See my comments and edit to your answer.

Comment: @datUser That's unfortunate. Your version of bash must be too old for `readarray`. In this case, you can use the second-best solution built on `read`. I'm referring to this: `a=(); while read -rd,; do a+=("$REPLY"); done <<<"$string,";` (with the `awk` substitution if you need multicharacter delimiter support). Let me know if you run into any problems; I'm pretty sure this solution should work on fairly old versions of bash, back to version 2-something, released like two decades ago.

Comment: Wow, what a brilliant answer! Hee hee, my response: ditched the bash script and fired up python!

Comment: @datUser bash on OSX is still stuck at 3.2 (released ca. 2007); I've used the bash found in Homebrew to get 4.X bash versions on OS X

Comment: readarray: -d: invalid option, are you sure your answer is right?

Comment: What exactly do I have to change if I do not want ", " but "|" as a delimiter?

Comment: I'd move your right answers up to the top, I had to scroll through a lot of rubbish to find out how to do it properly :-)

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing that will convince you to never code in bash. An astoundingly simple task that has 8 incorrect solutions. Btw, this is without a design constraint of, "Make it as obscure and finicky as possible"

Comment: I've heard Editing is the bulk of writing.  While I appreciate the thoroughness, if you could have cut this down to < 5K characters and focused on the answer it'd be a better answer than it is.

Comment: @dawg The solution without unset (`readarray -td '' a < <(awk '{ gsub(/,[ ]+/,"\0"); print; }' <<<"$string")`) causes the last array element to have a trailing newline on my system (Bash 5.0)

Comment: I will use this : `readarray -td, a < <(printf "%s" "$string"); declare -p a` no trailing `\n` hth

Comment: @Marcus this is true as awk its `print` statement adds an `ORS` at the end which by default is the <newline>-character

Comment: @bgoldst Your "Right answer" implemented with gawk only works correctly for some delimiters, so arguably is wrong :-) For example string=`a-` and delimiter=`--` should result in `a-` but your code outputs `a`

Comment: @jhnc It is logically incorrect in the first place to select a multicharacter delimiter to delimit values whose final character(s), when concatenated with the subsequent delimiter, produce a spurious delimiter, `--` in your example. My answer is fine.

Comment: @fbicknel, I though you were being facetious when you said "It may also be helpful to note (though understandably you had no room to do so)," then I read the end of bgoldst's post "Unfortunately, I've run out of room against Stack Overflow's draconian 30,000 character post limit..."  Extremely informative, bgoldst. Thank you.

Comment: One tiny thing. What if my separator contains the '/' character, or any other special character that would be misinterpreted by bash or awk? E.g. I want to split "I//am//your//nightmare" into an array of ["I", "am", "your", "nightmare"]? How to rewrite this so that instead it separates by what's in the variable $SEP?

Comment: You buried the lede.  You should at least mention at the top that you have a "right answer" at the bottom of your post.  You could also clearly mark which of the four code blocks in your right answer section you consider most right.

Answer (score 258):

Here is a way without setting IFS:

```
string="1:2:3:4:5"
set -f                      # avoid globbing (expansion of *).
array=(${string//:/ })
for i in "${!array[@]}"
do
    echo "$i=>${array[i]}"
done
```

The idea is using string replacement:

```
${string//substring/replacement}
```

to replace all matches of $substring with white space and then using the substituted string to initialize a array:

```
(element1 element2 ... elementN)
```

Note: this answer makes use of the [split+glob operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108963/79743). Thus, to prevent expansion of some characters (such as `*`) it is a good idea to pause globbing for this script.

Comment: Used this approach... until I came across a long string to split. 100% CPU for more than a minute (then I killed it). It's a pity because this method allows to split by a string, not some character in IFS.

Comment: 100% CPU time for one than a minute sounds to me like there must be something wrong somewhere. Just how long was that string, is it MB or GB sized ? I think, normally, if you're just going to need a small string split, you want to stay within Bash, but if it's a huge file, I would execute something like Perl to do it.

Comment: WARNING: Just ran into a problem with this approach. If you have an element named * you will get all the elements of your cwd as well. thus string="1:2:3:4:*" will give some unexpected and possibly dangerous results depending on your implementation. Did not get the same error with (IFS=', ' read -a array <<< "$string") and this one seems safe to use.

Comment: works in basic shell, while the other answer does not. Thanks!

Comment: quoting `${string//:/ }` prevents shell expansion

Comment: I had to use the following on OSX:

`array=(${string//:/ })`

Comment: As with @Markouver, I did not get the expected result directly following the answer, and instead had to use an unquoted version.

Comment: @AndrewWhite The edit to add quoting prevents shell splitting and breaks the answer. It is still vulnerable to expansion of * and related issues.

Comment: This answer is based on splitting by the shell, it would be wise to avoid globbing expansion to avoid expansion of an `*`. Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: @BinaryZebra fair enough. The answer as it stood certainly didn't work for me due to glob expansion and quoting it resolved that problem. Sorry if I was mistaken.

Comment: I like this a lot better than mucking with IFS. And tons faster than 'split'.

Comment: This worked for me when IFS barfed on me trying to process a string that had a "/" as a separator. (Yes, I even tried to escape it.) Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, I love this non-IFS solution!

Comment: unbeknownst to everyone here the splitting is still using `IFS`. It's just using the default value for `IFS` is the space, tab, new-line characters.

Comment: @Jim What if elements in the `string` contain space?

Answer (score 158):

```
t="one,two,three"
a=($(echo "$t" | tr ',' '\n'))
echo "${a[2]}"
```

Prints three

Comment: I actually prefer this approach. Simple.

Comment: I copied and pasted this and it did did not work with echo, but did work when I used it in a for loop.

Comment: This does not work as stated. @Jmoney38 or shrimpwagon if you can paste this in a terminal and get the desired output, please paste the result here.

Comment: @abalter Works for me with `a=($(echo $t | tr ',' "\n"))`. Same result with  `a=($(echo $t | tr ',' ' '))`.

Comment: @procrastinator I just tried it in`VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"` in a `bash` shell, and the last `echo` just prints a blank line. What version of Linux and which shell are you using? Unfortunately, can't display terminal session in a comment.

Comment: I rolled it back to the original, which worked. The edit on 10/16/2015 broke it. Note that backticks are deprecated and `$()` is preferred. The person who made the edit just put that correction in the wrong place. Also, the variables should be quoted. I've made an edit to reflect these changes.

Comment: Works smoothly on Ubuntu Trusty! The simplest and neat answer.

Comment: Although it doesn't use the values from the original question, this is the best solution. It's clean and doesn't involve IFS. _And yes, it will work  with original question if `','` is replaced with `', '`_

Comment: Was this one of the ["wrong answers"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45201229/605356)?  (Said post may be thorough, but it's long enough without a summary to where I'm unable to currently read it; no offense intended.)  Regardless, it seems to work nicely for me.

Comment: This is a simple solution but unfortunately doesn't supports strings with spaces.

Comment: One liner for iterating: `for x in ${a[@]}; do echo $x; done`

Comment: simple and works beautifully. I know there are many edge cases one could consider, but I feel it's much more productive to go with the method with minimum amount of code, filtering out the edge cases beforehand if necessary.

Comment: fails due to wordsplitting,globbing,etc. consider `t='1 /*,2a 2b,3'` where output should have 3 elements `1 /*`, `2a 2b`, `3`. also fails on multi-character delimiters

Answer (score 34):

The accepted answer works for values in one line.
 If the variable has several lines:

```
string='first line
        second line
        third line'
```

We need a very different command to get all lines:

`while read -r line; do lines+=("$line"); done <<<"$string"`

Or the much simpler bash *readarray*:

```
readarray -t lines <<<"$string"
```

Printing all lines is very easy taking advantage of a printf feature:

```
printf ">[%s]\n" "${lines[@]}"

>[first line]
>[        second line]
>[        third line]
```

Comment: While not every solution works for every situation, your mention of readarray... replaced my last two hours with 5 minutes... you got my vote

Comment: That `while read` loop will not produce the shown output as it'll strip leading/trailing white space. It'd need to be `while IFS= read -r line; do lines+=("$line"); done <<<"$string"` to produce the shown output.

Answer (score 32):

Sometimes it happened to me that the method described in the accepted answer didn't work, especially if the separator is a carriage return.
In those cases I solved in this way:

```
string='first line
second line
third line'

oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS='
'
IFS=${IFS:0:1} # this is useful to format your code with tabs
lines=( $string )
IFS="$oldIFS"

for line in "${lines[@]}"
    do
        echo "--> $line"
done
```

Comment: +1 This completely worked for me. I needed to put multiple strings, divided by a newline, into an array, and `read -a arr <<< "$strings"` did not work with `IFS=$'\n'`.

Comment: [Here is the answer to make the accepted answer work when the delimiter is a newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417414/can-i-put-strings-divided-by-newlines-into-an-array-using-the-read-builtin).

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the original question.

Answer (score 23):

if you use macOS and can't use readarray, you can simply do this-

```
MY_STRING="string1 string2 string3"
array=($MY_STRING)
```

To iterate over the elements:

```
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo $element
done
```

Comment: While this works great, it also may lead to expanding the `MY_STRING` values if they contains wildcards...

Comment: This answer does not get rid of the commas.

Comment: This does not work on macOS 12.12. The array is produced without splitting anything, so all elements are crammed into the first element.

Answer (score 18):

This works for me on OSX:

```sh
string="1 2 3 4 5"
declare -a array=($string)
```

If your string has different delimiter, just 1st replace those with space:

```sh
string="1,2,3,4,5"
delimiter=","
declare -a array=($(echo $string | tr "$delimiter" " "))
```

Simple :-)

Comment: Works for both Bash and Zsh which is a plus!

Comment: finally a working answer for zsh in macOS!

Comment: That can't possibly work in general due to `$string` being unquoted.

Answer (score 15):

I was curious about the relative performance of the "Right answer"
in the popular answer by @bgoldst, with its apparent decrying of loops,
so I have done a simple benchmark of it against three pure bash implementations.

In summary, I suggest:

1. for string length < 4k or so, pure bash is faster than gawk
2. for delimiter length < 10 and string length < 256k, pure bash is comparable to gawk
3. for delimiter length >> 10 and string length < 64k or so, pure bash is "acceptable";
   and gawk is less than 5x faster
4. for string length < 512k or so, gawk is "acceptable"

I arbitrarily define "acceptable" as "takes < 0.5s to split the string".

---

I am taking the problem to be to take a bash string and split it into a bash array, using an arbitrary-length delimiter string (not regex).

```
# in: $1=delim, $2=string
# out: sets array a
```

My pure bash implementations are:

```
# naive approach - slow
split_byStr_bash_naive(){
    a=()
    local prev=""
    local cdr="$2"
    [[ -z "${cdr}" ]] && a+=("")
    while [[ "$cdr" != "$prev" ]]; do
        prev="$cdr"
        a+=( "${cdr%%"$1"*}" )
        cdr="${cdr#*"$1"}"
    done
    # echo $( declare -p a | md5sum; declare -p a )
}
```

```
# use lengths wherever possible - faster
split_byStr_bash_faster(){
    a=()
    local car=""
    local cdr="$2"
    while
        car="${cdr%%"$1"*}"
        a+=("$car")
        cdr="${cdr:${#car}}"
        (( ${#cdr} ))
    do
        cdr="${cdr:${#1}}"
    done
    # echo $( declare -p a | md5sum; declare -p a )
}
```

```
# use pattern substitution and readarray - fastest
split_byStr_bash_sub(){
        a=()
        local delim="$1" string="$2"

        delim="${delim//=/=-}"
        delim="${delim//$'\n'/=n}"

        string="${string//=/=-}"
        string="${string//$'\n'/=n}"

        readarray -td $'\n' a <<<"${string//"$delim"/$'\n'}"

        local len=${#a[@]} i s
        for (( i=0; i<len; i++ )); do
                s="${a[i]//=n/$'\n'}"
                a[i]="${s//=-/=}"
        done
        # echo $( declare -p a | md5sum; declare -p a )
}
```

The initial `-z` test in in the naive version handles the case of a zero-length
string being passed. Without the test, the output array is empty;
with it, the array has a single zero-length element.

Replacing `readarray` with `while read` gives < 10% slowdown.

---

This is the gawk implementation I used:

```
split_byRE_gawk(){
    readarray -td '' a < <(awk '{gsub(/'"$1"'/,"\0")}1' <<<"$2$1")
    unset 'a[-1]'
    # echo $( declare -p a | md5sum; declare -p a )
}
```

Obviously, in the general case, the delim argument will need to be sanitised,
as gawk expects a regex, and gawk-special characters could cause problems.
Also, as-is, the implementation won't correctly handle newlines in the delimiter.

Since gawk is being used, a generalised version that handles more arbitrary
delimiters could be:

```
split_byREorStr_gawk(){
    local delim=$1
    local string=$2
    local useRegex=${3:+1}  # if set, delimiter is regex

    readarray -td '' a < <(
        export delim
        gawk -v re="$useRegex" '
            BEGIN {
                RS = FS = "\0"
                ORS = ""
                d = ENVIRON["delim"]

                # cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37039138
                if (!re) gsub(/[\\.^$(){}\[\]|*+?]/,"\\\\&",d)
            }
            gsub(d"|\n$","\0")
        ' <<<"$string"
    )
    # echo $( declare -p a | md5sum; declare -p a )
}
```

or the same idea in Perl:

```
split_byREorStr_perl(){
    local delim=$1
    local string=$2
    local regex=$3  # if set, delimiter is regex

    readarray -td '' a < <(
        export delim regex
        perl -0777pe '
            $d = $ENV{delim};
            $d = "\Q$d\E" if ! $ENV{regex};
            s/$d|\n$/\0/g;
        ' <<<"$string"
    )
    # echo $( declare -p a | md5sum; declare -p a )
}
```

---

The implementations produce identical output, tested by comparing md5sum separately.

Note that if input had been ambiguous ("logically incorrect" as @bgoldst puts it),
behaviour would diverge slightly. For example, with delimiter `--` and string `a-` or `a---`:

- @goldst's code returns: `declare -a a=([0]="a")` or `declare -a a=([0]="a" [1]="")`
- mine return: `declare -a a=([0]="a-")` or `declare -a a=([0]="a" [1]="-")`

---

Arguments were derived with simple Perl scripts from:

```
delim="-=-="
base="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345"
```

Here are the tables of timing results (in seconds) for 3 different types
of string and delimiter argument.

- `#s` - length of string argument
- `#d` - length of delim argument
- `=` - performance break-even point
- `!` - "acceptable" performance limit (bash) is somewhere around here
- `!!` - "acceptable" performance limit (gawk) is somewhere around here
- `-` - function took too long
- `<!>` - gawk command failed to run

**Type 1**

```
d=$(perl -e "print( '$delim' x (7*2**$n) )")
s=$(perl -e "print( '$delim' x (7*2**$n) . '$base' x (7*2**$n) )")
```

|  | n | #s | #d | gawk | b_sub | b_faster | b_naive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 0 | 252 | 28 | 0.002 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
|  | 1 | 504 | 56 | 0.005 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.001 |
|  | 2 | 1008 | 112 | 0.005 | 0.001 | 0.000 | 0.003 |
|  | 3 | 2016 | 224 | 0.006 | 0.001 | 0.000 | 0.009 |
|  | 4 | 4032 | 448 | 0.007 | 0.002 | 0.001 | 0.048 |
| = | 5 | 8064 | 896 | **0.014** | **0.008** | **0.005** | 0.377 |
|  | 6 | 16128 | 1792 | 0.018 | 0.029 | 0.017 | (2.214) |
|  | 7 | 32256 | 3584 | 0.033 | 0.057 | 0.039 | (15.16) |
| ! | 8 | 64512 | 7168 | **0.063** | **0.214** | **0.128** | - |
|  | 9 | 129024 | 14336 | 0.111 | (0.826) | (0.602) | - |
|  | 10 | 258048 | 28672 | 0.214 | (3.383) | (2.652) | - |
| !! | 11 | 516096 | 57344 | **0.430** | (13.46) | (11.00) | - |
|  | 12 | 1032192 | 114688 | (0.834) | (58.38) | - | - |
|  | 13 | 2064384 | 229376 | <!> | (228.9) | - | - |

**Type 2**

```
d=$(perl -e "print( '$delim' x ($n) )")
s=$(perl -e "print( ('$delim' x ($n) . '$base' x $n ) x (2**($n-1)) )")
```

|  | n | #s | #d | gawk | b_sub | b_faster | b_naive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.003 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
|  | 1 | 36 | 4 | 0.003 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
|  | 2 | 144 | 8 | 0.005 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
|  | 3 | 432 | 12 | 0.005 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
|  | 4 | 1152 | 16 | 0.005 | 0.001 | 0.001 | 0.002 |
|  | 5 | 2880 | 20 | 0.005 | 0.001 | 0.002 | 0.003 |
|  | 6 | 6912 | 24 | 0.006 | 0.003 | 0.009 | 0.014 |
| = | 7 | 16128 | 28 | **0.012** | **0.012** | 0.037 | 0.044 |
|  | 8 | 36864 | 32 | 0.023 | 0.044 | 0.167 | 0.187 |
| ! | 9 | 82944 | 36 | **0.049** | **0.192** | (0.753) | (0.840) |
|  | 10 | 184320 | 40 | 0.097 | (0.925) | (3.682) | (4.016) |
|  | 11 | 405504 | 44 | 0.204 | (4.709) | (18.00) | (19.58) |
| !! | 12 | 884736 | 48 | **0.444** | (22.17) | - | - |
|  | 13 | 1916928 | 52 | (1.019) | (102.4) | - | - |

**Type 3**

```
d=$(perl -e "print( '$delim' x (2**($n-1)) )")
s=$(perl -e "print( ('$delim' x (2**($n-1)) . '$base' x (2**($n-1)) ) x ($n) )")
```

|  | n | #s | #d | gawk | b_sub | b_faster | b_naive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
|  | 1 | 36 | 4 | 0.004 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
|  | 2 | 144 | 8 | 0.003 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
|  | 3 | 432 | 16 | 0.003 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
|  | 4 | 1152 | 32 | 0.005 | 0.001 | 0.001 | 0.002 |
|  | 5 | 2880 | 64 | 0.005 | 0.002 | 0.001 | 0.003 |
|  | 6 | 6912 | 128 | 0.006 | 0.003 | 0.003 | 0.014 |
| = | 7 | 16128 | 256 | **0.012** | **0.011** | **0.010** | 0.077 |
|  | 8 | 36864 | 512 | 0.023 | 0.046 | 0.046 | (0.513) |
| ! | 9 | 82944 | 1024 | **0.049** | **0.195** | **0.197** | (3.850) |
|  | 10 | 184320 | 2048 | 0.103 | (0.951) | (1.061) | (31.84) |
|  | 11 | 405504 | 4096 | 0.222 | (4.796) | - | - |
| !! | 12 | 884736 | 8192 | **0.473** | (22.88) | - | - |
|  | 13 | 1916928 | 16384 | (1.126) | (105.4) | - | - |

---

**Summary of delimiters length 1..10**

As short delimiters are probably more likely than long,
summarised below are the results of varying delimiter length
between 1 and 10 (results for 2..9 mostly elided as very similar).

```
s1=$(perl -e "print( '$d' . '$base' x (7*2**$n) )")
s2=$(perl -e "print( ('$d' . '$base' x $n ) x (2**($n-1)) )")
s3=$(perl -e "print( ('$d' . '$base' x (2**($n-1)) ) x ($n) )")
```

**bash_sub < gawk**

| string | n | #s | #d | gawk | b_sub | b_faster | b_naive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | 10 | 229377 | 1 | 0.131 | 0.089 | 1.709 | - |
| s1 | 10 | 229386 | 10 | 0.142 | 0.095 | 1.907 | - |
| s2 | 8 | 32896 | 1 | 0.022 | 0.007 | 0.148 | 0.168 |
| s2 | 8 | 34048 | 10 | 0.021 | 0.021 | 0.163 | 0.179 |
| s3 | 12 | 786444 | 1 | 0.436 | 0.468 | - | - |
| s3 | 12 | 786456 | 2 | 0.434 | 0.317 | - | - |
| s3 | 12 | 786552 | 10 | 0.438 | 0.333 | - | - |

**bash_sub < 0.5s**

| string | n | #s | #d | gawk | b_sub | b_faster | b_naive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | 11 | 458753 | 1 | 0.256 | 0.332 | (7.089) | - |
| s1 | 11 | 458762 | 10 | 0.269 | 0.387 | (8.003) | - |
| s2 | 11 | 361472 | 1 | 0.205 | 0.283 | (14.54) | - |
| s2 | 11 | 363520 | 3 | 0.207 | 0.462 | (16.66) | - |
| s3 | 12 | 786444 | 1 | 0.436 | 0.468 | - | - |
| s3 | 12 | 786456 | 2 | 0.434 | 0.317 | - | - |
| s3 | 12 | 786552 | 10 | 0.438 | 0.333 | - | - |

**gawk < 0.5s**

| string | n | #s | $d | gawk | b_sub | b_faster | b_naive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | 11 | 458753 | 1 | 0.256 | 0.332 | (7.089) | - |
| s1 | 11 | 458762 | 10 | 0.269 | 0.387 | (8.003) | - |
| s2 | 12 | 788480 | 1 | 0.440 | (1.252) | - | - |
| s2 | 12 | 806912 | 10 | 0.449 | (4.968) | - | - |
| s3 | 12 | 786444 | 1 | 0.436 | 0.468 | - | - |
| s3 | 12 | 786456 | 2 | 0.434 | 0.317 | - | - |
| s3 | 12 | 786552 | 10 | 0.438 | 0.333 | - | - |

(I'm not entirely sure why bash_sub with s>160k and d=1 was consistently slower than d>1 for s3.)

All tests carried out with bash 5.0.17 on an Intel i7-7500U running xubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Perfect answer! Total mastery of the subject! The "split_byStr_bash_faster" function was an excellent implementation. **The amount of upvotes for this post does not do justice to the quality of the answer presented**.

Comment: If it helps, an adaptation of the "split_byStr_bash_faster" function can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73263419/3223785 . 

Comment: This is BOSS-level analysis, very insightful answer.

Answer (score 12):

The key to splitting your string into an array is the multi character delimiter of `", "`. Any solution using `IFS` for multi character delimiters is inherently wrong since IFS is a set of those characters, not a string.

If you assign `IFS=", "` then the string will break on EITHER `","` OR `" "` or any combination of them which is not an accurate representation of the two character delimiter of `", "`.

You can use `awk` or `sed` to split the string, with process substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="Paris, France, Europe"
array=()
while read -r -d $'\0' each; do   # use a NUL terminated field separator 
    array+=("$each")
done < <(printf "%s" "$str" | awk '{ gsub(/,[ ]+|$/,"\0"); print }')
declare -p array
# declare -a array=([0]="Paris" [1]="France" [2]="Europe") output
```

It is more efficient to use a regex you directly in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="Paris, France, Europe"

array=()
while [[ $str =~ ([^,]+)(,[ ]+|$) ]]; do
    array+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")   # capture the field
    i=${#BASH_REMATCH}              # length of field + delimiter
    str=${str:i}                    # advance the string by that length
done                                # the loop deletes $str, so make a copy if needed

declare -p array
# declare -a array=([0]="Paris" [1]="France" [2]="Europe") output...
```

With the second form, there is no sub shell and it will be inherently faster.

---

**Edit by bgoldst:** Here are some benchmarks comparing my `readarray` solution to dawg's regex solution, and I also included the `read` solution for the heck of it (note: I slightly modified the regex solution for greater harmony with my solution) (also see my comments below the post):

```
## competitors
function c_readarray { readarray -td '' a < <(awk '{ gsub(/, /,"\0"); print; };' <<<"$1, "); unset 'a[-1]'; };
function c_read { a=(); local REPLY=''; while read -r -d ''; do a+=("$REPLY"); done < <(awk '{ gsub(/, /,"\0"); print; };' <<<"$1, "); };
function c_regex { a=(); local s="$1, "; while [[ $s =~ ([^,]+),\  ]]; do a+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"); s=${s:${#BASH_REMATCH}}; done; };

## helper functions
function rep {
    local -i i=-1;
    for ((i = 0; i<$1; ++i)); do
        printf %s "$2";
    done;
}; ## end rep()

function testAll {
    local funcs=();
    local args=();
    local func='';
    local -i rc=-1;
    while [[ "$1" != ':' ]]; do
        func="$1";
        if [[ ! "$func" =~ ^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$ ]]; then
            echo "bad function name: $func" >&2;
            return 2;
        fi;
        funcs+=("$func");
        shift;
    done;
    shift;
    args=("$@");
    for func in "${funcs[@]}"; do
        echo -n "$func ";
        { time $func "${args[@]}" >/dev/null 2>&1; } 2>&1| tr '\n' '/';
        rc=${PIPESTATUS[0]}; if [[ $rc -ne 0 ]]; then echo "[$rc]"; else echo; fi;
    done| column -ts/;
}; ## end testAll()

function makeStringToSplit {
    local -i n=$1; ## number of fields
    if [[ $n -lt 0 ]]; then echo "bad field count: $n" >&2; return 2; fi;
    if [[ $n -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo;
    elif [[ $n -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo 'first field';
    elif [[ "$n" -eq 2 ]]; then
        echo 'first field, last field';
    else
        echo "first field, $(rep $[$1-2] 'mid field, ')last field";
    fi;
}; ## end makeStringToSplit()

function testAll_splitIntoArray {
    local -i n=$1; ## number of fields in input string
    local s='';
    echo "===== $n field$(if [[ $n -ne 1 ]]; then echo 's'; fi;) =====";
    s="$(makeStringToSplit "$n")";
    testAll c_readarray c_read c_regex : "$s";
}; ## end testAll_splitIntoArray()

## results
testAll_splitIntoArray 1;
## ===== 1 field =====
## c_readarray   real  0m0.067s   user 0m0.000s   sys  0m0.000s
## c_read        real  0m0.064s   user 0m0.000s   sys  0m0.000s
## c_regex       real  0m0.000s   user 0m0.000s   sys  0m0.000s
##
testAll_splitIntoArray 10;
## ===== 10 fields =====
## c_readarray   real  0m0.067s   user 0m0.000s   sys  0m0.000s
## c_read        real  0m0.064s   user 0m0.000s   sys  0m0.000s
## c_regex       real  0m0.001s   user 0m0.000s   sys  0m0.000s
##
testAll_splitIntoArray 100;
## ===== 100 fields =====
## c_readarray   real  0m0.069s   user 0m0.000s   sys  0m0.062s
## c_read        real  0m0.065s   user 0m0.000s   sys  0m0.046s
## c_regex       real  0m0.005s   user 0m0.000s   sys  0m0.000s
##
testAll_splitIntoArray 1000;
## ===== 1000 fields =====
## c_readarray   real  0m0.084s   user 0m0.031s   sys  0m0.077s
## c_read        real  0m0.092s   user 0m0.031s   sys  0m0.046s
## c_regex       real  0m0.125s   user 0m0.125s   sys  0m0.000s
##
testAll_splitIntoArray 10000;
## ===== 10000 fields =====
## c_readarray   real  0m0.209s   user 0m0.093s   sys  0m0.108s
## c_read        real  0m0.333s   user 0m0.234s   sys  0m0.109s
## c_regex       real  0m9.095s   user 0m9.078s   sys  0m0.000s
##
testAll_splitIntoArray 100000;
## ===== 100000 fields =====
## c_readarray   real  0m1.460s   user 0m0.326s   sys  0m1.124s
## c_read        real  0m2.780s   user 0m1.686s   sys  0m1.092s
## c_regex       real  17m38.208s   user 15m16.359s   sys  2m19.375s
##
```

Comment: Very cool solution! I never thought of using a loop on a regex match, nifty use of `$BASH_REMATCH`. It works, and does indeed avoid spawning subshells. +1 from me. However, by way of criticism, the regex itself is a little non-ideal, in that it appears you were forced to duplicate part of the delimiter token (specifically the comma) so as to work around the lack of support for non-greedy multipliers (also lookarounds) in ERE ("extended" regex flavor built into bash). This makes it a little less generic and robust.

Comment: Secondly, I did some benchmarking, and although the performance is better than the other solutions for smallish strings, it worsens exponentially due to the repeated string-rebuilding, becoming catastrophic for very large strings. See my edit to your answer.

Comment: @bgoldst: What a cool benchmark! In defense of the regex, for 10's or 100's of thousands of fields (what the regex is splitting) there would probably be some form of record (like `\n` delimited text lines) comprising those fields so the catastrophic slow-down would likely not occur. If you have a string with 100,000 fields -- maybe Bash is not ideal ;-)  Thanks for the benchmark. I learned a thing or two.

Comment: Echoing some of comments for the @bgoldst answer, `c_readarray` won't work for pre v4.4 Bash. `c_read` and `c_regex` work just fine.
Where might you find such 'old' Bash version you ask?? In distros like RHEL7.9, I tells ya.

Comment: I couldn't see how to generalise your answer, as bash doesn't have ungreedy regex, but I've come up with a method using pattern substitution which seems to run at a comparable speed to the @bgoldst gawk up to ~256k characters, as long as delimiter is short (<10 or so). https://stackoverflow.com/a/73225463/10971581

Answer (score 11):

This is similar to the [approach by Jmoney38](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31405855/347339), but using sed:

```
string="1,2,3,4"
array=(`echo $string | sed 's/,/\n/g'`)
echo ${array[0]}
```

Prints 1

Comment: it prints 1 2 3 4 in my case

Comment: This basically just cribs the `tr` answer and makes it worse. Now a more complex tool is involved with a more complex syntax and regular expressions. Moreover, the modern `$()` syntax in the original has been replaced by the obsolescent backticks.

Answer (score 7):

`enter code here`**Pure bash multi-character delimiter solution.**

As others have pointed out in this thread, the OP's question gave an example of a comma delimited string to be parsed into an array, but did not indicate if he/she was only interested in comma delimiters, single character delimiters, or multi-character delimiters.

Since Google tends to rank this answer at or near the top of search results, I wanted to provide readers with a strong answer to the question of multiple character delimiters, since that is also mentioned in at least one response.

If you're in search of a solution to a multi-character delimiter problem, I suggest reviewing [Mallikarjun M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6427595/mallikarjun-m)'s post, in particular the response from [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf)
who provides this elegant pure BASH solution using parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
str="LearnABCtoABCSplitABCaABCString"
delimiter=ABC
s=$str$delimiter
array=();
while [[ $s ]]; do
    array+=( "${s%%"$delimiter"*}" );
    s=${s#*"$delimiter"};
done;
declare -p array
```

Link to [cited comment/referenced post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686922/howto-split-a-string-on-a-multi-character-delimiter-in-bash#comment82225797_47633817)

Link to cited question: [Howto split a string on a multi-character delimiter in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686922/howto-split-a-string-on-a-multi-character-delimiter-in-bash)

---

**Update 3 Aug 2022**

[xebeche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196133/xebeche) raised a good point in comments below. After reviewing their suggested edits, I've revised the script provided by [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf), and added remarks for ease of understanding what the script is doing. I also changed the double brackets [[]] to single brackets, for greater compatibility since many SHell variants do not support double bracket notation. In this case, for BaSH, the logic works inside single or double brackets.

```
#!/bin/bash
  
str="LearnABCtoABCSplitABCABCaABCStringABC"
delimiter="ABC"
array=()

while [ "$str" ]; do

    # parse next sub-string, left of next delimiter
    substring="${str%%"$delimiter"*}" 

    # when substring = delimiter, truncate leading delimiter
    # (i.e. pattern is "$delimiter$delimiter")
    [ -z "$substring" ] && str="${str#"$delimiter"}" && continue

    # create next array element with parsed substring
    array+=( "$substring" )

    # remaining string to the right of delimiter becomes next string to be evaluated
    str="${str:${#substring}}"

    # prevent infinite loop when last substring = delimiter
    [ "$str" == "$delimiter" ] && break

done

declare -p array
```

Without the comments:

```
#!/bin/bash
str="LearnABCtoABCSplitABCABCaABCStringABC"
delimiter="ABC"
array=()
while [ "$str" ]; do
    substring="${str%%"$delimiter"*}" 
    [ -z "$substring" ] && str="${str#"$delimiter"}" && continue
    array+=( "$substring" )
    str="${str:${#substring}}"
    [ "$str" == "$delimiter" ] && break
done
declare -p array
```

Comment: See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686922/howto-split-a-string-on-a-multi-character-delimiter-in-bash#comment99425158_47633817) for a similar but improved approach.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

string="a | b c"
pattern=' | '

# replaces pattern with newlines
splitted="$(sed "s/$pattern/\n/g" <<< "$string")"

# Reads lines and put them in array
readarray -t array2 <<< "$splitted"

# Prints number of elements
echo ${#array2[@]}
# Prints all elements
for a in "${array2[@]}"; do
        echo "> '$a'"
done
```

This solution works for larger delimiters (more than one char). 
Doesn't work if you have a newline already in the original string

Answer (score 1):

This works for the given data:

```
$ aaa='Paris, France, Europe'
$ mapfile -td ',' aaaa < <(echo -n "${aaa//, /,}")
$ declare -p aaaa
```

Result:

```
declare -a aaaa=([0]="Paris" [1]="France" [2]="Europe")
```

And it will also work for extended data with spaces, such as "New York":

```
$ aaa="New York, Paris, New Jersey, Hampshire"
$ mapfile -td ',' aaaa < <(echo -n "${aaa//, /,}")
$ declare -p aaaa
```

Result:

```
declare -a aaaa=([0]="New York" [1]="Paris" [2]="New Jersey" [3]="Hampshire")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure bash function which works for empty elements, multi-char-separators, globs etc.

```
# Usage: split_str_by "a,b,c" ,  # result is in "${__ret[@]}"
split_str_by(){
    local s="$1" sep="$2" el
    __ret=()
    while true; do
        el="${s%%"$sep"*}"
        __ret+=("$el")
        # If no sep was left, quit
        [[ "$el" == "$s" ]] && break
        s="${s#*"$sep"}"
    done
    return 0
}

# some tests:
split_str_by "a,b,c" ,
declare -p __ret  # __ret=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c")

split_str_by ",a,,b,c," ,
declare -p __ret # __ret=([0]="" [1]="a" [2]="" [3]="b" [4]="c" [5]="")

split_str_by ",,a,b,,,c,," ,,
declare -p __ret # __ret=([0]="" [1]="a,b" [2]=",c" [3]="")

split_str_by " *a *b *c *" ' *'
declare -p __ret # __ret=([0]="" [1]="a" [2]="b" [3]="c" [4]="")

split_str_by "--aa--bb--cc" '--'
declare -p __ret # declare -a __ret=([0]="" [1]="aa" [2]="bb" [3]="cc")
```

Comment: you can get rid of the ugly `true` and `break` by slightly modifying the loop to `while el=...; __ret+=...; [[ $el != $s ]]; do s=...; done` and I think `return 0` is the default behaviour

Comment:  this is equivalent to my `split_byStr_bash_naive` without needing an explicit test for empty string, and seems to run with comparable performance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IFS=', '; array=(Paris, France, Europe)
for item in ${array[@]}; do echo $item; done
```

It's simple. If you want, you can also add a declare (and also remove the commas):

```
IFS=' ';declare -a array=(Paris France Europe)
```

The IFS is added to undo the above but it works without it in a fresh bash instance

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do it without modifying IFS:

```
read -r -a myarray <<< "${string//, /$IFS}"
```

Rather than changing IFS to match our desired delimiter, **we can replace all occurrences of our desired delimiter `", "` with contents of `$IFS` via `"${string//, /$IFS}"`.**

Maybe this will be slow for very large strings though?

This is based on Dennis Williamson's answer.

Comment: the default IFS is a list of white space characters - you're just changing one string into another string but then still leaving IFS to separate based on characters in that string.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this post when looking to parse an input like:
word1,word2,...

none of the above helped me. solved it by using awk. If it helps someone:

```
STRING="value1,value2,value3"
array=`echo $STRING | awk -F ',' '{ s = $1; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) s = s "\n"$i; print s; }'`
for word in ${array}
do
        echo "This is the word $word"
done
```

Answer (score -2):

UPDATE: Don't do this, due to problems with eval.

With slightly less ceremony:

```
IFS=', ' eval 'array=($string)'
```

e.g.

```
string="foo, bar,baz"
IFS=', ' eval 'array=($string)'
echo ${array[1]} # -> bar
```

Comment: eval is evil! don't do this.

Comment: Pfft. No. If you're writing scripts large enough for this to matter, you're doing it wrong. In application code, eval is evil. In shell scripting, it's common, necessary, and inconsequential.

Comment: put a `$` in your variable and you'll see... I write many scripts and I never ever had to use a single `eval`

Comment: You're right, this is only usable when the input is known to be clean. Not a robust solution.

Comment: The only time i ever had to use eval, was for a application that would self generate its own code/modules... AND this never had any form of user input...

Answer (score -2):

Since there are so many ways to solve this, let's start by defining what we want to see in our solution.

1. Bash provides a builtin `readarray` for this purpose. Let's use it.
2. Avoid ugly and unnecessary tricks such as changing `IFS`, looping, using `eval`, or adding an extra element then removing it.
3. Find a simple, readable approach that can easily be adapted to similar problems.

The `readarray` command is easiest to use with newlines as the delimiter. With other delimiters it may add an extra element to the array. The cleanest approach is to first adapt our input into a form that works nicely with `readarray` before passing it in.

The input in this example does **not** have a multi-character delimiter. If we apply a little common sense, it's best understood as comma separated input for which each element may need to be trimmed. My solution is to split the input by comma into multiple lines, trim each element, and pass it all to `readarray`.

```
string='  Paris,France  ,   All of Europe  '
readarray -t foo < <(tr ',' '\n' <<< "$string" |sed 's/^ *//' |sed 's/ *$//')

# Result:
declare -p foo
# declare -a foo='([0]="Paris" [1]="France" [2]="All of Europe")'
```

---

**EDIT:** My solution allows inconsistent spacing around comma separators, while also allowing elements to contain spaces. Few other solutions can handle these special cases.

I also avoid approaches which seem like hacks, such as creating an extra array element and then removing it. If you don't agree it's the best answer here, please leave a comment to explain.

If you'd like to try the same approach purely in Bash and with fewer subshells, it's possible. But the result is harder to read, and this optimization is probably unnecessary.

```
string='     Paris,France  ,   All of Europe    '
foo="${string#"${string%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
foo="${foo%"${foo##*[![:space:]]}"}"
foo="${foo//+([[:space:]]),/,}"
foo="${foo//,+([[:space:]])/,}"
readarray -t foo < <(echo "$foo")
```

Answer (score -2):

**Do not change IFS!**

Here's a simple bash one-liner:

```bash
read -a my_array <<< $(echo ${INPUT_STRING} | tr -d ' ' | tr ',' ' ')
```

Answer (score -3):

**Here's my hack!**

Splitting strings by strings is a pretty boring thing to do using bash. What happens is that we have limited approaches that only work in a few cases (split by ";", "/", "." and so on) or we have a variety of side effects in the outputs.

The approach below has required a number of maneuvers, but I believe it will work for most of our needs!

```
#!/bin/bash

# --------------------------------------
# SPLIT FUNCTION
# ----------------

F_SPLIT_R=()
f_split() {
    : 'It does a "split" into a given string and returns an array.

    Args:
        TARGET_P (str): Target string to "split".
        DELIMITER_P (Optional[str]): Delimiter used to "split". If not 
    informed the split will be done by spaces.

    Returns:
        F_SPLIT_R (array): Array with the provided string separated by the 
    informed delimiter.
    '

    F_SPLIT_R=()
    TARGET_P=$1
    DELIMITER_P=$2
    if [ -z "$DELIMITER_P" ] ; then
        DELIMITER_P=" "
    fi

    REMOVE_N=1
    if [ "$DELIMITER_P" == "\n" ] ; then
        REMOVE_N=0
    fi

    # NOTE: This was the only parameter that has been a problem so far! 
    # By Questor
    # [Ref.: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390732/61742]
    if [ "$DELIMITER_P" == "./" ] ; then
        DELIMITER_P="[.]/"
    fi

    if [ ${REMOVE_N} -eq 1 ] ; then

        # NOTE: Due to bash limitations we have some problems getting the 
        # output of a split by awk inside an array and so we need to use 
        # "line break" (\n) to succeed. Seen this, we remove the line breaks 
        # momentarily afterwards we reintegrate them. The problem is that if 
        # there is a line break in the "string" informed, this line break will 
        # be lost, that is, it is erroneously removed in the output! 
        # By Questor
        TARGET_P=$(awk 'BEGIN {RS="dn"} {gsub("\n", "3F2C417D448C46918289218B7337FCAF"); printf $0}' <<< "${TARGET_P}")

    fi

    # NOTE: The replace of "\n" by "3F2C417D448C46918289218B7337FCAF" results 
    # in more occurrences of "3F2C417D448C46918289218B7337FCAF" than the 
    # amount of "\n" that there was originally in the string (one more 
    # occurrence at the end of the string)! We can not explain the reason for 
    # this side effect. The line below corrects this problem! By Questor
    TARGET_P=${TARGET_P%????????????????????????????????}

    SPLIT_NOW=$(awk -F"$DELIMITER_P" '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){printf "%s\n", $i}}' <<< "${TARGET_P}")

    while IFS= read -r LINE_NOW ; do
        if [ ${REMOVE_N} -eq 1 ] ; then

            # NOTE: We use "'" to prevent blank lines with no other characters 
            # in the sequence being erroneously removed! We do not know the 
            # reason for this side effect! By Questor
            LN_NOW_WITH_N=$(awk 'BEGIN {RS="dn"} {gsub("3F2C417D448C46918289218B7337FCAF", "\n"); printf $0}' <<< "'${LINE_NOW}'")

            # NOTE: We use the commands below to revert the intervention made 
            # immediately above! By Questor
            LN_NOW_WITH_N=${LN_NOW_WITH_N%?}
            LN_NOW_WITH_N=${LN_NOW_WITH_N#?}

            F_SPLIT_R+=("$LN_NOW_WITH_N")
        else
            F_SPLIT_R+=("$LINE_NOW")
        fi
    done <<< "$SPLIT_NOW"
}

# --------------------------------------
# HOW TO USE
# ----------------

STRING_TO_SPLIT="
 * How do I list all databases and tables using psql?

\"
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/psql -c \"\l\"
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/psql <DB_NAME> -c \"\dt\"
\"

\"
\list or \l: list all databases
\dt: list all tables in the current database
\"

[Ref.: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/how-do-i-list-all-databases-and-tables-using-psql]


"

f_split "$STRING_TO_SPLIT" "bin/psql -c"

# --------------------------------------
# OUTPUT AND TEST
# ----------------

ARR_LENGTH=${#F_SPLIT_R[*]}
for (( i=0; i<=$(( $ARR_LENGTH -1 )); i++ )) ; do
    echo " > -----------------------------------------"
    echo "${F_SPLIT_R[$i]}"
    echo " < -----------------------------------------"
done

if [ "$STRING_TO_SPLIT" == "${F_SPLIT_R[0]}bin/psql -c${F_SPLIT_R[1]}" ] ; then
    echo " > -----------------------------------------"
    echo "The strings are the same!"
    echo " < -----------------------------------------"
fi
```

Answer (score -3):

For multilined elements, why not something like

```
$ array=($(echo -e $'a a\nb b' | tr ' ' '§')) && array=("${array[@]//§/ }") && echo "${array[@]/%/ INTERELEMENT}"

a a INTERELEMENT b b INTERELEMENT
```

Answer (score -4):

Another way would be:

```
string="Paris, France, Europe"
IFS=', ' arr=(${string})
```

Now your elements are stored in "arr" array. 
To iterate through the elements:

```
for i in ${arr[@]}; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: I cover this idea in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/split-string-into-an-array-in-bash/45201229#45201229); see ***Wrong answer #5*** (you might be especially interested in my discussion of the `eval` trick). Your solution leaves `$IFS` set to the comma-space value after-the-fact.

Answer (score -5):

Another approach can be:

```
str="a, b, c, d"  # assuming there is a space after ',' as in Q
arr=(${str//,/})  # delete all occurrences of ','
```

After this 'arr' is an array with four strings.
This doesn't require dealing IFS or read or any other special stuff hence much simpler and direct.

Comment: Same (sadly common) antipattern as other answers: subject to word splitting and filename expansion.