# awk 1 unexpected character '.' suddenly appeared

Tags: awk

the script was working. I added some comments and renamed it then submitted it. today my instructor told me it doesnt work and give me the error of `awk 1 unexpected character '.'`
the script is supposed to read a name in command line and return the student information for the name back.
right now I checked it and surprisingly it gives me the error.
I should run it by the command like this:

```
scriptName -v name="aname" -f filename
```

what is this problem and which part of my code make it?

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
BEGIN{
tmp=name;
nameIsValid;
if (name && tolower(name) eq ~/^[a-z]+$/ )
{

    inputName=tolower(name)
    nameIsValid++;
}
else
{
    print "you have not entered the student name"
    printf "Enter the student's name: "
    getline inputName < "-"
    tmp=inputName;
    if (tolower(inputName) eq ~/^[a-z]+$/)
    {
        tmpName=inputName
        nameIsValid++
    }
    else
    {
    print "Enter a valid name!"
    exit
    }
}
inputName=tolower(inputName)
FS=":"
   }
   {
if($1=="Student Number")
{
    split ($0,header,FS)    
}
if ($1 ~/^[0-9]+$/ && length($1)==8)
{
    split($2,names," ")
    if (tolower(names[1]) == inputName || tolower(names[2])==inputName )
    {
        counter++
            for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            {
                printf"%s:%s ",header[i], $i

            }

            printf "\n"

    }
}
   }
   END{
   if (counter == 0 && nameIsValid)
   {
 printf "There is no record for the %-10s\n" , tmp 
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps to fix the script:

1. Get rid of all those spurious `NULL` statements (trailing semi-colons at the end of lines).
2. Get rid of the unset variable `eq` (it is NOT an equality operator!) from all of your comparions.
3. Cleanup the indenting.
4. Get rid of that first non-functional `nameIsValid;` statement.
5. Change `printf "\n"` to the simpler `print ""`.
6. Get rid of the useless `,FS` arg to `split()`.
7. Change `name && tolower(name) ~ /^[a-z]+$/` to just the second part of that condition since if that matches then of course name is populated.
8. Get rid of all of those `tolower()`s and use character classes instead of explicit `a-z` ranges.
9. Get rid of the `tmp` variable.
10. Simplify your `BEGIN` logic.
11. Get rid of the unnecessary `nameIsValid` variable completely.
12. Make the awk body a bit more awk-like

And here's the result (untested since no sample input/output posted):

```
BEGIN {
    if (name !~ /^[[:alpha:]]+$/ ) {
        print "you have not entered the student name"
        printf "Enter the student's name: "
        getline name < "-"
    }

    if (name ~ /^[[:alpha:]]+$/) {
        inputName=tolower(name)
        FS=":"
    }
    else {
        print "Enter a valid name!"
        exit
    }
}

$1=="Student Number" { split ($0,header) }

$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ && length($1)==8 {

        split(tolower($2),names," ")

        if (names[1]==inputName || names[2]==inputName ) {
            counter++
            for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                printf "%s:%s ",header[i], $i
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
}

END {
    if (counter == 0 && inputName) {
        printf "There is no record for the %-10s\n" , name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed the shebang line to:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
```

and then in command line didnt use -f. It is working now

Comment: Make sure you never run this script on Solaris where /usr/bin/awk is old, broken awk or you'll get cryptic syntax errors and/or unexpected output.

Answer (score 0):

Run the script in the following way:

```
awk -f script_name.awk input_file.txt
```

This seems to suppress the warnings and errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was resetting the IFS variable to be `IFS=","` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10586169/2675672) for splitting string into an array. So I resetted the IFS variable and got my code to work.

```
IFS=', '
read -r -a array <<< "$string"
IFS=' ' # reset IFS
```