# split string based on delimeter and put them into array using bash script

Tags: bash

What is a simple way to split a string and put into an array
Here is my string

```
aa_bb__cc_dd
```

I would like to have them in an array like this:

```
array[0] = "aa"

array[1] = "bb"

array[2] = ""

array[3] = "cc"

array[4] = "dd"
```

Comment: Look at this [solution][1], this exactly has what you're looking for.

Just use

`IFS='_' read -a array <<< "aa_bb__cc_dd"`

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/bash-split-string-into-array

Answer (score 5):

```
var=aa_bb__cc_dd
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=_
array=($var)
IFS=$oldIFS
```