# I want to insert/store wc -l result into a bash array

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have the following comand:

```
grep RJAVA | grep -v grep | wc -l ' | sort | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f2
```

After executing this, I get the following result :

10 
0
0
10

I would like to put all these numbers into a bash array so that I can loop through
the array. I tried using xargs but couldn't make it work. Any suggestion ?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/bash-split-string-into-array‎)?

Comment: wondering how the `grep ... | grep ... | wc -l` gives you the above result... (wc on pipe results only one number...), so what you sorting? and whats mean the single `'` after the `wc`? strange...

Comment: It has a badly paired `'` char. So it is syntactically wrong and it will prompt a '>' to enter the enclosing `'`. But if you remove `'` this waits forever and ever more! First `grep` tries to read something from `stdin`. So this will not write anything to anywhere... Anyway do not use such pipe snakes. Use e.g. one `awk` instead. Or if you have old `awk` use a `sort` and `awk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work:

```
array=($( YOUR_ENTIRE_PIPED_COMMAND ))
```

BTW, the command above seems broken - you are missing the input to the first `grep` (either filnames, or pipe into it)

Comment: You don't want the backticks in there.

Comment: @Kevin - Old (pre-bash) habits die hard :(

Answer (score -1):

you could try tr:

```
IN="10 0 0 10"

arr=$(echo $IN | tr " " "\n")

for x in $arr
do
    echo "> [$x]"
done
```

Regards, Edi

Comment: Ok, DVK's answer is easier. I thought to complicated, as I adopted a solution I had in another script :)

Comment: and misleading: not an array but a whitespace-separated string (tempted to downvote).