# Why does my string not split nicely into an array?

Tags: arrays, string, git, bash, ifs

I have that bash script that shall read the output of `git show` into an array.

First, I create a string with the following statement:

```
git show --quiet --date=rfc --pretty=format:"%s|%b|%an, %ae|%H|%cd" HEAD
```

Which gives me the pattern that I want:

```
SUBJECT|BODY|AUTHOR_NAME, AUTHOR_EMAIL|COMMIT_HASH|COMMIT_DATE
```

I can confirm that the resulting string does **not** contain a `|` character on an unexpected place.

Next, I want to split up the string into it's fields as supposed in [Split string into an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/bash-split-string-into-array):

```
  IFS='|' read -ra FIELDS <<< "$(git show --quiet --date=rfc --pretty=format:"%s|%b|%an, %ae|%H|%cd" $i)"
```

When I now look at `FIELDS`, only the first two elements are filled, but the others are empty:

```
echo ${FIELDS[0]} # prints SUBJECT
echo ${FIELDS[1]} # prints BODY
echo ${FIELDS[2]} # prints nothing
echo ${FIELDS[3]} # prints nothing
echo ${FIELDS[4]} # prints nothing
```

What am I doing wrong? Why are the last three array elements empty?

Comment: Can you show the output of the command? In my case, BODY entry is empty, but multiline body comes last.

Comment: @choroba: see answer of l0b0 below. The problem is that `git show` terminates the body with a newline which breaks the array creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @l0b0 pointed out, the problem is caused by a newline in `git show`'s output, right after "BODY" -- the `read` command reads a single line, so it stops there. You can make it read the whole thing by changing its line delimiter character from newline to... nothing, with `read -d ''`:

```
IFS='|' read -d '' -ra FIELDS <<< "$(git show --quiet --date=rfc --pretty=format:"%s|%b|%an, %ae|%H|%cd" $i)"
```

This sets `${FIELDS[0]}` to "SUBJECT", `${FIELDS[1]}` to "BODY\n", `${FIELDS[2]}` to "AUTHOR_NAME, AUTHOR_EMAIL", etc. One complication, however, is that it'll also treat the syntactic newline at the end of the output as part of the last field, i.e. `${FIELDS[4]}` will be set to "COMMIT_DATE\n".

Comment: Keep in mind that `read -d ''` always exits with status 1, since technically it runs out of input before the line delimiter was found.

Answer (score 3):

The `git show` command you've given splits the output into multiple lines (at least in version 1.8.3.1), even when passed to another command:

```
$ git show --quiet --date=rfc --pretty=format:"%s|%b|%an, %ae|%H|%cd" HEAD
SUBJECT|BODY
|AUTHOR_NAME, AUTHOR_EMAIL|COMMIT_HASH|COMMIT_DATE
```

To work around this you can pipe the output to `tr -d '\n'` before `read`ing it.

Comment: Yep. Could confirm this behavior.

Comment: using `tr` is not suitable for me since I want to keep the line feeds in the `BODY`. Instead, I'll fetch the body in a second `git show` call and append it to the array manually. Thx!

Comment: You could also use `read -d '' ...` to make it read the entire string in one go (instead of just the first line).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Go ahead and make your comment an answer. While the answer of l0b0 pointed me to the cause of the wrong behavior, your comment is the answer for me.