# Split string into multiple variables in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a string that gets generated below:

```
192.168.1.1,UPDOWN,Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13, changed state to up
```

How can I take that string and make 2 variables out of it (using bash)?

For example I want

```
$ip=192.168.1.1 
$int=GigabitEthernet1/0/13
```

Comment: How is `GigabitEthernet1/0/13` delimited? Whatever follows `Interface<space>`?

Comment: Yes. Whatever follows Interface

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try this:

```
mystring="192.168.1.1,UPDOWN,Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13, changed state to up"

IFS=',' read -a myarray <<< "$mystring"

echo "IP: ${myarray[0]}"
echo "STATUS: ${myarray[3]}"
```

In this script `${myarray[0]}` refers to the **first** field in the comma-separated string, `${myarray[1]}` refers to the **second** field in the comma-separated string, etc.

Answer (score 27):

Use `read` with a custom field separator (`IFS=,`):

```
$ IFS=, read ip state int change <<< "192.168.1.1,UPDOWN,Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet1013, changed state to up"
$ echo $ip
192.168.1.1
$ echo ${int##*Interface}
GigabitEthernet1013
```

Make sure to enclose the string in quotes.

Comment: how do I split a string into one array variable?

Comment: @Inoperable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/split-string-into-an-array-in-bash

Answer (score 8):

@damienfrancois has the best answer. You can also use bash regex matching:

```
if [[ $string =~ ([^,]+).*"Interface "([^,]+) ]]; then 
    ip=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    int=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
echo $ip; echo $int
```

```
192.168.1.1
GigabitEthernet1/0/13
```

With bash regexes, any literal text can be quoted (must be, if there's whitespace), but the regex metachars must not be quoted.

Comment: I'll point out here what I said in my now-deleted redundant answer: a regular expression may not be that much better than string splitting in this case, but can be useful for other problems.