# Can I put strings divided by newlines into an array using the read builtin?

Tags: arrays, string, bash, newline, delimiter

I have a variable:

```
var='/path/to/filename.ext
     /path/to/filename2.ext
     /path/to/filename3.ext'
```

I want to put all strings separated by a newline in an array:

```
declare -a arr
```

Based on numerous posts here on StackOverflow, I found a couple of ways:

```
# method 1: while loop
while read line; do
    arr+=($line)
done <<< "$var"

# method 2: readarray
readarray -t arr <<< "$var"

# method 3:
IFS=$'\n'
arr=("$var")
```

However, before I learned all these methods, I was using another one, namely:

```
# method 4 (not working in the current situation)
IFS=$'\n'
read -a arr <<< "$var"
```

This is not working, because it will only store the first string of `var` in `arr[0]`. I don't understand why it doesn't work in situations where the delimiter is a newline, while it *does* work with other delimiters, e.g.:

```
IFS='|'
strings='/path/to/filename.ext|/path/to/filename2.ext|'
read -a arr <<< "$strings"
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

### Edit

Removed my own answer that argued you cannot use `read` for this purpose. Turns out you can.

Comment: Maybe it's the `$` in front of the `'\n'`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that your answer is *wrong*. Yes, you can! you need to use the `-d` switch to `read`:

> `-d` *delim*
>
> The first character of *delim* is used to terminate the input line, rather than newline.

If you use it with an empty argument, bash uses the null byte as a delimiter:

```
$ var=$'/path/to/filename.ext\n/path/to/filename2.ext\n/path/to/filename3.ext'
$ IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a arr < <(printf '%s\0' "$var")
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="/path/to/filename.ext" [1]="/path/to/filename2.ext" [2]="/path/to/filename3.ext")'
```

Success. Here we're using a process substitution with `printf` that just dumps the content of the variable with a trailing null byte, so that `read` is happy and returns a success return code. You could use:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a arr <<< "$var"
```

In this case, the content of `arr` is the same; the only difference is that the return code of `read` is `1` (failure).

---

As a side note: there's a difference between

```
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ read ...
```

and

```
$ IFS=$'\n' read ...
```

The former sets `IFS` globally (i.e., `IFS` will retain this value for the remaining part of the script—until you modify it again, of course): *you very likely don't want to do that!*

The latter only sets `IFS` for the command `read`. *You certainly want to use it that way!*

---

Another side note: about your method 1. You're missing quotes, you're not unsetting `IFS`, and you're not using the `-r` flag to `read`. This is bad:

```
while read line; do
    arr+=($line)
done <<< "$var"
```

This is good:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    arr+=( "$line" )
done <<< "$var"
```

Why?

- without unsetting `IFS`, you'll get leading and trailing spaces removed.
- Without `-r`, some backslashes will be understood as escaping backslashes (`\'`, trailing `\`, `\`, and maybe others).
- Without properly quoting `( "$line" )`, you'll get word splitting and filename expansion turned on: you don't want that in case your input contains spaces or glob characters (like `*`, `[`, `?`, etc.).

Comment: Awesome, great explanation, I've learned ten new things from your answer!

Comment: Question: why is the return value of `read` `0` (success) in the first case  (process substitution), but `1` (error) in the second case (using unadorned `"$var"`)? Does it have to do with that `read` doesn't encounter EOF in the first case (strings ends with null character), but does encounter it in the second case?

Comment: @Neftas: Yes. `read -d ''` stops reading as soon as it encounters a null byte or when it can't read anymore. In the former case, it exits with a success return code (since it happily met the delimiter). In the latter case, it exits (it has no other choices), but isn't happy as it didn't meet the delimiter, and complains about it by returning a `1` code (failure). The `< <(printf '%s\0' "$var")` ensures that `read` meets a null byte. With `<<< "$var"`, `read` never encounters a null byte, only an EOF.

Comment: And what if we change `var` to include a null character like: `var=$'/path/to/filename.ext\n/path/to/filename2.ext\n/path/to/filename3.ext\0'` and use it in a here string `<<< "$var"`. It still gives `1` as exit code?

Comment: @Neftas: in Bash, a variable cannot contain a null byte. You can't, however hard you try, put a null byte in there. You may try: `var=$'test\0test`, but `declare -p var` shows that `var` contains `test` only; you can try `printf -v var 'test\0test'`, but the same happens. You can try `var=$(printf 'test\0test')`, and here `declare -p var` shows that `var` contains `testtest`. So you really can't put a null byte in a Bash variable!

Comment: OK, so putting null characters at the end of strings only works in a process substitution, because Bash is working on a named pipe, which is special kind of file, and files obviously _can_ contain strings which end with null characters. Am I right?

Comment: And perhaps to save someone else a few hours of madness, note that *read*'s "-d" flag requires an intervening space before its argument. That is, *read -d ''* works, but *read -d''* does not. That's with version 3.2.57(1)-release on macOS.

Comment: @seh indeed! with `-d''` (no space), Bash (any version, and in fact any shell) will parse it as just `-d` (that's because of the [quote removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quote-Removal) step of the parser).