# nested bash loop to print two arrays on same line

Tags: arrays, bash

Hi I have created two arrays:

```
$ echo "${prot}"
abc
def
ghi

$ echo "${pos}"
123
456
789
```

where element n in prot refers to element n in pos. so I want to print the corresponding elements on one line, with one new line per pair.

I am trying to do this with a nested loop, where I split the respective arrays into elements via a newline:

```
for i in "${!prot[@]}";  do
    for j in "${!pos[@]}";  do
        IFS=$'\n' read -a arr1 <<<"$i"
        IFS=$'\n' read -a arr2 <<<"$j"
        echo $i $j  
    done
done
```

but this only gives me the last pair. it's one line which is great, but it's not printing them all. what am I doing wrong?

Expected output:

```
$
    abc 123
    def 456
    ghi 789
```

I created the arrays in the first place by doing

```
    for i in *.fasta; do
    IFS=_-. read -ra arr <<<"$i"
    tmp=$(printf "${arr[*]: 0: 1} ${arr[*]: 1: 1} ${arr[*]: -2: 1}")
    fa+="$tmp\n"
    done

   for i in "${fa[@]}"; do
   prot=$(echo -e "$i" | cut -d\  -f 1)
   pos=$(echo -e "$i" | cut -d\ -f 2) 
   done
```

Comment: `${prot}` is just the same as `$prot`. `${prot[@]}` is the array.

Comment: More specifically, `prot` is *not* an array, but a string with embedded newlines.

Comment: confirm that `prot` and `pos` are **arrays** and not simple variables that contain 3-words with embedded **newlines**.

Comment: If `echo "${prot}"` spits out all three of those lines then you don't have an array you have a string.

Comment: I also have doubts that `fa` is an array; how does *that* get created?

Comment: @David C. Rankin - you are right, I thought they were arrays but they are not. the last chunk of code in my questions shows how I "generate" what I thought were arrays

Comment: @chepner - have added how I create `fa` in last code chunk of question

Comment: Happens to all of us... Once they are in arrays, a single loop is all that is needed. You can use the `seq` approach to iterate, or a c-style loop `for((i=0;i<${#array[@];i++)); do` to output both elements side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to split strings into proper bash arrays:

```
readarray -t prot_array <<< "$prot"
readarray -t pos_array <<< "$pos"
```

Then, I would try something like:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#prot_array[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "${prot_array[i]} ${pos_array[i]}";
done
```

It's simple solution without nested loops. `${#prot[@]}` is the size of the array. The loop displays corresponding elements of both arrays.

Comment: thank you. it does print out all elements, however it doesn't appear to split the input by newline, hence all of `${prot[i]}` gets printed first on x newlines, followed by `${pos[i]}`. the inputs need to be read into an array that splits elements by newline. I shall add how I created the initial arrays in question.

Comment: have added expected output and how i created initial arrays

Comment: @brucezepplin take a look at: [bash split string into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/bash-split-string-into-array)

Comment: Use a C-style for loop (`for ((i=0; i<${#prot[@]}; i++))`) instead of `seq`.

Comment: @tmp that post is helpful, however I still cannot output `prot[1]` and `pos[1]` on same line. following the method on the link i output all elements of `prot[@]` with each element on a newline, followed by the same for `$pos[@]`

Comment: I think the problem is that they aren;t arrays, but rather lines of strings as @David has pointed out.

Comment: @brucezepplin - code for splitting strings into arrays added

Answer (score 1):

Another way that works even when dealing with arrays of differing length is simply to use a `while` loop with a counter variable to output the arrays side-by-side so long as both arrays have values:

```
#!/bin/bash

a1=( 1 2 3 4 5 )
a2=( a b c d e f g )

declare -i i=0

while [ "${a1[i]}" -a "${a2[i]}" ]; do

    printf " %s  %s\n" "${a1[i]}" "${a2[i]}"
    ((i++))

done

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash arrays_out.sh
 1  a
 2  b
 3  c
 4  d
 5  e
```

Comment: It's very neat!