# How to change a variable name in a loop

Tags: bash

I'm having a [very bad] blonde moment, and would like to know how I can have a changing variable name inside the following snippet of code:

```
sentence="This is   a sentence containing f@#cy |3tt3r5."
for word in $sentence
do
    echo $word
done
```

Ideally I would like to have each of the `word`s in the `$sentence` variable be held my a unique variable. So for example `echo $word_1` would print "This" and `echo $word_5` would print "containing" ... etc.

Should I be using arrays?

**Q:** How can I make a variable that keeps on changing i.e. `word_1` `word_2`.. `word_n`  until the for loop is complete.

Comment: Yeah, you could say `sentence=(This is a sentence containing 'f@#cy' '|3tter5.')` and loop over `"${sentence[@]}"` but you need to quote any token with shell metacharacters in it (and actually might want to quote each token).

Comment: @triplee Still having the blonde moment- `${sentence[@]}` why would I need to quote it ie `"${sentence[@]}"` and not `${sentence[@]}`? Also "${sentence[@]}" would be an array named "sentence"?

Comment: That's the syntax, yeah. The quotes are part of that syntax.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/split-string-into-an-array-in-bash might help you use array