# bash 4: Generic access to substring (n) of string by arbitrary delimiter?

Tags: string, bash, substring

Let's assume I have the following string: `x="number 1;number 2;number 3"`.

Access to the *first* substring is successfull via `${x%%";"*}`, access to the *last* substring is via `${x##*";"}`:

```
$ x="number 1;number 2;number 3"
$ echo "front : ${x%%";"*}"  #front-most-part
number 1
$ echo "back  : ${x##*";"}"  #back-most-part
number 3
$
```

How do I access the *middle part:* (eg. `number 2`)?
Is there a better way to do this if I have (many...) more parts then just three?
**In other words: Is there a generic way of accessing substring No. *`n`* of string *`yyy`*, delimited by string *`xxx`* where *`xxx`* is an arbitraty string/delimiter?**

---

I have read [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash?rq=1), but I specifically do not want to iterate over the string but rather directly access a given substring.

This specifically does not ask or a split into arrays, but into sub-strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string into an array in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/split-string-into-an-array-in-bash)

Comment: try this `cut -d';' -f2 <<< $x`

Comment: @Kalanidhi That _only_ accesses the second substring, in the end I'd like delimited access to all of them (this actually happens in a loop and generic access to any of the substrings is required).

Comment: @dev-null No, I ask for a split into strings, not arrays (This actually happens within a loop over a multidimensional array, so I don't want a subarray of an array).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a fixed index:

```
x="number 1;number 2;number 3"

# Split input into fields by ';' and read the 2nd field into $f2
# Note the need for the *2nd* `unused`, otherwise f2 would 
# receive the 2nd field *plus the remainder of the line*.
IFS=';' read -r unused f2 unused <<<"$x"

echo "$f2"
```

Generically, using an array:

```
x="number 1;number 2;number 3"

# Split input int fields by ';' and read all resulting fields
# into an *array* (-a).
IFS=';' read -r -a fields <<<"$x"

# Access the desired field.
ndx=1
echo "${fields[ndx]}"
```

---

**Constraints**:

Using `IFS`, the special variable specifying the **I**nternal **F**ield **S**eparator characters, *invariably* means:

- Only *single*, literal characters can act as field separators.

  - However, you can specify *multiple* characters, in which case *any* of them is treated as a separator.
- The *default* separator characters are `$' \t\n'` - i.e., space, tab, and newline, and *runs* of them (multiple contiguious instances) are always considered a *single* separator; e.g., `'a   b'` has *2* fields - the multiple space count as a single separator.
- By contrast, *with any other character*, characters in a run are considered separately, and thus separate *empty* fields; e.g., `'a;;b'` has *3* fields - each `;` is its own separator, so there's an empty field between `;;`.

The `read -r -a ... <<<...` technique **generally works well, as long as**:

- the input is *single-line*
- you're not concerned about *a trailing empty field getting discarded*

If you need a **fully generic, robust solution** that addresses the issues above, 
use the following variation, which is explained in [@gniourf_gniourf answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24426608/45375):

```
sep=';' 
IFS="$sep" read -r -d '' -a fields < <(printf "%s${sep}\0" "$x")
```

Note the need to use `-d ''` to read multi-line input all at once, and the need to terminate the input with another separator instance to preserve a trailing empty field; the trailing `\0` is needed to ensure that `read`'s exit code is `0`.

Comment: Quicker then Stackoverflow let's me accept it as the correct answer ;) Thanks!

Comment: Please use this to break a string: `IFS=';' read -r -d '' -a fields < <(printf '%s;\0' "$x")`. See my answer in the linked question.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Good point, I've updated the answer (and ++ for your linked answer).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use:

<s>Create an array with a delimiter of `;`:</s>

```
x="number 1;number 2;number 3"
_IFS=$IFS; IFS=';'
arr=($x)
IFS=$_IFS

echo ${arr[0]} # number 1
echo ${arr[1]} # number 2
echo ${arr[2]} # number 3
```

Comment: The is _the_ broken method to “split” a string on a delimiter (I should say, to introduce bugs) that is, unfortunately, wide spread, as it is subject pathname expansion (globbing). The “fix” is then to use `set -f` (but this doesn't fix _all_ the issues, as it will still concatenate multiple successive empty fields); and at this point you probably feel that you're fighting _against_ the shell: that's because you're using an _antipattern._ The linked question shows the canonical way to split a string: `IFS=\; read -r -d '' -a arr < <(printf '%s;\0' "$x")` (and it's only one line!).

Comment: When I say _it will still concatenate multiple successive empty field_ I mean when used with a space as `IFS` (which is not the case here). Though in this case it will remove the last field if it's empty.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: The globbing argument is valid (and having to set and restore _2_ configuration items (`IFS`, `set -f`) makes this solution ultimately cumbersome (though it may have a slight performance advantage compared to `read ... <<<...` and presumably more so compared to `read ... < <(printf ...)`). However, from what I can tell, there's no escaping the shell considering _runs_ of tabs, spaces, newlines a _single_ separator (concatenating multiple successive empty fields) - this logic is built into `IFS`, so it affects the array-literal syntax as well as `read`.

Comment: @mklement0 this happens when `IFS` is set to a space character, like a space or a tab or a newline (because Bash treats these chars in a special way). Try it with: `a='a  b'` (with 2 spaces between `a` and `b`) and then `IFS=' '; ary=( $a )`. You'll see that the empty fields are discarded. While this actually looks like what we'd want in general, it can be surprising when trying to slurp the output of a command in an array using `IFS=$'\n'; a=( $(echo a; echo; echo b) )`. Here the empty line isn't preserved… whether this is good or bad doesn't really matter; just something to be aware of!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Fully agreed, and my updated answer describes all that. My point was: this behavior is _inevitable_ with `IFS` and is not a shortcoming of _this_, the `($x)` approach - I now suspect you never meant to imply that, that you were only pointing out a _general_ limitation - so I think we're in full agreement.