# Bash script to convert decimal IP to binary

Tags: bash

I need to write a script to enter 2 IP addresses and then change them to binary.
I tried this script but it works just with numbers. I can't write the IP thus: `192.168.1.1`, but when I write it as `100` it's working fine.

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "Ebter the first ip"
read ip1
echo "Enter the second ip"
read ip2

a=`echo "obase=2;$ip1" | bc`
b=`echo "obase=2;$ip2" | bc`
echo $a
echo $b
```

What is wrong in my script?

Comment: You have to split the four components of the IP address and convert them separately

Comment: how can i separate them due to "."

Comment: Using arrays and `read`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/split-string-into-an-array-in-bash

Comment: What output do you expect? `2.2.2.2` should become `10.10.10.10` or `00000010000000100000001000000010` or something else?

Comment: 10.10.10.10
i need "." between binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

function convip()
{
    CONV=({0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1})

    ip=""
    for byte in `echo ${1} | tr "." " "`; do
        ip="${ip}.${CONV[${byte}]}"
    done
    echo ${ip:1}
}

echo "Enter the first ip"
read ip1
echo "Enter the second ip"
read ip2

a=`convip "${ip1}"`
b=`convip "${ip2}"`

echo "${a}"
echo "${b}"
```

**Result:**

```
Enter the first ip
1.1.1.1
Enter the second ip
2.2.2.2
00000001.00000001.00000001.00000001
00000010.00000010.00000010.00000010
```

**EDIT:** updated to keep dots

Comment: thanks for ur help
but how i can add dot between the binarys number

Comment: nitpicking: you can create CONV with `{0,1}{0,1}...` as well.