# how to split a string into an array?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to show to the user the list of zip file contained in a folder and give user the ability to choice which file to elaborate.

i'm trying  this

```
roms=$(ls ~/roms/*.zip)

PS3="Choose a ROM "
select opt in "${roms[@]}" "quit"; do
....
done
```

The problem is that my menu is showed in this way:

```
1) /home/realtebo/roms/rom_01.zip
/home/realtebo/roms/rom_02.zip
/home/realtebo/roms/rom_02_v2.zip
....
2) quit
```

Instead I need this

```
1) /home/realtebo/roms/rom_01.zip
2) /home/realtebo/roms/rom_02.zip
3) /home/realtebo/roms/rom_02_v2.zip
...
n+1) quit
```

How to 'explode' the result of ls as an array?
I'm using bash under linux mint 17.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string into an array in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/split-string-into-an-array-in-bash)

Comment: `ls` is redundant *and* [wrong](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) here. Use `roms=( ~/roms/*.zip )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need a variable (and using `ls` to populate the variable is certainly discouraged -- see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) so the code can be significantly simplified to

```
PS3="Choose a ROM "
select opt in ~/roms/*.zip "quit"; do
   :
```

If you *want* the file names in an array, just use the wildcard instead of `ls` (again, see the link above about why using `ls` breaks things):

```
roms=(~/roms/*.zip)
select opt in "${roms[@]}" "quit"; do
  :
```

Comment: Yes, thank you a lot, this works, but .... my question was different. I'm really interessed in how to split an ls string as an array to be used with select

Comment: @realtebo Note that your problem is that `rom=$(...)` doesn't create an array; it creates a flat string of space-separated filenames.