How to use awk to replace text with another text containing the "&" symbol?
I want to replace a file's text using awk. An example script:
#!/bin/bash

test_file="test.md"
key="KEY"
value="- & -"

echo "AAA $key AAA" > "$test_file"
echo "Original: $(cat "$test_file")"

tmp=$(mktemp)
awk -v s="$key" -v r="$value" '{sub(s,r)}1' "$test_file" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$test_file"
echo "Updated: $(cat "$test_file")"

rm "$test_file"

The expected output is:

Original: AAA KEY AAA
Updated: AAA - & - AAA

However, it outputs incorrectly (the "KEY" remains there instead of "&" symbol):

Original: AAA KEY AAA
Updated: AAA - KEY - AAA

I also tried the way below but no luck.
awk '
BEGIN { s=ARGV[1]; r=ARGV[2]; delete ARGV[1]; delete ARGV[2]; }
{ sub(s,r) }1
END {}' "$key" "$value" "$test_file" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$test_file"

Replacing "&" with other symbols works fine. Any suggestions for handling this case?

Please ignore the sed command in this question as I have some other cases to deal with and awk is suitable for my case except this weird "&" issue.

In the replacement, the symbol & represents the text that sub matched.  It needs to be escaped.  eg: value='- \\& -'

@WilliamPursell thank you! I just tested it and the output is correct. However, my real world case's value is taken from another file, I can't manually modify it to escape. So I just tried raw_value="- & -" && value="$(echo "$raw_value" | sed -e 's/&/\&/g')", but it doesn't work. I'll try more tmr, or do you have any suggestions?

See "Escape a string for a sed replace pattern" and "Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed".

@GordonDavisson It seems that the sed regex substitution result doesn't make awk cmd work when passing it as a value (I tried some last night, will read further when I get a chance). The solution provided by anuhava solved my problem. Anyway, thank you!

@GordonDavisson Update: raw_value="- & -" && value="$(echo "$raw_value" | sed -e 's/&/\\\\&/g')" also makes awk substitution work. Nice!

You may use awk like this with a bash replacement:
key="KEY"
value="- & -"

awk -v s="$key" -v r="${value//&/\\\\&}" '{sub(s,r)}1' <<< 'AAA KEY AAA'

AAA - & - AAA

Here "${value//&/\\\\&}" will replace & with \\&.

It works! By the way, are there any other symbols to look out for?

In replacement only & has special meaning but in the search regex there can be many like ., *, +, [, ], (, ) etc

Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37039138/548225 to escape all special characters in the search string

I would exploit GNU AWK for this task following way
key="KEY"
value="- & -"
echo "AAA $key AAA" | awk --assign FS="$key" --assign OFS="$value" '{$1=$1;print}'

gives output
AAA - & - AAA

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that field separator is key and output field separator is value, then for each line I trigger rebuild ($1=$1) and print result. Keep in mind you still need to be watchful against characters of special meaning inside key. Disclaimer: this code replaces all key occurrences with value, which is different than sub which you have use.
If you want to know more about FS or OFS then read 8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
