# Bash - Parse a String Into Array separated with comma

Tags: arrays, regex, bash, delimiter, ifs

in Bash, how can i transform below string in an array in Bash:

```
details="cl roo,dara shi,GD leader, is the man,YG FAMILY"
```

This is my code:

```
IFS="[a-z],[a-z]" read -r -a details_list <<< "$details"
```

Expected output when array is iterated:

```
cl roo
dara shii
GD leader, is the man
YG FAMILY
```

Actual Output when array is iterated:

```
cl roo
dara shii
GD leader
is the man
YG FAMILY
```

Comment: Duplicate question:
Here's [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10586169/5612294)!

Comment: I've checked it and it is different from the Expected output.

Comment: How are you determining which commas to break on?

Comment: I was thinking thebdelimiter is a comma that is placed between two characters.... i don't know how to work it on regex.

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
details="cl roo;dara shi;GD leader, is the man;YG FAMILY"

IFS=';' read -r -a array <<< "$details"

echo "${array[2]}"   -> GD leader, is the man
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this but "GD leader, is the man" was cut in two. I want to put it in one index.

Comment: @stickyservernotes: Look at my edit. 'GD leader' is in one

Comment: @stickyservernotes now it works. Please use another seperator like ';'

Comment: I am saving this as the last resort. The string i am going to parse will be from a logfile so i can't change the separator as I like.