# Loop through results of sed

Tags: bash, loops, sed

I'm having trouble looping through the lines returned by sed that are stored in a variable.

Currently it looks a bit like this

```
lines=$(sed -rne '/'"$timestamplastupload"'/,/'"$timestampnow"'/ p' /var/log/test.log)

for line in "$lines"; do

        echo "This line is: $line"

done
```

But so far this isn't working, the loop one runs once and while the contents of the $line variable appears to be the entire $lines variable and thus only printed once not looped through line by line prefixing with "This line is: "

What am I missing to be able to loop through each line of the sed output piece by piece. (Eventually ill be uploading the matching ones line by line to an API) so I need each line separately so I can process them as required.

As requested, some output from sed which has been tided up for security

```
Wed Feb 28 22:33:11 2018 us=452112 xxx/1.2.3.4:55487 [xxx] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Wed Feb 28 22:33:11 2018 us=452112 xxx/1.2.3.4:55487 [xxx] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Wed Feb 28 22:33:11 2018 us=452112 xxx/1.2.3.4:55487 [xxx] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Wed Feb 28 22:33:11 2018 us=452180 xxx/1.2.3.4:55487 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, client-instance restarting
Wed Feb 28 22:33:11 2018 us=452180 xxx/1.2.3.4:55487 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, client-instance restarting
Wed Feb 28 22:33:11 2018 us=452180 xxx/1.2.3.4:55487 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, client-instance restarting
Wed Feb 28 22:33:11 2018 us=452180 xxx/1.2.3.4:55487 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, client-instance restarting
```

Comment: Add output of your `sed` command to your question.

Comment: I suggest to use a `while` loop or put `sed`'s output in an array.

Comment: Check this post: [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646525/6862601)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `for` for reading.  Use process substitution instead:

```
while read -r line; do
  # your logic
done < <(sed -rne '/'"$timestamplastupload"'/,/'"$timestampnow"'/ p' /var/log/test.log)
```

See:

- [BashFAQ/001 - How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 0):

The output of your sed would be useful (because of dealing with endlines), but other than that, it seems that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/split-string-into-an-array-in-bash#10586169) provides an answer that would go along these lines:

```
IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$lines"
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done
```

Comment: I am beginning to think it might be a case of carriage returns etc but I dont know how to figure out if this is the case or not. After trying your method, that appears splitting on spaces.