# Bash for loop skip first element of array

Tags: bash

In bash,
I have a string, I want to convert in array and use it in a for loop but skipping the first element. The code below does not works:

```
build_string="100 99 98"
build_list=("$build_string")

echo $build_list
for i in "${build_list[@]:1}"
   do  echo "i: " $i
done
```

The for loop does not print anything. Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: What does `echo $build_list` print?

Comment: Better, what does `declare -p build_list` output

Comment: It works using build_list=($build_string)

Answer (score 7):

I believe you are not converting the array properly (or at all).
Please see this snippet:

```
build_string="100 99 98"
#build_list=("$build_string")  <-- this is not converting into array, following line is.
IFS=' ' read -r -a build_list <<< "$build_string"

echo $build_list
for i in "${build_list[@]:1}"
   do  echo "i: " $i
done

sleep 2
```

now the output is:

```
100
i:  99
i:  98
```

Which sounds reasonable. The `100` is printed when you ask `echo $build_string`.
Reference: [split string into array in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/split-string-into-an-array-in-bash)

---

As pointed out by [prefire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57585914/2125110), the double quotes on the second line are preventing array conversion. This snippet also works:

```
build_string="100 99 98"
build_list=($build_string)

echo $build_list
for i in "${build_list[@]:1}"
   do  echo "i: " $i
done

sleep 2
```

Note: I've added a `sleep 2` at the end, so I can see what is being printed.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the second line with this:

```
build_list=($build_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

`build_list=("$build_string")`

`build_list` array only have one item, so 
`${build_list[@]:1` is empty.