# Split String into multiple parts in bash

Tags: string, bash, awk, split

I want to split a string and need some parameters from it.

```
USER="dn: uid=dfl3030,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=tenant,dc=ycs,dc=io cn: Reb Lena Schmidt krbpasswordexpiration: 20200415235959Z mail: arl0031@tenant.ycs.io mail: rebecca-lena.schmidt@arlanxeo.com"
```

Want Below Parameters from the USER string as ->

```
UserId=dfl3030
Name=Reb Lena Schmidt
PwdExpiry=20200415235959Z
Email=rebecca-lena.schmidt@arlanxeo.com ( Second mail not the first one)
```

The IFS ", " will delimit by comma and space only. I have long list of array which require splitting of string as mentioned above. Please someone can help me. I used cut as well but its getting complicated. If someone can help me using awk or have some better solution, please help me.

Comment: You asked the exact same question earlier today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59739919/split-string-in-bash-script

Comment: You can request that the question be reopened, don't post a new question.

Comment: I have asked for reopen my first question.