# I want to Extract the date from this string in Bash and save it to a variable

Tags: bash, substring

I want to Extract the date from this string in Bash and save it to a variable but the problem im facing is there are many - and I cant use `##`.

Example where I want to extract 20211021:

```
7_I-9112135749087-ZA_23-20211021-085359_2051521761_0000.zip
```

Comment: If the string is always the same format, you can [split it into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10586153/12859753) and pull out the appropriate index.  In this case, split on `-` and pull out the 4th piece.

Comment: so the 4th - how would i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the filenames are always in the same format, you can do this in one of two ways.

Using just string manipulation:

```sh
$ file="7_I-9112135749087-ZA_23-20211021-085359_2051521761_0000.zip";

$ file=${file%-*};  # remove last dash through end of string
$ file=${file##*-}; # remove everything up to last remaining dash

$ echo "$file";
20211021
```

Using an array:

```sh
$ file="7_I-9112135749087-ZA_23-20211021-085359_2051521761_0000.zip";
$ IFS="-" read -ra parts <<< "$file";  # split into 0-based array using "-" as delimiter
$ echo ${parts[3]}; # 4th index
20211021
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a visible separator (`-`), I would simply use `cut` to select the fourth range:
`$ var=$(echo "7_I-9112135749087-ZA_23-20211021-085359_2051521761_0000.zip" | cut -d "-" -f4)`