# How can I use an applescript list (copied to the clipboard) in a bash array?

Tags: arrays, bash, list, applescript, clipboard

In applescript I use the following code to set the clipboard to a list (array): `set the clipboard to {"4", "4", "5"}`

Is it possible to assign the items of the list in the clipboard to a bash array? In applescript, the code for assigning the list items (from the clipboard) to a variable looks like this: `set theList to list of (the clipboard)`. What would be the bash equivalent for this code?

Thank you!

Comment: Accessing the clipboard in bash is done with `pbcopy`, which reads stdin and `pbpaste`, which writes to stdout. I don't know much more though.

Comment: Thanks, @gurkensaas!  
I've quit trying to transfer the AS (AppleScript) list (array) to Bash. I believe that the only option available is to store the elements of the AS list in the clipboard as string. Like this:  `set the clipboard to items of theList as string` (items must contain a line break at the end, so that they are pasted in Bash on separate lines).  
In Bash, I use this code:  `clipboard="$(pbpaste)"` to put the content of the clipboard in a var.
How to make array from "clipboard" var: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/how-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-in-bash

Comment: Seems good, if you manage to do it, consider posting an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to my question is as it follows. There's no Bash equivalent to `set theList to list of (the clipboard)`. But, there's this code that puts the content of the clipboard into a variable called "clipboard" (provided that the clipboard contains items separated by space or on separate lines).

```
#!/bin/bash

clipboard="$(pbpaste)" # get the content of the clipboard
theList=( $clipboard ) # make an array from the clipboard content

echo ${theList[1]} # proof that "theList" is an array
```